# Apex Test Class coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test

I test my class and its 50% on trigger handler class, what can I do to cover the lines with the red code;

**My Class:**

```
public class AccountTriggerHandler
{
    public static void updateContactAddresses(Map<ID, Account> updatedAccounts, Map<ID, Account> oldAccounts)
    {
        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Account a : updatedAccounts.values()){ 
            if(oldAccounts !=null) {
                //this is the red highlight
              /*  Account old = oldAccounts.get(a.Id); 
                if (a.billingstreet != old.billingstreet|| a.billingcity !=old.billingcity || a.billingstate !=old.billingstate || a.billingcountry != old.billingcountry) { 
                    accountIds.add(a.Id); */
                }
            } 
            else{
               accountIds.add(a.Id); 
            }
        }
        if (accountIds.size() > 0) {
            Contact[] updateAddress = [SELECT Id, accountId FROM contact WHERE accountId IN :accountIds];
            for (contact c : updateAddress) {
                 //red highlights
              /*  account a = updatedAccounts.get(c.accountId);
                c.mailingStreet = a.billingStreet;
                c.mailingcity = a.billingcity;
                c.mailingstate = a.billingstate;
                c.mailingpostalcode = a.billingpostalcode;
                c.mailingcountry = a.billingcountry;
               */
                }
            update updateAddress;
         }
    }
}
```

**My trigger** is 100%;

```
trigger contactFromAccounts on Account (after insert, after update) {
    AccountTriggerHandler.updateContactAddresses(Trigger.NewMap, Trigger.OldMap);      
}
```

This is my **Test class**:

```
@isTest
private class ContactAddressChange {
    static testmethod void testAddressChange() {
        //create Account
        Account sAcct = new Account();
        sAcct.Name = 'Test Account 1';
        //create address
        sAcct.BillingStreet = '11 Initial Street';
        sAcct.BillingCity = 'Rochester';
        sAcct.BillingPostalCode = '12456';
        sAcct.BillingState = 'NY';
        sAcct.BillingCountry = 'USA';
        insert sAcct;
        Test.stopTest();

        //create contact for Account "Test Account 1"
        Contact sContact1 = new Contact();
         //create contact address
        sContact1.MailingStreet = '1 Initial street';
        sContact1.MailingCity = 'Rochester';
        sContact1.MailingPostalCode = '12456';
        sContact1.MailingState = 'NY';
        sContact1.MailingCountry = 'USA';
        // sContact1.account.id = sAcct.id;
        sAcct.id = sContact1.account.id;

        Contact sContact2 = new Contact();
        sContact2.MailingStreet = '2 Initial street';
        sContact2.MailingCity = 'Rochester';
        sContact2.MailingPostalCode = '12456';
        sContact2.MailingState = 'NY';
        sContact2.MailingCountry = 'USA';
        //sContact2.account.id = sAcct.id;
        sAcct.id = sContact2.account.id;

        Contact sContact3 = new Contact();
        sContact3.MailingStreet = '3 Initial street';
        sContact3.MailingCity = 'Rochester';
        sContact3.MailingPostalCode = '12456';
        sContact3.MailingState = 'NY';
        sContact3.MailingCountry = 'USA';
        //sContact3.account.id = sAcct.id;
        sAcct.id = sContact3.account.id;

        //change address on account
        sAcct.BillingStreet = '11 Updated Street'; 
        sAcct.BillingCity = 'Updated City';
        sAcct.BillingPostalCode = '99999';
        sAcct.BillingState = 'PA';
        sAcct.BillingCountry = 'Mexico';

        Test.startTest();
         update sAcct;//this should fire my trigger.
        Test.stopTest();

        //check if account updated address match each contact address
        System.assertEquals(sAcct.BillingStreet, sContact1.mailingstreet); 
        System.assertEquals(sAcct.BillingCity, sContact1.MailingCity); 
        System.assertEquals(sAcct.BillingPostalCode, sContact1.MailingPostalCode); 
        System.assertEquals(sAcct.BillingState, sContact1.MailingState);
        System.assertEquals(sAcct.BillingCountry, sContact1.MailingCountry);

        System.assertEquals(sAcct.BillingStreet, sContact2.mailingstreet); 
        System.assertEquals(sAcct.BillingCity, sContact2.MailingCity); 
        System.assertEquals(sAcct.BillingPostalCode, sContact2.MailingPostalCode); 
        System.assertEquals(sAcct.BillingState, sContact2.MailingState);
        System.assertEquals(sAcct.BillingCountry, sContact2.MailingCountry);

        System.assertEquals(sAcct.BillingStreet, sContact3.mailingstreet); 
        System.assertEquals(sAcct.BillingCity, sContact3.MailingCity); 
        System.assertEquals(sAcct.BillingPostalCode, sContact3.MailingPostalCode); 
        System.assertEquals(sAcct.BillingState, sContact3.MailingState);
        System.assertEquals(sAcct.BillingCountry, sContact3.MailingCountry);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your class `AccountTriggerHandler` will not compile.

Comment: @Reshma What do you mean will not compile?

Comment: You have not commented one closing brace `}`

Comment: I just comment that here for stating that the lines are in red highlights.

Comment: Please also take a look at [these resources](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see many issues with your code and test class.

1. You have not commented closing brace `}` at line 12
2. There are multiple `Test.stopTest()` in test class
3. You have not updated contact's AccountId field so will not cover 50% of your code. Contact did not inserted to database.
4. You will be getting required field error for Contact since `Lastname` was not populated.
5. There will be update exception for Account since `Id` was not specified.

Update your test class with below code and add assertion.

```
@isTest
private class ContactAddressChange {
    static testmethod void testAddressChange() {
        Test.startTest();
        //create Account
        Account sAcct = new Account();
        sAcct.Name = 'Test Account 1';
        //create address
        sAcct.BillingStreet = '11 Initial Street';
        sAcct.BillingCity = 'Rochester';
        sAcct.BillingPostalCode = '12456';
        sAcct.BillingState = 'NY';
        sAcct.BillingCountry = 'USA';
        insert sAcct;

        //create contact for Account "Test Account 1"
        Contact sContact1 = new Contact();
        //create contact address
        sContact1.Lastname = 'sContact1';
        sContact1.MailingStreet = '1 Initial street';
        sContact1.MailingCity = 'Rochester';
        sContact1.MailingPostalCode = '12456';
        sContact1.MailingState = 'NY';
        sContact1.MailingCountry = 'USA';
        sContact1.Accountid = sAcct.id;

        Contact sContact2 = new Contact();
        sContact2.Lastname = 'sContact2';
        sContact2.MailingStreet = '2 Initial street';
        sContact2.MailingCity = 'Rochester';
        sContact2.MailingPostalCode = '12456';
        sContact2.MailingState = 'NY';
        sContact2.MailingCountry = 'USA';
        sContact2.Accountid = sAcct.id;

        Contact sContact3 = new Contact();
        sContact3.Lastname = 'sContact3';
        sContact3.MailingStreet = '3 Initial street';
        sContact3.MailingCity = 'Rochester';
        sContact3.MailingPostalCode = '12456';
        sContact3.MailingState = 'NY';
        sContact3.MailingCountry = 'USA';
        sContact3.Accountid = sAcct.id;

        List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>{sContact1, sContact2, sContact3};
        Insert contacts;

        //change address on account
        sAcct.BillingStreet = '11 Updated Street'; 
        sAcct.BillingCity = 'Updated City';
        sAcct.BillingPostalCode = '99999';
        sAcct.BillingState = 'PA';
        sAcct.BillingCountry = 'Mexico';

        update sAcct;//this should fire my trigger.
        Test.stopTest();

        //Add valid assertion for unit test
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Reshma, can you help me on my visualforce project? I have a post and I need some help. I very much appreciate if you help me..Thank you very much .