# CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, LeadConvert: execution of BeforeInsert

Tags: apex, trigger

> ERROR: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, LeadConvert: execution of BeforeInsert
>
> caused by: System.SObjectException: Field mkto_si__Last_Interesting_Moment__c is not editable
>
> Class.Class_Lead_TriggerFunction.mapContactFields: line 157, column 1
> Class.Class_Lead_TriggerFunction.leadDedupCheck: line 63, column 1
> Class.Class_Lead_TriggerFunction.beforeInsert: line 10, column 1
> Trigger.LeadConvert: line 6, column 1: []

Field `mkto_si__Last_Interesting_Moment__c` is a formula field of a managed package and not been used in the code/trigger.

TriggerHelper class:

```
public static void leadDedupCheck(list<Lead> newList){
      set<Id> leadIdSetToDelete = new set<Id>();

      list<Lead> leadListToUpdate = new list<Lead>();
      list<Contact> contactListToUpdate = new list<Contact>();

    map<string,Lead> emailLeadMap = new map<string,Lead>();
    map<string,Lead> exisitngEmailLeadMap = new map<string,Lead>();
    map<string,Contact> exisitngEmailContactMap = new map<string,Contact>();

      for(Lead newLead : newList){ 
      if(newLead.Email != null){ 
        emailLeadMap.put(newLead.Email,newLead);
      }
    }
    system.debug('emailLeadMap*size()*******************************'+emailLeadMap.size());
    system.debug('emailLeadMap**************************************'+emailLeadMap);
    if(emailLeadMap.size() > 0){
      string leadQuery = constructQuery('Lead_Conversion_Field_Mapping','Lead',emailLeadMap.keyset()) + ' AND IsConverted = false';
      for(Lead existingLead : Database.query(leadQuery)){
        exisitngEmailLeadMap.put(existingLead.email,existingLead);
      }
      system.debug('exisitngEmailLeadMap*****************************'+exisitngEmailLeadMap); 
      for(Contact existingContact : Database.query(constructQuery('Lead_Conversion_Field_Mapping','Contact',emailLeadMap.keyset()))){
        exisitngEmailContactMap.put(existingContact.email,existingContact);
      }
      system.debug('exisitngEmailContactMap***********************************'+exisitngEmailContactMap);
      for(Lead leadToProcess : emailLeadMap.values()){
        if(exisitngEmailLeadMap.size() > 0 && exisitngEmailLeadMap.get(leadToProcess.email) != null){
          Lead leadToUpdate = mapLeadFields(exisitngEmailLeadMap.get(leadToProcess.email),leadToProcess);
          system.debug('leadToUpdate***********************************'+leadToUpdate);
          leadListToUpdate.add(leadToUpdate);
          leadIdSetToDelete.add(leadToProcess.Id);
          leadToProcess.Is_Duplicate__c = true;
          leadToProcess.Delete_Date_Time__c = (DateTime.now()).addMinutes(1);
        }
        else if(exisitngEmailContactMap.size() > 0 && exisitngEmailContactMap.get(leadToProcess.email) != null){
          Contact contactToUpdate = mapContactFields(exisitngEmailContactMap.get(leadToProcess.email),leadToProcess);
          system.debug('contactToUpdate***********************************'+contactToUpdate);
          contactListToUpdate.add(contactToUpdate);
          leadIdSetToDelete.add(leadToProcess.Id);
          leadToProcess.Is_Duplicate__c = true;
          leadToProcess.Delete_Date_Time__c = (DateTime.now()).addMinutes(1);        
        }
      }
      if(leadListToUpdate.size() > 0){
        update leadListToUpdate;
      }
      if(contactListToUpdate.size() > 0){
        update contactListToUpdate;
      }      
    }               
    }
    public static void deleteDuplicateLeads(list<Lead> newList,map<Id,Lead> oldMap){
    set<Id> leadIdSetToDelete = new set<Id>();
      for(Lead newLead : newList){
         if(trigger.isUpdate && oldMap != null && oldMap.get(newLead.Id).Ready_To_Delete__c != newLead.Ready_To_Delete__c && newLead.Ready_To_Delete__c){
        leadIdSetToDelete.add(newLead.Id);
      }          
    }
    if(leadIdSetToDelete.size() > 0){
      delete [select id from Lead where id in : leadIdSetToDelete];  
    }     
    }    
    
    public static void afterLeadConvert(list<Lead> newList,map<Id,Lead> oldMap){
      map<String,Id> accountNameIdMap = new map<string,Id>();
      set<string> leadCompanySet = new set<string>();
    list<Lead> leadListToConvert = new list<Lead>();
     
      for(Lead newLead : newList){
       if((trigger.isInsert || (trigger.isUpdate && oldMap.get(newLead.Id).LeadSource != newLead.LeadSource)) && newLead.Is_Duplicate__c == false && !(newLead.LeadSource != null && newLead.LeadSource.startsWith('SFDC'))){
        leadListToConvert.add(newLead);
        if(lead.Company != null){
          leadCompanySet.add(newLead.Company);
        }
       }  
    }
    system.debug('leadCompanySet*************************************'+leadCompanySet);
    if(leadCompanySet.size() > 0){
      for(Account account : [select Id,Name from Account where Name in : leadCompanySet]){
        accountNameIdMap.put(account.Name,account.Id);
              
      }
    }
    system.debug('accountNameIdMap*************************************'+accountNameIdMap);
    for(Lead newLead : leadListToConvert){
      Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert(); 
      lc.setLeadId(newLead.Id);
      if(accountNameIdMap.get(newLead.company) != null){
        lc.setAccountId(accountNameIdMap.get(newLead.company));
      }
         lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);         
      lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
      Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc); 
      System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());
    }
    }
  
  public static String constructQuery(String fieldSetName, String ObjectName,set<string> valueSet){
    list<String> literals = new list<String>();
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> GlobalDescribeMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
      Schema.SObjectType SObjectTypeObj = GlobalDescribeMap.get(ObjectName);
      Schema.DescribeSObjectResult DescribeSObjectResultObj = SObjectTypeObj.getDescribe();
    Schema.FieldSet fieldSetObj = DescribeSObjectResultObj.FieldSets.getMap().get(fieldSetName);
    String query = 'SELECT ';
        for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : fieldSetObj.getFields()){
            query += f.getFieldPath() + ', ';
        }
    for(string value : valueSet){
      literals.add('\'' + value + '\'');
    }  
        query += 'Id FROM '+objectName+' where Email IN ' + '(' + String.join(literals, ',') + ')';
    system.debug('Query**************************'+query);
    return query;
  }
  
  public static Lead mapLeadFields(Lead oldLead,Lead newLead){
    List<Schema.FieldSetMember> schemaset = SObjectType.Lead.FieldSets.Lead_Conversion_Field_Mapping.getFields();
    for(integer a=0; a<schemaset.size(); a++){
      if(oldLead.get(schemaset[a].getFieldPath())  == null || oldLead.get(schemaset[a].getFieldPath())  == ' ' || string.ValueOf(schemaset[a].getType()) == 'BOOLEAN'){
        oldLead.put(schemaset[a].getFieldPath(),newLead.get(schemaset[a].getFieldPath()));
      }
    }
    return oldLead;
  }
  
  public static Contact mapContactFields(Contact contactToUpdate,Lead newLead){
    List<Schema.FieldSetMember> schemaset = SObjectType.Contact.FieldSets.Lead_Conversion_Field_Mapping.getFields();
    for(integer a=0; a<schemaset.size(); a++){      
      if(contactToUpdate.get(schemaset[a].getFieldPath())  == null || contactToUpdate.get(schemaset[a].getFieldPath())  == ' ' || string.ValueOf(schemaset[a].getType()) == 'BOOLEAN'){
        contactToUpdate.put(schemaset[a].getFieldPath(),newLead.get(schemaset[a].getFieldPath()));
      }
    }
    return contactToUpdate;
  }
```

What could be the probable issue?

TestClass:

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=false)
private class Class_Lead_TriggerFunction_Test {

    static testMethod void my_Class_Lead_TriggerFunction_Test(){
      
      test.startTest();  
        // TO DO: implement unit test
        Lead newLead = new Lead(
          FirstName = null,
          LastName = 'LN',
          Email = 'test@test.com',
          Company = 'Test Company',
          LeadSource = 'Test Lead Source',
          Is_Duplicate__c = false,
          Ready_To_Delete__c = false
        );
        insert newLead;
        
        Lead newLead1 = new Lead(
          FirstName = 'FN',
          LastName = 'LN',
          Email = 'test@test.com',
          Company = 'Test Company',
          LeadSource = 'Test Lead Source',
          Is_Duplicate__c = true,
          Ready_To_Delete__c = false,
          isConverted = false
        );
        insert newLead1;
        newLead1.Ready_To_Delete__c = true;
        update newLead1;
        
        test.stopTest();
    }

    static testMethod void my_Class_Contact_Dedup_Test() {
    test.startTest();
    Account testAccount = new Account(
      Name = 'Test Account'
    );
    insert testAccount;  

    Contact testContact = new Contact(
      FirstName = null,
      LastName = 'LN',
          Email = 'test1@test.com',
      AccountId = testAccount.Id      
    ); 
    insert testContact;

        // TO DO: implement unit test
        Lead newLead = new Lead(
          FirstName = 'FN',
          LastName = 'LN',
          Email = 'test1@test.com',
          Company = 'Test Company',
          LeadSource = 'Test Lead Source',
          Is_Duplicate__c = false
        );
        insert newLead;
    
        test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the actual trigger code that produces this error - limiting as best you can to the relevant lines.

Comment: Test methods failing, code coverage low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method

```
 public static Contact mapContactFields(Contact contactToUpdate,Lead newLead){
    List<Schema.FieldSetMember> schemaset = SObjectType.Contact.FieldSets.Lead_Conversion_Field_Mapping.getFields();
    for(integer a=0; a<schemaset.size(); a++){      
      if(contactToUpdate.get(schemaset[a].getFieldPath())  == null || contactToUpdate.get(schemaset[a].getFieldPath())  == ' ' || string.ValueOf(schemaset[a].getType()) == 'BOOLEAN'){
        contactToUpdate.put(schemaset[a].getFieldPath(),newLead.get(schemaset[a].getFieldPath()));
      }
    }
    return contactToUpdate;
  }
```

has only one dependency: the field set `Contact.Lead_Conversion_Field_Mapping`. It seems that the field `mkto_si__Last_Interesting_Moment__c` has been included in that field set by mistake. Removing it should cure the issue.

Comment: Thanks @David. Issue resolved!

Comment: How can i increase the code coverage for this test class?

Comment: @RichaUpadhyay See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines