# Attempting to get better code coverage on fairly simple trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage

I am new to working with Map objects in Apex and it has introduced a wrinkle to my test class process. I am only able to achieve 74% coverage and I absolutely cannot figure out why. This trigger is meant to assign a follow up task on selection of a certain call disposition by agents/reps.

Here is the trigger

```
    trigger DSFollowUpTask on DS_Denali__DialSource_Action__c(after update, after insert) {
    date current = date.today();
    DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now();

    //Declare empty arrays to hold IDs
    //Create Task List to insert
    Map < Id, DS_Denali__DialSource_Action__c > leadMap = new Map < Id, DS_Denali__DialSource_Action__c > ();
    Map < Id, DS_Denali__DialSource_Action__c > contactMap = new Map < Id, DS_Denali__DialSource_Action__c > ();
    List < Task > taskList = new List < Task > ();

    //Extract Lead and Contact IDs from DSAs with an appropriate Disposition and the call ended field populated
    for (DS_Denali__DialSource_Action__c dsa: trigger.new) {
        if (dsa.DS_Denali__Call_Ended__c != null && dsa.DS_Denali__Call_Disposition__c != null && (
                dsa.DS_Denali__Call_Disposition__c == 'Task follow up 3 days' ||
                dsa.DS_Denali__Call_Disposition__c == 'Task follow up 7 days' ||
                dsa.DS_Denali__Call_Disposition__c == 'Task follow up tomorrow')) {
            if (dsa.DS_Denali__Lead__c != null) {
                leadMap.put(dsa.DS_Denali__Lead__c, dsa);

            }
            else if (dsa.DS_Denali__Contact__c != null && dsa.DS_Denali__Lead__c == null) {
                contactMap.put(dsa.DS_Denali__Contact__c, dsa);
            }
        }
    }
    //Make sure there are Lead DSAs to process.
    if (!leadMap.isEmpty()) {
        //Query the necessary Lead information and loop through the results. 
        //Create Followup Tasks using the Lead information.
        for (Lead l: [Select Id, FirstName, LastName From Lead Where Id IN: leadMap.keyset()]) {

            DS_Denali__DialSource_Action__c dsa = leadMap.get(l.Id);
            Task FollowUp = new Task();
            FollowUp.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
            FollowUp.WhoId = l.Id;
            FollowUp.Status = 'Not Started';
            FollowUp.Priority = 'Normal';
            if (dsa.DS_Denali__Call_Disposition__c == 'Task Follow Up 3 Days') {
                FollowUp.Subject = 'Follow Up With ' + l.FirstName + ' ' + l.LastName + ' -- 3 days';
                FollowUp.ActivityDate = current.addDays(3);
                FollowUp.ReminderDateTime = currentDateTime.AddDays(3);
            }
            if (dsa.DS_Denali__Call_Disposition__c == 'Task follow up 7 days') {
                FollowUp.Subject = 'Follow Up With ' + l.FirstName + ' ' + l.LastName + ' -- 7 days';
                FollowUp.ActivityDate = current.addDays(7);
                FollowUp.ReminderDateTime = currentDateTime.AddDays(7);
            }
            if (dsa.DS_Denali__Call_Disposition__c == 'Task follow up tomorrow') {
                FollowUp.Subject = 'Follow Up With ' + l.FirstName + ' ' + l.LastName + ' -- from yesterday';
                FollowUp.ActivityDate = current.addDays(1);
                FollowUp.ReminderDateTime = currentDateTime.AddDays(1);
            } //else {
                //FollowUp.Subject = 'Follow Up With ' + l.FirstName + ' ' + l.LastName;
                //FollowUp.ActivityDate = current;
            //}
            taskList.add(FollowUp);
        }
    }

    //Make sure there are Lead DSAs to process.
    if (!contactMap.isEmpty()) {
        //Query the necessary Lead information and loop through the results. 
        //Create Followup Tasks using the Lead information.
        for (Contact c: [Select Id, FirstName, LastName, AccountId From Contact Where Id IN: contactMap.keyset()]) {

            DS_Denali__DialSource_Action__c dsa = contactMap.get(c.Id);
            Task FollowUp = new Task();
            FollowUp.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
            FollowUp.WhoId = c.Id;

            //if DSA related to opp, relate task to opp
            if(dsa.DS_Denali__Opportunity__c != null){
                FollowUp.WhatId = dsa.DS_Denali__Opportunity__c;
            }
            else {
                FollowUp.WhatId = c.AccountId;
            }
            FollowUp.Status = 'Not Started';
            FollowUp.Priority = 'Normal';
            if (dsa.DS_Denali__Call_Disposition__c == 'Task follow up 3 days') {
                FollowUp.Subject = 'Follow Up With ' + c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName + ' -- 3 days';
                FollowUp.ActivityDate = current.addDays(3);
                FollowUp.ReminderDateTime = currentDateTime.AddDays(3);
            }
            if (dsa.DS_Denali__Call_Disposition__c == 'Task follow up 7 days') {
                FollowUp.Subject = 'Follow Up With ' + c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName + ' -- 7 days';
                FollowUp.ActivityDate = current.addDays(7);
                FollowUp.ReminderDateTime = currentDateTime.AddDays(7);
            }
            if (dsa.DS_Denali__Call_Disposition__c == 'Task follow up tomorrow') {
                FollowUp.Subject = 'Follow Up With ' + c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName + ' -- from yesterday';
                FollowUp.ActivityDate = current.addDays(1);
                FollowUp.ReminderDateTime = currentDateTime.AddDays(1);
            } //else {
                //FollowUp.Subject = 'Follow Up With ' + c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName;
                //FollowUp.ActivityDate = current;
            //}
            taskList.add(FollowUp);
        }
    }
    //Make sure there are Tasks to insert.
    if (!taskList.isEmpty() && trigger.isUpdate) {

        try {
            insert taskList;
        } catch (exception e) {
            system.debug('Follow up Task was not created.');
            system.debug('ERROR: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And the test class:

```
@isTest

    private class DSFollowUpTask_Test {
     static testMethod void validateDSFollowUpTask() {
         //Map < Id, DS_Denali__DialSource_Action__c > leadMapTest = new Map < Id, DS_Denali__DialSource_Action__c > ();
         //Map < Id, DS_Denali__DialSource_Action__c > contactMapTest = new Map < Id, DS_Denali__DialSource_Action__c > ();

         //create DS Session
         DS_Denali__DialSource_Sessions_V3__c dsSession = new DS_Denali__DialSource_Sessions_V3__c();
         dsSession.Name = 'ce9958d2-c7f7-4045-8067-fdf7ffd929ef - 5d02cea5330efe001243086a';

         insert dsSession;

         //create account
         Account a = new Account(Name = 'Anthonys fantabulous account');
         insert a;

         ID aID = a.Id;

         //create contact
         Contact c = new Contact(FirstName = 'Anthony', LastName = 'Parker', AccountId = aId);
         insert c;

         Id conID = c.Id;
         //Map<id, Contact> conMap = new Map<id, Contact>();
         //conMap.put(conID, c);
         //System.debug(conMap);

         //create opp
         Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
         o.Name = 'Expensive Opportunity';
         o.AccountId = aID;
         o.CloseDate = date.Today();
         o.StageName = 'Prospecting';
         insert o;

         Id oppId = o.Id;

         /*  
         //insert DSA with Dispo of Follow Up
         d.DS_Denali__Opportunity__c = oppId;
         d.DS_Denali__Account__c = aID;
         d.DS_Denali__Contact__c = conID;
         d.DS_Denali__Call_Disposition__c = 'Follow up task tomorrow';
         d.DS_Denali__Subject__c = 'Booga';
         d.RecordTypeId = '0122E000000Yn8FQAS';
         d.DS_Denali__Call_Ended__c = system.now();
         insert d;
         System.debug(d.Id);
         */

         Lead l = new Lead(FirstName = 'Bruce', LastName = 'Wayne', Company = 'Wayne Corp', Status = 'Open - Not Contacted');
         insert l;
         ID leadID = l.Id;
         //leadMapTest.put(leadId, d);

         List < DS_Denali__DialSource_Action__c > actions = new List < DS_Denali__DialSource_Action__c > ();

         //for(integer i=0;i<200;i++){

         DS_Denali__DialSource_Action__c d1 = new DS_Denali__DialSource_Action__c(
             DS_Denali__DialSource_Session__c = dsSession.Id,
             DS_Denali__Subject__c = 'Oogie Boogie Man',
             DS_Denali__Call_Ended__c = system.now(),
             RecordTypeId = '0122E000000Yn8FQAS',
             DS_Denali__Lead__c = leadID,
             DS_Denali__Call_Disposition__c = 'Task follow up 3 days');
         actions.add(d1);

         DS_Denali__DialSource_Action__c d2 = new DS_Denali__DialSource_Action__c(
             DS_Denali__DialSource_Session__c = dsSession.Id,
             DS_Denali__Subject__c = 'Jack Skellington',
             DS_Denali__Call_Ended__c = system.now(),
             RecordTypeId = '0122E000000Yn8FQAS',
             DS_Denali__Contact__c = conID,
             DS_Denali__Opportunity__c = oppID,
             DS_Denali__Call_Disposition__c = 'Task follow up tomorrow');
         actions.add(d2);

         DS_Denali__DialSource_Action__c d3 = new DS_Denali__DialSource_Action__c(
             DS_Denali__DialSource_Session__c = dsSession.Id,
             DS_Denali__Subject__c = 'Jack Skellington',
             DS_Denali__Call_Ended__c = system.now(),
             RecordTypeId = '0122E000000Yn8FQAS',
             DS_Denali__Contact__c = conID,
             DS_Denali__Opportunity__c = null,
             DS_Denali__Call_Disposition__c = 'Task follow up 7 day');
         actions.add(d3);



         /*

          //Set parent record(s)
          if(math.mod(4, 2)==0){
            d.DS_Denali__Opportunity__c = oppId;
            d.DS_Denali__Account__c = aID;
            d.DS_Denali__Contact__c = conID;
          }
          else{
              d.DS_Denali__Lead__c = l.Id;
          }

          String s = 'a';
          //Set Disposition value
          if(s=='a'){
              d.DS_Denali__Call_Disposition__c = 'Task follow up 3 days';
              s='b';
          }
          if(s=='b'){
              d.DS_Denali__Call_Disposition__c = 'Task follow up 3 days';
              s='c';
          }
          if(s=='c'){
              d.DS_Denali__Call_Disposition__c = 'Task follow up 3 days';
              s='a';
          }
          actions.add(d);
      }
      */


         insert actions;





         //validate task created?


     }
 }
```

EDIT: All instances of the following are not getting coverage:

```
FollowUp.ActivityDate = current.addDays(x);
FollowUp.ReminderDateTime = currentDateTime.AddDays(x);
```

Comment: Testing is a pretty common topic here, so we have some [tag:canonical-qa] tagged questions dedicated to it. Specifically, the following might help you: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines

Comment: Please clarify which lines are uncovered that you believe should be covered, via an [edit].

Comment: Aside from that, it'd be helpful if you could show us what lines of code aren't being covered by making an [edit]. Also, to format code to display correctly on this site, you should select the entirety of your code, and then push the `{}` button in the editor (`ctrl` + `k` or `cmd` + `k` do the same thing).

Comment: Done, thanks guys. I put at the bottom which lines are not getting coverage.

Comment: N.B. `switch` statement would make this easier to read; also testing dates that depend on `Date.today()` is best done by using a class that maintains a property that you can dependency inject a fixed date during testing. This helps avoid TZ and midnight issues when test class runs