# Need help Schedule Test Class for tast create on Opportunity

Tags: apex, unit-test, class, schedule

I need help on the test class for this schedule on Opportunity. Getting error on below code with comment and only 35% coverage code.

```
global class OppJob_Task_1stPhoneFollowup implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {

     List<Opportunity> oppList = [Select ID, Post_1st_Follow_Up_cycle_days_ROPP__c, owner.id, owner.isactive, 
                                 Master_Opportunity__c, X2nd_Follow_Up_cycle_days_ROPP__c
                                 from Opportunity 
                                 where Master_Opportunity__c = null and 
                                 Renewal_Stage__c not in ('Renewed','Canceled','Pending Region') and 
                                 X2nd_Follow_Up_cycle_days_ROPP__c = NEXT_N_DAYS:1 ];
                                // X2nd_Follow_Up_cycle_days_ROPP__c = today ];
     List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

        For(Opportunity opp : oppList) {
      if(opp.Owner.isActive == true) {
                   Task newTask = new Task(
                         WhatId = opp.Id,
                        OwnerId = opp.OwnerId,
                   ActivityDate = opp.X2nd_Follow_Up_cycle_days_ROPP__c.adddays(1) ,
                        Subject = '1st Phone Follow-up',
                    Description = 'Call customer for 1st Phone Follow-up');
         taskList.add(newTask);
         }
        }
       system.debug('tasklink'+ tasklist.size());
    if (tasklist.size()>0){
        insert taskList;
    }
}}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class OppJob_Task_1stPhoneFollowupTest {
    static testmethod void testScheduledJob() {
        String CRON_EXP = '0 0 0 3 9 ? 2020';

        Account ac = TestingDataUtil.CreateAccounts(1)[0];
        insert ac;

        Opportunity opp = TestingDataUtil.CreateOpportunities(1, ac.Id, 'Renewal')[0];
        opp.SAP_Contract_Amount__c = 1200;
        opp.Master_Opportunity__c = null;
        opp.Renewal_Stage__c = 'Invoice Sent';
        opp.OwnerId = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
        insert opp;

        Test.StartTest();
        //Schedule the Test Job
        String jobID = System.schedule('OppJob_Task_1stPhoneFollowup123', CRON_EXP, new OppJob_Task_1stPhoneFollowup());
         Task newTask = new Task(
                         WhatId = opp.Id,
                        OwnerId = opp.OwnerId,
                     ActivityDate = date.valueOf('2019-12-24 11:30:20'),
                        Subject = '1st Phone Follow-up',
                    Description = 'Call customer for 1st Phone Follow-up');
        insert newtask;

   /**getting an error on this**
    Unexpected token 'opp.Id'
    Missing 'IDENTIFIER' at ']' 
    expecting a colon, found 'opp.Id'*
   */ 
     //error on this below//
      List<Task> lt = [SELECT Id, whatID FROM Task where whatid = opp.Id];     
      Test.stopTest();


    }    
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] this post to *be very specific* about the problem. Right now, the community cannot even tell if this test passes. We need you to help us help you. See [ask].

Comment: What is your question?  Please edit your post to include the details of your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is easily solved:

```
List<Task> lt = [SELECT Id, whatID FROM Task where whatid = opp.Id];
```

yields

> Unexpected token 'opp.Id'
>       Missing 'IDENTIFIER' at ']' 
>       expecting a colon, found 'opp.Id'*

because you can't put an Apex identifier (`opp.Id`) into a SOQL query without using *binding notation*: a colon prior to the identifier or expression, that is, `:opp.Id`.

See [Using Apex Variables in SOQL and SOSL Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm)
 for details on how to use Apex binding.

Making the test compile and pass will likely change your test coverage total. You should review the resources in [How do I increase my code coverage?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines) for more guidance on how to work with code coverage.

Comment: I have changes this and same error message:
List<Task> lt = [SELECT Id, whatID FROM Task where whatid :opp.Id];

Comment: @Smurfet The line you pasted above is incorrect because the = operator is missing.

Comment: thanks, I completely overlook and mistakenly ":=" to "=:" my bad....  it is working now...