# unable to cover try catch condition

Tags: apex

```
public class Cls_CheckDuplicateAsin {
  Public Id oppid;
  public list<serp__Opportunity_Research__c> serpOppReList;
  public Map<String,list<serp__Opportunity_Research__c>>  mapOppResearch ;
  public list<serp__Opportunity_Research__c> duplicateOppReList{get;set;}
  public List<WrapOppResearch> wraposearch{get; set;}
  public list<serp__Opportunity_Research__c> OppReListWithoutAsin{get;set;}

  public Cls_CheckDuplicateAsin(){
    serpOppReList = new list<serp__Opportunity_Research__c>();
    duplicateOppReList = new list<serp__Opportunity_Research__c>();
    mapOppResearch = New Map<String,list<serp__Opportunity_Research__c>>();
    OppReListWithoutAsin  = new list<serp__Opportunity_Research__c>();
  }

  public pagereference initMethod(){
   oppid = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
   try{
      OppReListWithoutAsin  =[Select id,Name,Parent_ASIN__c,Parent_Listing__c from serp__Opportunity_Research__c where serp__Opportunities__c =: oppid AND Parent_ASIN__c != null AND Parent_Listing__c =: null]; 
   }Catch(Exception e){
       System.Debug('e:'+e);
   }
   try{
      for(serp__Opportunity_Research__c oppResearch : [Select id,name,serp__ASIN__c,serp__Supplier_Title__c,B2C_SKU_FBA__c,serp__B2C_SKU__c from serp__Opportunity_Research__c where serp__Opportunities__c =: oppid AND serp__ASIN__c != null LIMIT:10000]){

           String key=oppResearch.serp__ASIN__c;
           serpOppReList=mapOppResearch.get(key);
           system.debug('**'+serpOppReList);
           if (null==serpOppReList)

           {
               serpOppReList=new List<serp__Opportunity_Research__c>();
               mapOppResearch.put(key,New list<serp__Opportunity_Research__c>{oppResearch});
           }else{
               serpOppReList.add(oppResearch );
           }
      }

      wraposearch =new List<WrapOppResearch>();
      for (String key : mapOppResearch.keySet())
      {
        if(mapOppResearch.get(key) != null && mapOppResearch.get(key).size() >1){
           WrapOppResearch gr=new WrapOppResearch();
           gr.oppr =mapOppResearch.get(key);
           gr.asinval=key;
           gr.removeRecord=False;
           wraposearch.add(gr);

        }
      }

    }Catch(Exception e){

    }
    return  null;
  }

  public pagereference cancel(){
    pagereference p = New pagereference('/'+oppid);
    p.setRedirect(true);
    return p;
  }
  public class WrapOppResearch{
      public List<serp__Opportunity_Research__c> oppr{get; set;}
      public String asinval{get; set;}
      public boolean removeRecord{get; set;}
 }
```

Comment: please narrow down the question, where you are stuck and what you tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines

Comment: Any time you write an exception handler, you should have some theory about what exception you are going to catch. On a quick read, I don't see any system exceptions that you can or should catch here - just possibly `NullPointerExceptions` caused by sloppy logic. If that's the concern, validate the logic and remove the handlers.

Answer (score 3):

It is hardly ever a good idea to have a try/catch with an empty catch block or a catch block that just logs. Your user will assume the action has worked when it has not, and then anyone trying to diagnose the problem will have little information to work from.

So rather than trying to cover them in a test, remove them as they are doing more harm than good.