# Need help with Test coverage of batch apex error- System.InvalidParameterValueException:

Tags: batch, code-coverage, failing-tests

I am trying to write a test class for the batch apex class, but i am getting an wierd error(System.InvalidParameterValueException: Provide the ID of a test-context sObject as the first parameter for setCreatedDate().) and i am able to extend the code coverage, write now my coverage is 28%, how do i extend to 100%

below is mt test class

```
global class Emailalertbatchclass implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Schedulable, Database.Stateful {

    //Variable Section
    global FINAL String strQuery;
    global FINAL String leadid;
    global List<String> errorMessages = new List<String>();

    global Emailalertbatchclass() { 
        this.strQuery = getBatchQuery();
    }

    //Returns the Query String to Batch constructor to fetch right records.
    private String getBatchQuery() {
        String strQuery = 'SELECT Id,Name,Status,Email,owner.email,owner.name,ownerid,No_Enquiry_Email_Sent__c,Manager_Email__c FROM Lead where No_Enquiry_Email_Sent__c=false AND Status=\'Enquiry\' And (CreatedDate = YESTERDAY OR LastModifiedDate = YESTERDAY) limit 1';
        return strQuery;
    }

    //Batch Start method
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(strQuery);
    }

    //Batch Execute method calls findCostForWoD method
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scopeList) {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, '== scopeList size ==' + scopeList.size());

        List<Lead> ld = (List<Lead>) scopeList;
        List<Lead> updatedld = new List<Lead>();
        if(!ld.isEmpty()) { 
            List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mailList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
            for (Lead prod : ld)
            {               
                // Step 1: Create a new Email
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

                // Step 2: Set list of people who should get the email
                String[] toAddresses = new String[] {prod.owner.Email,prod.Manager_Email__c,'chandra.s@proseraa.com'};
                    mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);

                // Step 3: Set who the email is sent from
                mail.setReplyTo(prod.owner.Email);
                mail.setSenderDisplayName('No Activity on Leads for 24hrs');

                // (Optional) Set list of people who should be CC'ed
                List<String> ccTo = new List<String>();
                ccTo.add('manjunath.s@proseraa.com');
                mail.setCcAddresses(ccTo);

                // Step 4. Set email contents - you can use variables!
                mail.setSubject('No Activity on Lead for 24hrs');
                String body = 'Dear ' + prod.owner.name + ', <br><br>';
                body += 'This is to notify you that there is no activity done on the respective <b> Lead Name: ';
                body +=prod.Name+'</b>  please find the link below..<br><br>';
                body += 'link to file: https://moengage--proseraa.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Lead/'+prod.id+'/view'+'<br><br><br> Thanks,<br>Moengage Team</body></html>';
                mail.setHtmlBody(body);

                // Step 5. Add your email to the master list
                mailList.add(mail);
                prod.No_Enquiry_Email_Sent__c = true;
                updatedld.add(prod);

            }
            if(!mailList.isEmpty()) {
                try{
                    Messaging.sendEmail(mailList);
                    update updatedld;
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    errorMessages.add('Unable to send email to Tech: '+ ex.getStackTraceString());
                }
            }
        }
    }  

    //Batch Finish method for after execution of batch work
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) { 

    }

    //Method which schedules the ProductDownloadBatch
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {        
        Emailalertbatchclass snInstance = new Emailalertbatchclass();
        ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(snInstance);
    }
}
```

My Test class

```
@isTest
public class EmailalertbatchclassTestclass
{
    static testMethod void testmethod1()
    {
        List<Lead> Leadld = New List<Lead>();
        lead ld = new lead();
        ld.RecordTypeId = '012p0000000Nn05AAC';
        ld.Company = 'Google';
        ld.FirstName= 'test';
        ld.LastName='Test2';
        ld.status='Enquiry';
        ld.Email = 'manjunath.s@proseraa.com';
        insert Leadld;

        Datetime yesterday = Datetime.now().addDays(-1); 
        Test.setCreatedDate(ld.Id, yesterday);

        Test.startTest();

        Emailalertbatchclass snInstance = new Emailalertbatchclass();
        ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(snInstance);

        Test.stopTest();
    }
    public static testMethod void testschedule() {
        Test.StartTest();
        Emailalertbatchclass sh1 = new Emailalertbatchclass();
        String sch = '0 00 01 * * ?'; 
        ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(sh1);
        String jobId = system.schedule('Emailalertbatchclass', sch, sh1);
        System.assert(jobId != null);
        Test.stopTest(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ld.Id` is `null` because you aren't really inserting it.

```
    List<Lead> Leadld = New List<Lead>();
    lead ld = new lead();
    ld.RecordTypeId = '012p0000000Nn05AAC';
    ld.Company = 'Google';
    // ... snipped ...
    insert Leadld;
```

The `Lead` object `ld` is not in the list `Leadld`, which is empty. Your `insert` therefore does nothing, and `ld.Id` remains `null`, which is why you get an error when you do

```
    Test.setCreatedDate(ld.Id, yesterday);
```

There are a number of other issues with this code I'd recommend following up on.

- You should be using schema methods to access your Record Type Id, not hard coding it.
- Your classes should not be `global` unless you are building a managed package and truly want them to be `global`.
- Your unit tests all should have meaningful assertions.
- You should never swallow exceptions and `System.debug()` them. You will trap meaningful exceptions and replace them with meaningless logs that are unlikely to surface the errors where they need to be seen.

Comment: i googled further and modified the code, now i am getting 97% code coverage, but i am not satisified with the code, can you please guide like how to write the perfect test class

Comment: Please review our [canonical resources](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines) on code coverage.