# Test Class for Apex Batch Job generating Invoices covers only 38%

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, code-coverage

Please help me to finish my Test Class for the following Batch Job generating Invoice creation.

**Apex Batch Job**

```
global class InvoiceGenerateBatchJob implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {


        return Database.getQueryLocator([
                SELECT Name, Id, Rent_Due_Date__c, Monthly_Rate__c, Property__c
                FROM Tenant__c
                WHERE Rent_Due_Date__c = TODAY
        ]);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Tenant__c> tenants) {

        List<Invoice__c> invoices = new List<Invoice__c>();

        for (Tenant__c tenant : tenants) {
            for(Invoice__c invoice : invoices){

                invoice.Bill_To_Tenant__c = tenant.Name;
                invoice.Due_Date__c = tenant.Rent_Due_Date__c;
                invoices.add(invoice);
            }
        }
        insert invoices;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

        AsyncApexJob job = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed,TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email
                            FROM AsyncApexJob
                            WHERE Id = :BC.getJobId()];
    }

}
```

**Scheduler Class For Batch Apex**

```
global class InvoiceGenerateBatchScheduled implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        InvoiceGenerateBatchJob invBatch = new InvoiceGenerateBatchJob();
        Database.executeBatch(invBatch, 200);

    }
}
```

**​​​​​​Testing Batch Apex Job and Scheduler Classes:**

```
@IsTest
private class InvoiceGenerateBatchTest {

    @TestSetup
    static void setupData() {

        List<Property__c> prop = new List<Property__c>();
        Property__c property = new Property__c();
        property.Name = 'Prop1';
        property.Business__c = 'Gov';
        prop.add(property);
        insert prop;

        List<Tenant__c> tenants = new List<Tenant__c>();
        for (Integer i = 1; i < 5; i++);{

            try {
                Tenant__c t = new Tenant__c();
                t.Name = 'TenOne';
                t.Property__c = [
                        SELECT Id
                        FROM Property__c
                        WHERE Name = 'Prop1'
                        LIMIT 5
                ].Id;
                tenants.add(t);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                insert tenants;
            }
        }
    }

    @IsTest
     static void testInvoiceGenerateBatch() {

     String CRON_EXP = '0 0 22 30 3 ?';
     Date dueDate = Date.today();

     Test.startTest();

     String jobId = System.schedule('CreateInvoice', CRON_EXP, new InvoiceGenerateBatchScheduled());
     Database.executeBatch(new InvoiceGenerateBatchJob());

     Test.stopTest();

     System.assertEquals(5, [SELECT COUNT() FROM Invoice__c WHERE Bill_To_Tenant__r.Name = 'TenOne']);

        }
    }
```

Comment: [How do I increase code coverage, or why can't I cover these lines](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines) may be a helpful resource.

Answer (score 0):

In your start Method filter is Rent_Due_Date__c = TODAY

In test class,You need to  provide the value for Rent Due date

```
    Tenant__c tenant = new Tenant__c();
    tenant.Name = 'TenOne';
    tenant.Rent_Due_Date__c = System.today();
    tenant.Property__c = property.Id;
    ten.add(tenant);
    insert ten;
 //Create Invoice records as well
```

If start method doesn't have any records,then execute method will not work

Comment: Thank you Annappa for your input. The Rent_due_Date is on Tenant object, so I have made the corrections to my code. But it is still covering only 76% and I'm expecting that 1 invoice will be created, but it shows 0.

Comment: yes thats on tenant object.  i have updated my answer. if it resolves your query make it as best answer and  close the question

Comment: So I've created Invoice records as well and technically the test has passed, but still shows only 76% of coverage. How can I make it 100%?

Comment: Please update new question. dont modify the original question

Comment: Please read [our canonical resource on test coverage](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines).

Comment: David Reed, Derek F, and Annappa PH, thank you all for your comments and links. Will note for future.