# Test code coverage for trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage, before-trigger

I have a tigger and I want to get code coverage of 100%. Could someone please explain me where I went wrong. I'm getting code coverage of 85% on trigger and 44% on handler class.

This line is in Red :   `OptNameUpd_Handler.befupd(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap, currentProfileId, cs);`
and this method is not called `befupd();`

trigger

```
trigger OptNameUpd on Opportunity (before update,before Insert) {
    Opportunity__c prof = Opportunity__c.getInstance('System Admin');
    Id currentProfileId = Userinfo.getProfileId();
    Id cs = prof.Profile__c; 
    if(trigger.IsBefore && trigger.IsUpdate){  
     OptNameUpd_Handler.befupd(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap, currentProfileId, cs);
    }else if(trigger.IsBefore && trigger.IsInsert){ 
    OptNameUpd_Handler.befIns(Trigger.new, currentProfileId, cs);
    } 
}
```

Trigger Handler

```
public class OptNameUpd_Handler {
    public static void befupd(List<Opportunity> newOpty, Map<Id,Opportunity> oldOptyMap, ID currentProfileId, ID cs){      
        Map<Id,Opportunity> optyList = oldOptyMap;
        if(currentProfileId==cs){
            for(Opportunity o:newOpty){
                if(o.Name!=optyList.get(o.Id).name){
                    if(o.Opportunity_Type__c=='Upsell'){
                        if(o.name.contains('Upsell')||o.name.contains('upsell')){
                            o.name = o.Name.remove('Upsell');
                            o.name = o.Name.remove('upsell');   
                        }
                        o.name = 'Upsell'+ ' ' + o.name;
                    }
                }     
            }  
        }
    }      
    public static void befIns(List<Opportunity> newOpty, ID currentProfileId, ID cs){
        if(currentProfileId==cs){
            for(Opportunity o:newOpty){
                if(o.Opportunity_Type__c=='Upsell'){
                    if(o.name.contains('Upsell')||o.name.contains('upsell')){
                        o.name = o.Name.remove('Upsell');
                        o.name = o.Name.remove('upsell');   
                    }
                    o.name = 'Upsell'+ ' ' + o.name;
                }
            }
        }     
    }    
}
```

Test Class

```
@IsTest(SeeAllData=true)
private  class OptNameUpdTestClass {
    @IsTest static void OptNameUpdTestClassins(){
        Opportunity__c prof = Opportunity__c.getInstance('System Admin');
        @TestVisible  Id currentProfileId = [Select Id,Name from Profile where Id=:Userinfo.getProfileId()].Id;
        @TestVisible  Id cs = prof.Profile__c;   
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp.name = 'Ashish Upsell';
        opp.Opportunity_Type__c = 'Upsell';
        opp.StageName = 'Open';
        insert opp;

        Opportunity opp1 = [Select id, Opportunity_Type__c,name from Opportunity where id=:opp.Id];
        opp1.name='Ashish 12 Upsell';
        opp1.Opportunity_Type__c = 'Upsell';
        update opp1;       
    } 
}
```

Comment: have you taken a look through [How do I increase my code coverage, or why can't I cover these lines?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines)

Comment: Are you sure that your code lines are being executed?  Have you checked your debug logs?

Comment: Your Code is probably throwing some exception before the update. Maybe at 
`insert opp;`. 
Check your Logs and Tests tab on the developer console to see more info.

Other Notes:
1) You don't need TestVisible annotation inside the test class. That is needed when you want to access private properties of a class that you are testing. Consult doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_testvisible.htm
4) It's not best practice to use SeeAllData, you'll probably have issues deploying. Though its not the cause of your current problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the insert DML is failing in the test method (possibly due to some missing required field). Due to insert failure, the SOQL query in your code might not fetch any record and the update DML never occurs. ***Did you check the test logs?*** Since you are testing the before insert operation, the test coverage will happen for the insert related method (even if the insert operation itself fails later).

Few best practices to avoid this:

- Use system.assert to ensure that the DML succeeded and the expected result was achieved.
- Use different records for unit testing on insert method vs update method.
- Its recommended to write unit test code for the trigger handler class, instead of writing for the trigger itself. This will help in isolating any possible errors due to DML operations.

Comment: Please don't ask for answer acceptance. The asker will decide that. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Yes my DML was failing due to required field closeDate. Thank you so much everyone.