# How to do code coverage for Trigger/create a test class and trigger handler for trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage, class

First, I am totally new to Apex Trigger, I'm still learning the Apex Class and Triggers.

I just found a code that actually works in our org. So what it does are below.

1. get the record type id and assigned it to recId
2. For the loop, for every new case created, if the case recordtype is equal to 'Booking', it will do a substring to get the value between the 'Corporate ID' and 'X' and put it to the custom field `Parse_Description_Assignment__c`

```java
trigger CaseTriggerBookingCase on Case (before insert) {
   Id recId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Booking').getRecordTypeId();
    for (Case c : trigger.new){
        if(C.RecordTypeId == recId){
            String data = c.Description;
            c.Parse_Description_Assignment__c = data.substringBetween('Corporate ID', 'X');
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I'm trying to deploy it from the sandbox to the production, it is requiring me to have code coverage.

I'm actually trying to formulate/create a trigger handler and a test class based on this [article](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301481/test-code-coverage-for-trigger) that I found.

Can someone please help/guide me on how can I accomplish this?

Hi there,

Just want to update you all that I was able to create a test case and successfully run a test. However, it only covers the codes highlighted in blue. May I know how can I write a code for codes highlighted in red?[image] btw, thanks to @identigral for sending the link on how to create a unit-code/test class

```java
@isTest
private class TestCaseTriggerBookingCase {
    @isTest static void CaseParseDescription() {
        Case createCase = new Case (Subject = 'Test Booking Case for Apex Class and Trigger Unit Test');
        insert createCase;

        createCase = [select Id, Subject from Case where Subject = :createCase.Subject];
        System.assertEquals(createCase.Subject, 'Test Booking Case for Apex Class and Trigger Unit Test');
    }
}
```

Hi @elkaco Thank you so much for your help!

I was able to get the 100% coverage for the trigger below.

[image]

By following your code below. [image]

@isTest

private class TestCaseTriggerBookingCase {

```
@isTest static void CaseParseDescription() {
    
  Case createCase = new Case();
    createCase.Status='New';
    createCase.Subject='Test 2 Booking Case for Apex Class and Trigger Unit Test, please disregard';
    createCase.Description='Corporate ID 323 X Visit';
    createCase.recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Booking').getRecordTypeId();
      insert createCase;
    Case newcreateCase=[SELECT Id, Parse_Description_Assignment__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :createCase.Id];
    System.assertEquals('323',createCase.Parse_Description_Assignment__c );
```

}
}
However, I'm getting this error.

System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 323, Actual: null

Comment: Yes, it's really  helpful but I'm still missing some logic in my codes.

Comment: The lines highlighted in red are "uncovered" because the case record you're creating in your unit test does not have the record type specified in your business logic.

Comment: N.B. Pro Tip: change the variable name `recId` to `bookingRecordTypeId` for clarity

Comment: Thanks @cropredy

Answer (score 1):

In order to get code coverage for your trigger, you should create an Apex Test class.

An example:

```
    @isTest
    public class CaseTriggerBookingCaseTest {
    @isTest
    static void testBookingCase() {
        Case c = new Case();
        c.Status = 'New';
        c.Origin = 'Phone';
        c.Subject = 'Test testBookingCase 1';
        c.Description = 'Corporate Id: 1234567890 X random text';
        c.recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Booking').getRecordTypeId();

        insert c;
        Case newCase = [SELECT Id, Parse_Description_Assignment__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :c.Id];

        system.assertEquals(': 1234567890 ', newCase.Parse_Description_Assignment__c, 'The value should be 1234567890');

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add "        c.recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Booking').getRecordTypeId();" into the test method you edited your question, otherwise it's using the default Case Record Type that is not 'Booking'

Comment: Hi @elkaco Thank you so much for your help. The trigger codes below are now completely highlighted in blue or the code coverage: All Test 100%

trigger CaseTriggerBookingCase on Case (before insert) {
   Id recId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Booking').getRecordTypeId();
    for (Case C:trigger.new)
    {
        if(C.RecordTypeId==recId){
            String data=C.Description;
            C.Parse_Description_Assignment__c=data.substringBetween('Corporate ID', 'X');
        }
    }
}

Comment: However, I'm getting this error System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: The value should be 323: Expected: : 323, Actual: null

I followed your instructions to update my TestCaseTriggerBookingCase class.

Comment: I just updated my response to have the newCase in the System.assertEquals. If it answered your question, please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Case newCase = [SELECT Id, Parse_Description_Assignment__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :c.Id];

    system.assertEquals(': 1234567890 ', c.Parse_Description_Assignment__c, 'The value should be 1234567890');
```

Found the solution. I updated it below. If you will noticed the query variable c has been changed to newCase.

system.assertEquals(': 1234567890 ', newCase.Parse_Description_Assignment__c, 'The value should be 1234567890');