# Creating Trigger and Test Class for it. "Overall Code Coverage" always 0%

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

I have created following trigger:

```
Trigger updateTotalAddCost on Ad_Cost__c(after insert) {

  for (Ad_Cost__c a:Trigger.new) {

    Campaign SearchCampaign = [SELECT Id, Name, Ad_Cost__c FROM Campaign WHERE Id =: a.Campaign__c LIMIT 1];

    List<AggregateResult> TotalCostForCampaign = [SELECT SUM(Ad_Cost__c)Total FROM Ad_Cost__c WHERE Campaign__c =: SearchCampaign.Id];
    Decimal TotalCampaignCost = (Decimal)TotalCostForCampaign[0].get('Total');

    SearchCampaign.Ad_Cost__c = TotalCampaignCost;
    update SearchCampaign;

  }
  
}
```

Test class for this trigger looks as follow:

```
@isTest
private class TestupdateTotalAddCost {

  @isTest static void  testIfRecordExistsTrue() {

    Campaign campaignCreate = new Campaign(Name='Test Campaign');
    insert campaignCreate;

    Campaign SearchCampaign = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Campaign WHERE Id =: campaignCreate.Id LIMIT 1];

    System.assertEquals(true, SearchCampaign.isSet(Campaign.Name));    
    
  }
  
}
```

When in developer console I do "Test" > "New Run" and run the test, I always get "Overall Code Coverage" 0%
What am I doing wrong or what is missing, please.

----Update of test class (after suggestion)---

I have modified test class (thanks for the tip).
Now I get overall code coverage 7%
For trigger itself I get 100%

[image]

```
@isTest
private class TestupdateTotalAddCost {

  @isTest static void  testIfRecordExistsTrue() {

    Campaign campaignCreate = new Campaign(Name='Test Campaign');
    insert campaignCreate;

    Ad_Cost__c adCostCreate = new Ad_Cost__c(Campaign__c=campaignCreate.Id, Posted_Date__c=date.today());
    insert adCostCreate;

    Campaign SearchCampaign = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Campaign WHERE Id =: campaignCreate.Id LIMIT 1];

    System.assertEquals(true, SearchCampaign.isSet(Campaign.Name));    
    
  }
  
}
```

When I deploy it I get error "The following triggers have 0% code coverage. Each trigger must have at least 1% code coverage."

Please again for suggestion :)

Comment: Your trigger runs when your custom object `Ad_Cost__c` is inserted. So you need to do an insert in your test. Once you've got this working, the next step will be to move the `Campaign` query out of the loop in your trigger so the trigger works for bulk cases.

Comment: @Keith C, thanks I have updated test trigger but now when I deploy I get 0% coverage. TY

Comment: @user3299199 I'd recommend taking a look through [How do I increase my code coverage, or why can't I cover these lines?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines) if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Are you deploying the test class with the trigger? Are you running the test class during the deploymetn?

Comment: @DavidReed, Thank you very much, I did nod add my test class to the deployment.