# How to cover the below lines of code in a test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test

Please help me in order to write the test class for the below lines of code:

Id objUser = UserInfo.getUserId();

UserRecordAccess objRecordAccess = [Select RecordId, HasEditAccess From UserRecordAccess Where UserId =: UserInfo.getUserId() And RecordId =: objRecordId];

Note: objRecordId is an Id passed as an argument to the method

Comment: I wanted solution for this as I tried many ways but couldn't succeed for these statements...

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest re-framing your question so it doesn't sound like a "write my test for me" request. It's also likely impossible to help you with so little context. This site thirves on details and sharing what you've tried so far. You should also read through [How do I increase code coverage, or why can't I cover these lines?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines)

Comment: Thanks... I edited ...

Comment: Please include _what you have tried so far_ to test this code. Since your tests run as a user, this should not be too tricky to test.

Comment: I tried this way: UserRecordAccess objUser = [Select RecordId, HasEditAccess from UserRecordAccess where HasEditAccess =: true And RecordId =: UserInfo.getUserId()];

Comment: But this is not working can you help me with proper solution on the same

Comment: That is just code. Have you written a unit test?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, just coverage the method.

Class

```
public with sharing class UserRecord{
    public static void verify(Id objRecordId){
        UserRecordAccess objRecordAccess = [Select RecordId, HasEditAccess
                                            From UserRecordAccess 
                                            Where UserId = :UserInfo.getUserId() And RecordId = :objRecordId];
        system.debug(objRecordAccess);
    }
}
```

Test
@isTest
public with sharing class UserRecordTest{
@IsTest
static void methodName(){

```
        Test.startTest();
        Account ac = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
        insert ac;

        UserRecord.verify(ac.Id);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```