# Code Coverage Failure Your code coverage is 73%. You need at least 75% coverage to complete this deployment

Tags: apex, unit-test, deployment, code-coverage, compile

I did run all tests in my sandbox and also tried to run them each individually - the overall avg code coverage is around 88%. However, when i try to validate my change set in prod, it is throwing an error saying "Code Coverage Failure
Your code coverage is 73%. You need at least 75% coverage to complete this deployment."

None of the test classes failed. Now i'm stuck at a place where it is unable to show what's causing this error nor any directives.

I would really appreciate your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be poorly written tests. For example, some tests may be failing on validation rules, but the errors were swallowed by an indiscriminate try-catch block. You'll want to do a Run All Tests and check the results. If you have [Salesforce DX](https://developer.salesforce.com/platform/dx), it's as simple as:

```
sfdx force:apex:test:run -r human -c -w 100 -l RunLocalTests
```

This will (eventually) give you a report that includes code coverage, lines not covered, and overall percentage. You can use this knowledge to track down which lines of code are not covered and need improvement. Once you have that, you'll need to improve your coverage by fixing tests or bad logic until you get a high enough coverage.

You can read more tips [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/244794/2984).