# System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject. How to resolve it

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I have created a Test Class for below class. I am getting "System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject" error. I have tried a lot but no luck.

Class:

```
public class ItemSetupNewVersionController {
    
    /*Description: 
     * This method is used for cloning item setup record from parent record
     * Creating new case record for new Item setup
     * Creating new itemCaseRelation for new case record
     * Creating new Case Product RelationShips for new case record
     */ 
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void itemSetupClone(String recordId){ 
        Boolean isItprocessed = false;  
        Map<String, Integer> parentItemSetupMap = new Map<String, Integer>();         
        Case__c newCase = new Case__c();
        List<CaseICIXProductRelationship__c> newCaseProductList = new List<CaseICIXProductRelationship__c>();   
        List<String> fieldAPINames = new List<String>(Schema.SObjectType.Item_Setup__c.fields.getMap().keySet());
        String query = 'SELECT Case__r.Name, Case__r.Case_Description__c, Case__r.Pre_Listing_Case_Number__c, Case__r.Case_Content__c, Case__r.ELWIS_Case_Number__c, Case__r.EKS_Case_Number__c, Case__r.Category_Group_Item_Family__c, Case__r.Temporary_Unique_Key__c, Case__r.Case_version__c, (SELECT Id, ParentId__c FROM Item_setup__r),'+String.join(fieldAPINames,',')+ ' FROM Item_Setup__c WHERE Id=:recordId';  
        Item_Setup__c parentItemSetup = Database.query(query);
        parentItemSetupMap.put(parentItemSetup.ParentId__c == null?recordId:parentItemSetup.ParentId__c, parentItemSetup.ParentId__c == null?parentItemSetup.Item_setup__r.size():[SELECT (SELECT Id,ParentId__c from Item_setup__r) FROM Item_Setup__c WHERE Id =: parentItemSetup.ParentId__c].Item_setup__r.size());        
        // New Case record insertion
        if(parentItemSetup.Case__c != null){
           newCase = new Case__c(Name = parentItemSetup.Case__r.Name , Case_Version__c = parentItemSetup.ParentId__c == null?false:true, Case_Description__c = parentItemSetup.Case__r.Case_Description__c, Pre_Listing_Case_Number__c = parentItemSetup.Case__r.Pre_Listing_Case_Number__c, Case_Content__c = parentItemSetup.Case__r.Case_Content__c, ELWIS_Case_Number__c = parentItemSetup.Case__r.ELWIS_Case_Number__c, EKS_Case_Number__c = parentItemSetup.Case__r.EKS_Case_Number__c, Category_Group_Item_Family__c = parentItemSetup.Case__r.Category_Group_Item_Family__c,Temporary_Unique_Key__c = parentItemSetup.ParentId__c == null?parentItemSetup.Case__r.Temporary_Unique_Key__c+'_v'+(parentItemSetupMap.get(recordId)+1):parentItemSetup.Case__r.Temporary_Unique_Key__c.split('_v')[0]+'_v'+(parentItemSetupMap.get(parentItemSetup.ParentId__c)+1));  
            try{
                insert newCase;
            }catch(exception ex){
                System.debug('ItemSetupNewVersionController:itemSetupClone:case Error: '+ex.getMessage());
                throw new AuraHandledException('There is an Exception while inserting case records: '+ex.getMessage());
            }            
    
        }
  
        // Item Setup clone
        Item_Setup__c newItemSetup = parentItemSetup.clone();
        newItemSetup.Name = parentItemSetup.ParentId__c == null?parentItemSetup.Name+'_v'+(parentItemSetupMap.get(recordId)+1):parentItemSetup.Name.split('_v')[0]+'_v'+(parentItemSetupMap.get(parentItemSetup.ParentId__c)+1);       
        newItemSetup.Id = null;
        newItemSetup.Contract_Log_Created__c = false;
        newItemSetup.Valid_From_Verified__c = false;
        newItemSetup.Approved_by_Buyer__c = false;
        newItemSetup.Approved_by_MD__c = false;
        newItemSetup.Item__c = parentItemSetup.Item__c;
        newItemSetup.Case__c = newCase.Id;  
        if(parentItemSetup.ParentId__c == null){
           newItemSetup.ParentId__c = recordId;  
        }
        if(parentItemSetup.Processed__c){
            //Updating the Pricing Information on ItemSetup Record from SQL Server inorder to Populate the same on to the FORM
            List<SQLServerConnector.updateFieldsWrapperClass> pricingInfo = SQLServerConnector.getPricingInfo(recordId);
                                
            for(SQLServerConnector.updateFieldsWrapperClass wrap: pricingInfo){
                newItemSetup.put(wrap.fieldAPI,wrap.fieldValue);
            } 
            
        }              
            try{
                insert newItemSetup;
            }
            catch(exception ex){
                System.debug('ItemSetupNewVersionController:itemSetupClone:case Error: '+ex.getMessage());
                throw new AuraHandledException('There is an Exception while inserting Item Setup records: '+ex.getMessage());
            }
      
          // New itemCaseRelation insertion  
          ItemCaseRelationship__c itemCaseRelation = new ItemCaseRelationship__c ( Case__c = newCase.Id, Item__c = parentItemSetup.Item__c);
              
            try{
                insert itemCaseRelation; 
            }
            catch(exception ex){
                System.debug('ItemSetupNewVersionController:itemSetupClone:Item Case Relationship Error: '+ex.getMessage());
                throw new AuraHandledException('There is an Exception while inserting Item Case Relationship records: '+ex.getMessage());
                
            }
            
    
        //Insertion of new Case Product RelationShips
     
            CaseICIXProductRelationship__c newCaseProduct;
            for(CaseICIXProductRelationship__c caseProduct: [SELECT Id,case__c,ICIX_Product__c,Units_Per_Case__c,Product_UPC__c,Brand_Name__c,Number_of_Units_in_a_Pack__c,Pack_Size_a__c,Unit_of_Measure_a__c,Package_Type_a__c,Product_Long_Description__c FROM CaseICIXProductRelationship__c WHERE Case__c  =:parentItemSetup.Case__c]){
                newCaseProduct = caseProduct.clone();
                newCaseProduct.case__c = newCase.Id;
                newCaseProduct.Id = null;
                newCaseProductList.add(newCaseProduct);
            } 
            
            if(newCaseProductList.size()>0 && !newCaseProductList.isEmpty()){
                try{
                    insert newCaseProductList; 
                    
                }
                catch(exception ex){
                    System.debug('ItemSetupNewVersionController:itemSetupClone:Case ICIXProduct Relationship Error'+ex.getMessage());
                    throw new AuraHandledException('There is an Exception while inserting Case ICIXProduct Relationship records: '+ex.getMessage());
                }
                
            }  
 
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class ItemSetupNewVersionController_Test {
  
 static testMethod void test1(){
   
    List<User> userList = new List<User>();
    system.runAs(new User(Id=UserInfo.getUserId()))
       {
          String orgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
          String dateString = String.valueof(Datetime.now()).replace(' ','').replace(':','').replace('-','');
          Integer randomInt = Integer.valueOf(math.rint(math.random()*1000000));
          String uniqueName = orgId + dateString + randomInt;
          Profile p = [select id FROM Profile WHERE Name ='System Administrator'];
          Profile SU = [select id FROM Profile WHERE Name ='Standard User'];
          UserRole bd = [select id FROM UserRole WHERE Name ='Buyer'];
          UserRole b = [select id FROM UserRole WHERE Name ='Buying Director'];
          userList.add(new User(
            FirstName = 'Selena', 
            LastName = 'Kyle',
            Username = uniqueName + '@test' + orgId + '.org', 
            Email = uniqueName + '@test' + orgId + '.org', 
            Alias = 'Cats_',             
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles', 
            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', 
            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8', 
            ProfileId = p.Id, 
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
            UserRoleId = b.Id
        ));
           dateString = String.valueof(Datetime.now()).replace(' ','').replace(':','').replace('-','');
           randomInt = Integer.valueOf(math.rint(math.random()*1000000));
           uniqueName = orgId + dateString + randomInt;
         
          insert userList;
          System.debug(userList);
       }
  
        //Case Data
         List<Case__c> caseList = new List<Case__c>();
          caseList.add(new Case__c(
          Status__c = 'New',  
          Pre_Listing_Case_Number__c='123',                               // Status
          Name = '4444UATLIDLCase1',                          // Case Name
          Case_Description__c = 'Case Short Description -CASE',
          Mixed_Case__c = 'Yes',                               // Mixed Case
          Case_Contents_In_Unit__c = '11',                     // Case Pack
          ELWIS_Case_Number__c = 'elwis9817case',                // ELWIS Case Number (Admin Only)
          EKS_Case_Number__c = 'eks9817case',                    // EKS Case Number (Admin Only)
          Temporary_Unique_Key__c='4444UATLIDLCase1',
          Case_version__c=true,
          All__c = false,                                      // All
          GRM__c = true,                                       // GRM
          ATL__c = false,                                      // ATL
          PYE__c = false,                                      // PYE
          FRG__c = true,                                       // FRG
          Case_Content__c='test',
          Comment__c = '--',                                   // Comment
          Category_Group_Item_Family__c='90',
          Minimum_Order_Quantity__c = '11',                    // Minimum Order Quantity
          Minimum_Order_Quantity_Unit_of_Measure__c = 'Case'  // Minimum Order Quantity Unit of Measure
        ));
        
        caseList.add(new Case__c(
          Name = '5555UATLIDLCase2',                             // Case Name
          Pre_Listing_Case_Number__c='123', 
          Mixed_Case__c = 'Yes',                                 // Mixed Case
          Case_Description__c = 'Case Short Description -CASE',  // Case Short Description (Admin Only)
          ELWIS_Case_Number__c = 'elwis9817case',                // ELWIS Case Number (Admin Only)
          EKS_Case_Number__c = 'eks9817case',                    // EKS Case Number (Admin Only)
          Planned_Listing_Week__c = '1744',                      // Planned Listing Week (YYWW)
          All__c = false,                                        // All
          GRM__c = false,                                        // GRM
          Case_Content__c='12',
          Case_version__c=true,
          Temporary_Unique_Key__c='5555UATLIDLCase2',
          ATL__c = true,                                         // ATL
          PYE__c = true,                                         // PYE
          FRG__c = true,                                         // FRG
          Category_Group_Item_Family__c='90',
          Comment__c = 'case comment_9817'                      // Comment
        ));
        
          insert caseList;
          system.assertEquals(true,caseList.size()>0);
         
         //Item data
          List<Item__c> itemlist =new List<Item__c>();
          itemlist.add(new Item__c(
          Status__c = 'Listed',                                                                       // Status
          Name = '00 Test Product2',                                                                                 // Item Name
          Parallel_Listed_Article__c = false,                                                           // Parallel Listed Item
          Listing_Type__c = 'Core Range',                                                               // Listing Type
          Remaining_Shelf_Life_Upon_Delivery__c = '12',                                                 // Remaining Shelf Life Upon Delivery
          Days_Months__c = 'Months',                                                                    // Days/Months
          Shipper_Display__c = false,                                                                   // Shipper (Display)
          Approval_Status__c = 'Change -Rejected',                                                      // Approval Status
          Submitter__c = userList[0].id,                                                          // Submitter
          Status_Flag__c = 'Record Changed',                                                            // Status Flag
          Sent_for_Approval__c = 'No',                                                                  // Sent for Approval
          Item_Description__c = 'Test record Please ignore this if anybody received an email',          // Item Short Description (Admin Only)
          German_Item_Description__c = 'Test record Please ignore this if anybody received an email.',  // German Item Description (Admin Only)
          Minimum_Order_Quantity__c = '1',                                                              // Minimum Order Quantity
          Minimum_Order_Quantity_Unit_of_Measure__c = 'Case',                                           // Minimum Order Quantity Unit of Measure
          Pallet_Factor__c = '20',                                                                      // Pallet Factor
          Planned_Retail_Price__c = '42',                                                               // Planned Retail Price
          Units_Per_Store_Per_Week__c = '21',                                                           // Units Per Store Per Week
          Comment__c = '--'                                                                            // Comment
        ));
       
        itemlist.add(new Item__c(
          Status__c = 'Listed',                                // Status
          Name = 'Demo Cookie Item 123',                                      // Item Name
          Parallel_Listed_Article__c = false,                    // Parallel Listed Item
          Shipper_Display__c = false,                            // Shipper (Display)
          Approval_Status__c = 'Change -Rejected',               // Approval Status
          Submitter__c = ' userList[0].Id',                   // Submitter
          Status_Flag__c = 'No Change',                          // Status Flag
          Sent_for_Approval__c = 'No',                           // Sent for Approval
          Item_Description__c = 'Test Demo Cookie ITem',         // Item Short Description (Admin Only)
          Minimum_Order_Quantity__c = '200',                     // Minimum Order Quantity
          Minimum_Order_Quantity_Unit_of_Measure__c = 'Pallet',  // Minimum Order Quantity Unit of Measure
          Comment__c = '--'                                     // Comment
        ));
         
         insert itemlist;
   
   
    //Supplier data
    //
    List<Account>  supList = new List<Account>();
         supList.add(new Account(
          Name = 'QA Sup 6 v2.43 SB',
          Phone = '(765) 541-0786',              // Phone
          Website = 'http://www.kmbrandsinc.com',  // Website
           ICIX_V1__Internal__c =false,
             ICIX_V1__Status__c='Active',
           Supplier_Type__c = 'US Trading'
             
        ));
        supList.add( new Account(
         Name = 'DemoLidil0131002',
          Phone = '(765) 541-0786',              // Phone
          Website = 'http://www.kmbrandsinc.com',  // Website
            ICIX_V1__Internal__c = false,
            ICIX_V1__Status__c = 'Active'
        ));
        supList.add(new Account(
         Name = 'IKEA POC SB ',
          Phone = '(765) 541-0786',              // Phone
          Website = 'http://www.kmbrandsinc.com'  // Website
           
        ));
        insert supList;
        
       List<Item_Setup__c> itemsetuplist=new List<Item_Setup__c>();
       String recordId;
       List<Id> isid= new List<Id>();  
       Item_Setup__c itm_setup = ICIXTestdatafactory.CreateItemSetUp(); 
        itm_setup.Name = '4444UATLIDLItemSetup1';
        itm_setup.Buying_Price__c = 'testsetup';
        itm_setup.Item__c = itemlist[0].Id;
        itm_setup.Case__c = caseList[0].Id;
        itm_setup.Distributor_Name__c = 'testsetup';
        itm_setup.Valid_From_Date_Approximate__c = 'Yes';
        itm_setup.Valid_to__c = Date.today();
        itm_setup.Buyer_Comments2__c = 'Testing Comments';
        itm_setup.Valid_from__c = Date.today();
        itm_setup.Selected_Supplier__c = supList[0].id;
        itm_setup.Brand_Name__c = 'testname';
        itm_setup.Fixed_Quantity__c = '123';
        itm_setup.Processed__c = false;
        itm_setup.BuyingPrice_ALL__c = 10.25;
        itm_setup.BuyingPrice_FRG__c = 200.00;
        itm_setup.ParentId__c = null;
        
        Item_Setup__c itm_setup2 = ICIXTestdatafactory.CreateItemSetUp(); 
        itm_setup2.Name = 'testsetupPushDataReq1';
        itm_setup2.Buying_Price__c = 'testsetup';
        itm_setup2.Item__c = itm_setup.Item__c;
        itm_setup2.Case__c = itm_setup.Case__c;
        itm_setup2.Distributor_Name__c = 'testsetup';
        itm_setup2.Valid_From_Date_Approximate__c = 'Yes';
        itm_setup2.Valid_to__c = Date.today();
        itm_setup2.Buyer_Comments2__c = 'Testing Comments';
        itm_setup2.Valid_from__c = Date.today();
        itm_setup2.Selected_Supplier__c = supList[0].id;
        itm_setup2.Brand_Name__c = 'testname';
        itm_setup2.Fixed_Quantity__c = '123';
        itm_setup2.Processed__c = false;
        itm_setup2.BuyingPrice_ALL__c = 10.25;
        itm_setup2.BuyingPrice_FRG__c = 200.00;
        itm_setup2.ParentId__c=itm_setup.Id;
        itemsetuplist.add(itm_setup);
        itemsetuplist.add(itm_setup2);
        insert itemsetuplist;
        isid.add(itm_setup.Id);
        isid.add(itm_setup2.Id);
      
        recordId='itm_setup.Id';
        Map<String, Integer> parentItemSetupMap = new Map<String, Integer>(); 
        List<String> fieldAPINames = new List<String>(Schema.SObjectType.Item_Setup__c.fields.getMap().keySet());   
        Item_Setup__c parentItemSetup  =[SELECT Item__c,Case__r.Name, Case__r.Case_Description__c, Case__r.Pre_Listing_Case_Number__c, Case__r.Case_Content__c, Case__r.ELWIS_Case_Number__c, Case__r.EKS_Case_Number__c, Case__r.Category_Group_Item_Family__c, Case__r.Temporary_Unique_Key__c, Case__r.Case_version__c, ParentId__c,(SELECT Id, ParentId__c FROM Item_setup__r) FROM Item_Setup__c WHERE Id in:isid LIMIT 1];  
        parentItemSetupMap.put(recordId,parentItemSetup.Item_setup__r.size());
       
        parentItemSetup.Case__c=caseList[0].Id;
        update parentItemSetup;
        system.assertEquals(true,parentItemSetup.Case__c!=null);
        system.assertEquals(true,parentItemSetup.ParentId__c == null);
        
        Case__c newCase = new Case__c();
        if(parentItemSetup.Case__c != null){
           newCase = new Case__c(Name = parentItemSetup.Case__r.Name , Case_Version__c = false, Case_Description__c = parentItemSetup.Case__r.Case_Description__c, Pre_Listing_Case_Number__c = parentItemSetup.Case__r.Pre_Listing_Case_Number__c, Case_Content__c = parentItemSetup.Case__r.Case_Content__c, ELWIS_Case_Number__c = parentItemSetup.Case__r.ELWIS_Case_Number__c, EKS_Case_Number__c = parentItemSetup.Case__r.EKS_Case_Number__c, Category_Group_Item_Family__c = parentItemSetup.Case__r.Category_Group_Item_Family__c, Temporary_Unique_Key__c = parentItemSetup.Case__r.Temporary_Unique_Key__c);  
            try{
                insert newCase;
            }catch(exception ex){
                System.debug('ItemSetupNewVersionController:itemSetupClone:case Error: '+ex.getMessage());
                throw new AuraHandledException('There is an Exception while inserting case records: '+ex.getMessage());
            }
            
            
         // Item Setup clone
        Item_Setup__c newItemSetup = parentItemSetup.clone();
        newItemSetup.Name='4444UATLIDLItemSetup1_v1';       
        //newItemSetup.Id = 'a2Y6C0000003HLqUAM';
        newItemSetup.Contract_Log_Created__c = false;
        newItemSetup.Valid_From_Verified__c = false;
        newItemSetup.Approved_by_Buyer__c = false;
        newItemSetup.Approved_by_MD__c = false;
        newItemSetup.Item__c = parentItemSetup.Item__c;
        newItemSetup.Case__c = parentItemSetup.Case__c ;
        newItemSetup.ParentId__c=parentItemSetup.Id;
        insert newItemSetup;

       //ItemSetupNewVersionController.itemSetupClone('');
       
        //item case data
         
        List<ItemCaseRelationship__c>  itemCaseRelationList = new List<ItemCaseRelationship__c>();
        itemCaseRelationList.add(new ItemCaseRelationship__c(Case__c = newCase.Id, Item__c=parentItemSetup.Item__c));
        
        insert itemCaseRelationList;
        
        
       //Product data
       List<ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c> productList = new List<ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c> ();

       productList.add( new ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c(name='100% Apple Juice',Catch_Weight__c=true,
                                                       Approval_Status__c='Change -Awaiting Approval',Approver__c=userList[0].id,
                                                       Submitter__c=userList[0].id,Sent_for_Approval__c='No',
                                                       OldJson__c='null'));
            
       productList.add(new ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c(name='Sample Test Product',Catch_Weight__c=false,
                                                      Approval_Status__c='Pending Approval',Approver__c=userList[0].id,
                                                      Submitter__c=userList[0].id,Sent_for_Approval__c='Yes',
                                                      OldJson__c='{"attributes":{"type":"ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c"},"Remaining_Shelf_Life_upon_Delivery__c":"24","Days_Months__c":"Months","Current_Status__c":"New"}'));
       insert productList;
    
       //caseproduct data
       List<CaseICIXProductRelationship__c> caseProRelation = new List<CaseICIXProductRelationship__c>(); 
       caseProRelation.add(new CaseICIXProductRelationship__c(Case__c=parentItemSetup.Case__c, ICIX_Product__c =productList[0].Id,Pack_Size_a__c='apx. 2.00',Unit_of_Measure_a__c='lb',Package_Type_a__c='TRAY',Product_Long_Description__c='Test',
       OldJson__c='null'));
  
       caseProRelation.add(new CaseICIXProductRelationship__c(Case__c=parentItemSetup.Case__c, ICIX_Product__c =productList[0].Id,Pack_Size_a__c='apx. 2.00',Unit_of_Measure_a__c='lb',Package_Type_a__c='TRAY',Product_Long_Description__c='Test',
       OldJson__c='{"attributes":{"type":"CaseICIXProductRelationship__c"},"Units_Per_Case__c":12.00}'));
    
      CaseICIXProductRelationship__c newCaseProduct;
            for(CaseICIXProductRelationship__c caseProduct: [SELECT Id,case__c,ICIX_Product__c,Units_Per_Case__c,Product_UPC__c,Brand_Name__c,Number_of_Units_in_a_Pack__c,Pack_Size_a__c,Unit_of_Measure_a__c,Package_Type_a__c,Product_Long_Description__c FROM CaseICIXProductRelationship__c WHERE Case__c  =:parentItemSetup.Case__c]){
                newCaseProduct = caseProduct.clone();
                newCaseProduct.case__c = newCase.Id;
                newCaseProduct.Id = null;
                caseProRelation.add(newCaseProduct);
            } 
            
      if(caseProRelation.size()>0 && !caseProRelation.isEmpty()){
                
        insert caseProRelation; 
       
      List< Case__c> cs= [SELECT Name, Case_Description__c, Pre_Listing_Case_Number__c, Case_Content__c, ELWIS_Case_Number__c, EKS_Case_Number__c, Category_Group_Item_Family__c, Temporary_Unique_Key__c FROM Case__c ] ;  
      List<Item__c> it=[SELECT Status__c ,Name,Parallel_Listed_Article__c,Shipper_Display__c , Approval_Status__c,Submitter__c , Status_Flag__c , Sent_for_Approval__c, Item_Description__c, Minimum_Order_Quantity_Unit_of_Measure__c, Minimum_Order_Quantity__c,  Comment__c From Item__c];                   
       
      List<Item_Setup__c> is = [SELECT Item__c,Case__r.Name, Case__r.Case_Description__c, Case__r.Pre_Listing_Case_Number__c, Case__r.Case_Content__c, Case__r.ELWIS_Case_Number__c, Case__r.EKS_Case_Number__c, Case__r.Category_Group_Item_Family__c, Case__r.Temporary_Unique_Key__c, Case__r.Case_version__c,ParentId__c, (SELECT Id, ParentId__c FROM Item_setup__r) FROM Item_Setup__c Where Id in:isid ] ;  
      List<CaseICIXProductRelationship__c> caseProduct=[SELECT Id,case__c,ICIX_Product__c,Units_Per_Case__c,Product_UPC__c,Brand_Name__c,Number_of_Units_in_a_Pack__c,Pack_Size_a__c,Unit_of_Measure_a__c,Package_Type_a__c,Product_Long_Description__c FROM CaseICIXProductRelationship__c];
      
      ItemSetupNewVersionController.itemSetupClone('is.ParentId__c');
          
          
     }   
  }            
}
```

---

I am getting error at this line
`Item_Setup__c parentItemSetup = Database.query(query);`

I tried lot but unable to resolve the error my code coverage is 16%. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Alternatively, does this answer your question? [How do I increase my code coverage, or why can't I cover these lines](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines)

Comment: @PhilW I already gone through this but it is not helping in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class being tested is expecting an Id, but your test is not passing an Id.

The issue is on the last line of code in your test class: `ItemSetupNewVersionController.itemSetupClone('is.ParentId__c');`

enclosing things in single quotes makes it a string, so you're literally passing "is.ParentId__c" to the method you're testing (instead of the id of the record). You could verify this by placing a system.debug() at the start of your method (to print the value of the "recordId" argument) and looking at the debug log for the test.

Remove the single quotes, and it should work.

+edit:

PhilW pointed out that `is` is a List rather than a single instance. In that case, you would need to use `is[0].ParentId__c`.

If that doesn't work, then you likely need to set up additional test data so that your query does return a record.

As a side note, you should strongly consider improving your variable names to be more descriptive (and accurate). Variable names like `is` gives little to no indication of what the variable holds, or what it's used for. `itemSetupList` would be a marked improvement (tells you that it is a list, tells you what data is contained in the list). Your successors (or even yourself, 6 months in the future) will thank you for it.

Comment: Would need to be `is[0].ParentId__c` I suspect. And that's if the array length is non-zero.

Comment: @PhilW Good catch, editing my answer.

Comment: @Derek F Thanks for your response. your suggestion resolved my issue. Its my bad. Thanks for your help