# Test Class covering only 75% coverage .How to increase coverage for this test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, rest-api, rest

```java
@RestResource(urlMapping='/convertlead/*')
global with sharing class LeadConvertRestAPI{
    public class ApplicantDetails {
        public String Application_Id;
        public String Applicant_Id;
        public String Record_Id;
        public String Verification_Flag;
        public String Applicant_Flag;
        public ApplicantDetails() {
            Application_Id = '';
            Applicant_Id = '';
            Record_Id = '';
            Verification_Flag = '';
            Applicant_Flag = '';  
        } 
    }

    global class ModelClass {
        public String Status;
        public String Message;
        public String Application_Id;
        public String Applicant_Id;
        //public List<ListApplicantData> List_Applicant_Data;
        public String Lead_Id;
        public String Opportunity_Id;
        public ModelClass() {
            Status = '';
            Message = '';
            //List_Applicant_Data = new List<ListApplicantData>();
            Application_Id = '';
            Applicant_Id = '';
            Lead_Id = '';
            Opportunity_Id = '';
        }
    }

    public static ModelClass checkValidation(String status , String message) {
        ModelClass modCls = new ModelClass();
        modCls.status = status;
        modcls.message = message;
        return modCls;
    }

    global static ModelClass LeadConvert() {
       Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
       try {    
            RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
            RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
           
            ApplicantDetails appDetails = (ApplicantDetails)JSON.deserialize(req.requestBody.toString(),ApplicantDetails.class);
  
            List<Lead> listLead = [SELECT Id,Name,FirstName,LastName,
                                   Lead_Phone_Number_1__c,Residential_Address__c,
                                   Loan_amount_Required_Cust__c,PostalCode,
                                   Purpose_of_Loan_P__c,Status,Branch__c,Branch__r.Name,Comfortable_EMI__c,
                                   Location__Longitude__s,Location__Latitude__s,Convert_Flag__c,LO_Loan_Officer__c
                                   FROM Lead WHERE Id = :appDetails.Record_Id];
            if(listLead.size() == 0) {
                ModelClass modelClassObj = checkValidation('Error','Lead With This Record Id Not Found.');
                return ModelClassObj;    
            }
            else {
                List<Branch__c> listBranch =[SELECT Id,Name
                                             FROM Branch__c WHERE Branch_PinCode__c = :listLead[0].PostalCode Limit 1];
                Customer__c cust = new Customer__c();
                cust.Branch__c = (listLead[0].Branch__c == null) ? 'Jaipur' : listLead[0].Branch__r.Name; 
                cust.Name= listLead[0].Name;
                cust.Customer_Name__c = listLead[0].Name;
                cust.First_name__c = listLead[0].FirstName;
                cust.Last_Name__c= listLead[0].LastName;
                cust.Mobile__c = listLead[0].Lead_Phone_Number_1__c;
                cust.Lead__c = appDetails.Record_Id;
                cust.Loan_Amount_Applied__c = listLead[0].Loan_amount_Required_Cust__c;
                cust.Comfortable_EMI__c=listLead[0].Comfortable_EMI__c;
                cust.LO__c = listLead[0].LO_Loan_Officer__c;                                     
                insert cust;
                
                List<Opportunity> listOpp = [SELECT Id,Purpose_of_loan__c,Loan_Amount_Required__c,Loan_Number__c,Customer_Location_1__Latitude__s,Customer_Location_1__Longitude__s,Household__c,(SELECT ContactId, OpportunityId FROM OpportunityContactRoles) FROM Opportunity WHERE Household__c=:cust.Id];
                System.debug('listOpp--->'+listOpp);
                listOpp[0].Purpose_of_loan__c = listLead[0].Purpose_of_Loan_P__c;
                listOpp[0].Loan_Amount_Required__c = listLead[0].Loan_amount_Required_Cust__c;
                listOpp[0].LM_Loan_Status__c = 'Pending';
                update listOpp;
                List<OpportunityContactRole> listRole = listOpp[0].OpportunityContactRoles;
                ModelClass modelClassObj = checkValidation('Success','Applicant Is Added Successfully');
                modelClassObj.Application_Id = String.valueOf(listOpp[0].Loan_Number__c);

                modelClassObj.Applicant_Id = String.valueOf(listRole[0].ContactId);                                         
                Contact con = new Contact();
                con.id = listRole[0].ContactId;  
                if(appDetails.Verification_Flag != NULL && appDetails.Verification_Flag.length() > 0) {
                    con.Verification_Flag__c = String.valueOf(appDetails.Verification_Flag);
                }
                update con;
                listLead[0].Convert_Flag__c = true;
                listLead[0].Status = 'Converted'; 

                update listLead;
                return ModelClassObj;
            }
        }
        catch(exception e) {
            System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
            Database.rollback(sp);
            ModelClass modelClassObj = checkValidation('Error','Something Went Wrong.');
            return ModelClassObj;
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@istest
public class LeadConvertRestAPITest {
      
    public static testmethod void mytest1(){
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.FirstName='Fanindra';
        acc.LastName = 'Fanindra';
        acc.Employee_Id__c = 'EMP-1004';
        acc.Branch__c='a0D3K000000yAk2UAE';
        acc.Address_Line_1__pc='noida';
        acc.Address_Line_2__pc='addl2';
        acc.Address_Line_3__pc='addl3';
        insert acc;

        Contact con = new Contact();
        con.LastName='choudhary';
        con.FirstName='fanindra';
        con.Aadhar_Card__c='test';
        con.Mobile__c='rest';
        con.Is_Property_Identified__c=false;
        con.is_Property_Owner__c='Yes';
        con.Created_By_Employee__c=acc.id;
        con.Address_Line_1__c='address1';
        con.Address_Line_2__c='address2';
        con.Address_Line_3__c='address4';
        con.Date_Of_Birth__c=system.today();
        con.Personal_email__c='fmc@tmc.com';
        insert con; 


        lead ld = new lead();
        ld.LastName='test';
        ld.Branch__c = 'a0D3K000000yAk2UAE';
        ld.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Lead.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Call Centre').getRecordTypeId();
        ld.Lead_Phone_Number_1__c='test';
        ld.Lead_Current_Status__c='New';
        ld.LeadSource='Door to Door Marketing';
        ld.Applied_Loan_Amount__c=1000000;
        ld.Comfortable_EMI__c=5000.0;
        insert ld;
        Customer__c cust = new Customer__c();
        cust.Branch__c =ld.Branch__r.Name;  
        cust.Name= ld.Name;
        cust.Customer_Name__c = ld.Name;
        cust.First_name__c =ld.FirstName;
        cust.Last_Name__c= ld.LastName;
        cust.Mobile__c = ld.Lead_Phone_Number_1__c;
        cust.Lead__c = ld.Id;
        cust.Loan_Amount_Applied__c =ld.Applied_Loan_Amount__c;
        cust.Comfortable_EMI__c=ld.Comfortable_EMI__c;
        insert cust;
        Config__c cf = new Config__c();
        cf.Name__c = 'Test Config';
        cf.Value__c = '009870';
        insert cf;
        List<Opportunity> opplist = new List<Opportunity>();

        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp.Phone_No__c='9875678910';
        opp.Sanc_EMI__c=2000;
        opp.Date_Cibil_completed__c=system.today();
        opp.Name='test';
        opp.Loan_Number__c='AP-rrrrr';
        opp.AccountId=acc.Id;
        opp.ColPin__c=872344;
        opp.CloseDate=system.today();
        opp.StageName='closed Won';
        opp.LM_Loan_Status__c='Cheque Pending/Not Cleared';
        opp.Loan_Amount_Required__c=50000;
        opplist.add(opp);
        insert opplist;
        opp.Loan_Number__c=opp.id;
        update opp;
        update opplist;
        list<Opportunity> opList = [select Id,Name,Loan_Number__c from  Opportunity where Id =:opplist[0].Id];
        OpportunityContactRole ocr = new OpportunityContactRole();
        ocr.ContactId = con.Id;
        ocr.OpportunityId = opp.Id;
        ocr.IsPrimary = TRUE;
        ocr.Role = 'Main Applicant';
        insert ocr;


        Test.startTest();
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

        req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/ControllerFunction'; 
        req.httpMethod = 'POST';
        string val='{"Record_Id" : "'+ld.id+'"}';
        System.assert(ld.id !=null );
        req.requestBody = Blob.valueOf(val);

        RestContext.request = req;
        RestContext.response= res;
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new WebSermockTest());
        LeadConvertRestAPI.LeadConvert(); 
        req.requestBody = Blob.valueOf('{"Record_Id" : "'+ld.id+'"}');
        LeadConvertRestAPI.LeadConvert();
        req.requestBody = Blob.valueOf('{"Applicant_Id" : " "}');
        LeadConvertRestAPI.LeadConvert();
        req.requestBody = Blob.valueOf('{"Applicant_Id" : "'+con.id+'"}');
        LeadConvertRestAPI.LeadConvert();
        req.requestBody = Blob.valueOf('{"Application_Id" : "'+opplist[0].id+'","Record_Id" : "'+opplist[0].Loan_Number__c+'"}');
        LeadConvertRestAPI.LeadConvert();
        LeadConvertRestAPI.ApplicantDetails objCd1 = new LeadConvertRestAPI.ApplicantDetails();
        test.stopTest();
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I increase my code coverage, or why can't I cover these lines?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines)

Comment: You need to stop hard-coding ids in your test class, as well. Your test code cannot see those records. Tests must generate all of the required data.