# Hi, I am stuck there when writing a test class. Please help me rectifying it

Tags: unit-test, failing-tests

The class:
[image]

And The test Class I have written:

```
@isTest
public class AccountAffiliationServiceTest {
    public static void DataSetup(){
        Test.startTest();   
        
        Account acc = new account();
        acc.name='testAccount';
        acc.IsPremierCurrent__c = true;
        acc.IsPumpedItUpCurrent__c = true;
        insert acc; 
        
        Id RccognitionId = Schema.SObjectType.Marketing_Program__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Sponsor Recognition').getRecordTypeId();
        list<Marketing_Program__c> mpclist = new list<Marketing_Program__c>();
        Marketing_Program__c mp = new Marketing_Program__c(Name = 'Pump it up Current', Scope__c = 'account' ,Nationwide_Marketing_Program__c='yes',RecordTypeId=RccognitionId);
        mpclist.add(mp);
        Marketing_Program__c mp1 = new Marketing_Program__c(Name = 'Premier Current', Scope__c = 'account' ,Nationwide_Marketing_Program__c='yes',RecordTypeId=RccognitionId);
        mpclist.add(mp1);
        insert mpclist;
        
        Account_Marketing_Program__c amp = new Account_Marketing_Program__c();
        amp.Account__c = acc.Id;
        amp.Marketing_Program__c = mp.Id;
        insert amp;
    } 
   @isTest
    public static void AccountFlagForPumpItUpCurrent(){
        list<Account_Marketing_Program__c> NewList = [SELECT Id, Name,Marketing_Program__c,Account__c,
                                                      Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, Date_Assigned__c,Marketing_Program__r.RecordType.Name,Marketing_Program__r.Name,
                                                      Date_Removed__c from Account_Marketing_Program__c where Marketing_Program__r.RecordType.Name='Sponsor Recognition'
                                                      AND Marketing_Program__r.Name in ('Pump It Up Current','Premier Current')];
      AccountAffiliationService.AccountFlagForPumpItUpCurrent(NewList, 'Insert');  
    }  
}
```

Comment: You should not update a question such that it invalidates the given answer. Please post a new question.

Comment: Ok, Sorry i did not knew that.

Comment: Before posting a question about coverage, please do read our standard [resources](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines) on that topic. Generic "how do I increase to X%" questions are likely to be closed as duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are missing the [annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_testsetup.htm) `@TestSetup`  on method `DataSetup`

> If a test class contains a test setup method, the testing framework
> executes the test setup method first, before any test method in the
> class. Records that are created in a test setup method are available
> to all test methods in the test class and are rolled back at the end
> of test class execution. If a test method changes those records, such
> as record field updates or record deletions, those changes are rolled
> back after each test method finishes execution. The next executing
> test method gets access to the original unmodified state of those
> records.