# How to write a test class for this Batch covering all scenarios

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, code-coverage, schedulebatch

I am writing a test class for following batch, but code coverage is not increasing more than 28%. Can anyone please help with the test class for this batch.

```
global class CaseOwnerManagerUpdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.Stateful,Schedulable {
    global CaseOwnerManagerUpdate() {
    }

    global Database.Querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        //Return all open cases owned by a user
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Case_Owner_Manager__c, OwnerId FROM Case WHERE Status != 'Closed' AND Owner.Type = 'User'  AND RecordType.DeveloperName IN ('Suppport','Support_New')]);
    }
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Case> scope) {
        //Iterate through the cases and build a set of owner ids that we can use to query the user object
        Set<Id> userIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Case c : scope) {
            userIds.add(c.OwnerId);
        }
        
        //Query the user records for each of these case owners
        Map<Id, User> caseowners = new Map<Id, User>([SELECT Id, ManagerId FROM User WHERE Id IN :userIds]);
        
        //Create a list that will hold cases that need to be updated
        List<Case> casesforupdate = new List<Case>();
        
        //Iterate through the cases and check to see if a manager update is needed
        for (Case c : scope) {
            if (c.Case_Owner_Manager__c != caseowners.get(c.OwnerId).ManagerId) {
                c.Case_Owner_Manager__c = caseowners.get(c.OwnerId).ManagerId;
                casesforupdate.add(c);
            }
        }
        
        //If we have any cases that need to be updated, update them
        if (casesforupdate.size() > 0) {
            update casesforupdate;
        }
        
    }
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        //send confirmation email notifications
         AsyncApexJob a = [Select Id, Status,ExtendedStatus,NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed,TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email    from AsyncApexJob where Id =:BC.getJobId()];
      
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {a.CreatedBy.Email};
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setSubject('Match Merge Batch ' + a.Status);
        mail.setPlainTextBody('records processed ' + a.TotalJobItems +   'with '+ a.NumberOfErrors + ' failures.');
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }

    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        database.executebatch(new CaseOwnerManagerUpdate());
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to include a copy of your test class as well.

Comment: You should look through [How do I increase my code coverage, or why can't I cover these lines?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines). The short version is that you should have multiple test methods, and you need to create the test data to guarantee that your queries return results and execute certain code paths.