# Test Class Coverage TriggerDispatcher

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Unable to cover this class , this is a common class for all triggers. Please help.

```
public virtual class TriggerDispatcherBase implements ITriggerDispatcher { 
        
        private static ITriggerHandler beforeInserthandler;
        private static ITriggerHandler beforeUpdatehandler;
        private static ITriggerHandler beforeDeleteHandler;
        private static ITriggerHandler afterInserthandler;
        private static ITriggerHandler afterUpdatehandler;
        private static ITriggerHandler afterDeleteHandler;
        private static ITriggerHandler afterUndeleteHandler;
    
        
        public virtual void bulkBefore( TriggerParameters tp ) {}
    
        public virtual void bulkAfter( TriggerParameters tp ) {}
    
        public virtual void beforeInsert( TriggerParameters tp ) {}
    
    
        public virtual void beforeUpdate( TriggerParameters tp ) {}
    
        public virtual void beforeDelete( TriggerParameters tp ) {}
    
    
        public virtual void afterInsert( TriggerParameters tp ) {} 
    
        public virtual void afterUpdate( TriggerParameters tp ) {}
    
        public virtual void afterDelete( TriggerParameters tp ) {}
    
        public virtual void afterUnDelete( TriggerParameters tp ) {}
        
        public virtual void andFinally() {}
        
        protected void execute( ITriggerHandler handlerInstance, TriggerParameters tp, TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent tEvent ) {
            if ( handlerInstance != null ) {
                if ( tEvent == TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent.beforeInsert )
                    beforeInsertHandler = handlerInstance;
                if ( tEvent == TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent.beforeUpdate )
                    beforeUpdateHandler = handlerInstance;
                if ( tEvent == TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent.beforeDelete )
                    beforeDeleteHandler = handlerInstance;
                if ( tEvent == TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent.afterInsert )
                    afterInsertHandler = handlerInstance;
                if ( tEvent == TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent.afterUpdate )
                    afterUpdateHandler = handlerInstance;
                if ( tEvent == TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent.afterDelete )
                    afterDeleteHandler = handlerInstance;
                if ( tEvent == TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent.afterUnDelete )
                    afterUndeleteHandler = handlerInstance;
                handlerInstance.mainEntry( tp );
                handlerInstance.updateObjects();
            } else {
                if ( tEvent == TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent.beforeInsert )
                    beforeInsertHandler.inProgressEntry( tp );
                if ( tEvent == TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent.beforeUpdate )
                    beforeUpdateHandler.inProgressEntry( tp );
                if ( tEvent == TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent.beforeDelete )
                    beforeDeleteHandler.inProgressEntry( tp );
                if ( tEvent == TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent.afterInsert )
                    afterInsertHandler.inProgressEntry( tp );
                if ( tEvent == TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent.afterUpdate )
                    afterUpdateHandler.inProgressEntry( tp );
                if ( tEvent == TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent.afterDelete )
                    afterDeleteHandler.inProgressEntry( tp );
                if ( tEvent == TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent.afterUnDelete )
                    afterUndeleteHandler.inProgressEntry( tp );
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried :

```
@isTest
public class TriggerDispatcherBase_Test {

    @isTest
    public static void testmethod1()
    {
        Test.startTest();
        Account testAccount = TestDataFactory.createAccount( true );
        update testAccount;
        List<Account> acclist=new List<Account>();
acclist.add(testAccount);
       TriggerParameters tp = new TriggerParameters( acclist, acclist, Trigger.newMap, Trigger.oldmap,
       Trigger.isBefore, Trigger.isAfter, Trigger.isDelete, 
       Trigger.isInsert, Trigger.isUpdate, Trigger.isUnDelete, Trigger.isExecuting );
        TriggerDispatcherBase obj=new TriggerDispatcherBase();
       obj.bulkBefore(tp);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Thank you for including code - both test code and code you are trying to test. Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/356926/edit) your question to add the exact error(s) you are getting when running your test, or details of the unexpected results/issues you are seeing when running your test. And see if the information in this canonical question and answer, or in anything it links to, help:: [How do I write an Apex unit test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/244788/81648)

Comment: You should take a look at [How do I increase my code coverage, or why can't I cover these lines](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines). Generally, every time you have an `if` statement, you'll want two test methods (one where you enter the `if` block, and one where you don't). Your test class here should have around 14 test methods in it.

Comment: Also, you should be aware that trigger context values are generally null (I think `trigger.isExecuting` may be the exception) unless you're inside of a trigger (or a class called from a trigger, when the trigger is executed). At the very least, you'll want to replace the instances of `Trigger.isInsert`, `Trigger.isAfter`, etc... with boolean literals (true/false).

Answer (score 0):

You need two parts. Part 1 covers all of the virtual methods. Part 2 will cover the protected method.

## Part 1: Virtual Coverage

Simply create a new TriggerDispatcherBase and call all the methods:

```
@isTest static void testVirtualMethods() {
  TriggerDispatcherBase base = new TriggerDispatcherBase();
  base.bulkBefore(null);
  base.bulkAfter(null);
  base.bulkInsert(null);
  base.afterInsert(null);
  base.beforeUpdate(null);
  base.afterUpdate(null);
  base.beforeDelete(null);
  base.afterDelete(null);
  base.afterUndelete(null);
  base.andFinally();
}
```

Since these methods do nothing, this provides do-nothing coverage in an efficient manner.

## Part 2: Protected Coverage

To cover this, we need to make mock classes, then use those to inject data.

```
@isTest class TriggerDispatcherBaseTest {
    public class MockHandlerInstance implements TriggerDispatcherBase.ITriggerHandler {
        public void inProgressEntry(TriggerParameters tp) {

        }
        public void mainEntry(TriggerDispatcherBase.TriggerParameters tp) {
        }
        public void updateObjects() {
        }
    }
    public class TriggerDispatcherBaseMock extends TriggerDispatcherBase {
        public void executeAllDispatchers() {
            MockHandlerInstance mock = new MockHandlerInstance();
            for(TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent triggerEvent: TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent.values()) {
                execute(mock, null, triggerEvent);
                execute(null, null, triggerEvent);
            }
        }
    }
    @isTest static void testExecuteMethod() {
        new TriggerDispatcherBaseMock().executeAllDispatchers();
    }
}
```

Note that I don't have all of the information from your related classes, so there's some parts you have to fill out, but this should get you most of the way there. You may need to add `override`, change return types, etc.