# How do I write a test for my Trigger?

Tags: trigger, unit-test

I'm currently in the test phase of my project. I suppose to write a test on my triggers if someone has the good syntax for that (I've tried but it didn't work): here my triggers

1/

```
trigger FA_TRH_CalculeAmount on Order (before update) {
    for(integer i=0; i< trigger.new.size(); i++){
        Order newOrder= trigger.new[i];
        newOrder.NetAmount__c = newOrder.TotalAmount - newOrder.ShipmentCost__c;
    }
}
```

2/

```
trigger FA_TRH_UpdateAccountCA on Order (before insert) {
    set<Id> setAccountIds = new set<Id>();
    List<Order> ordersList = trigger.new;
    FA_QR_Account accountQuery = new FA_QR_Account();
    FA_SRV_Account accountService = new FA_SRV_Account();
    for(integer i=0; i< trigger.new.size(); i++){
        Order newOrder= trigger.new[i];
        setAccountIds.add(newOrder.AccountId);
    }
    Map<Id,Account> mapAccountId = accountQuery.getAccountsByIds(setAccountIds);
    List<Account> accToUpdate = new List<Account>();
    for (Order order : ordersList){
        if(order.Status == 'Ordered' ||order.Status == 'Activated'){
            Account acc = mapAccountId.get(order.AccountId);
            if(acc != null){
                acc.Chiffre_d_affaire__c = acc.Chiffre_d_affaire__c + order.TotalAmount;
            }
        accToUpdate.add(acc);
        }
    }
    accountService.updateAccount(accToUpdate);
}
```

Comment: Please find the below articles which shows how to write the test classes. [How to write test classes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test) [Test classes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines)

Comment: Any reason why 1 isn't a formula field, workflow rule, process builder or flow? Similarly 2 *looks* like it could be a roll ups summary field (appreciate it might not be a master detail etc).

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Please take the SFSE [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) & look in the Help Center - especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) where it states, _"Questions that ask for the community to write code or provide step-by-step instructions for implementation are often not received well and are likely to be closed."_ Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/357239/edit) your question to include how it is not working (e.g., exact errors, issues).