# How can i test my Apex method

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, unit-test, code-coverage, test-setup

I am not sure how to write test class for this method. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Map<String, String>> getPickListValues() {
        List<Map<String, String>> options = new List<Map<String, String>>();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ratingPickList = Account.Rating.getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
        for (Schema.PicklistEntry entry :ratingPickList) {
            if (entry.isActive() == true) {
                options.add(new Map<String, String>{'label' => entry.getLabel(), 'value' => entry.getValue()});
            }
        }
        return options;
    }
```

Comment: can you please edit this question and ask a concrete question, like "I am already doing **this**, but **this** result is not expected, I am expecting to have **the following** result"?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test || https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to dynamically edit picklist field values in Apex (you can use  Metadata API but that is not worth it in your case).

So, for your case, just to cover this method I would do something like:

```
@IsTest
private static void getPickListValuesTest() {
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> activeValues = Account.Rating.getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
    List<Map<String, String>> actualActiveValues = getPickListValues();
    
    System.assertEquals(activeValues.size(), actualActiveValues.size());
    // TODO: some other assertions for exact picklist values
}
```