# How to write test class for return type methods?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am really new to Apex and test classes. I am having issues while writing the test for the below class. Can someone please help me?

At least guide me what data should I insert first and mainly how to cover the `public List‹Insuredl_C> getInsured1Records () {` method.

```java
public class convertPDFController {

    public String selecteduserId {set;get;}
    public String documentType{set;get;}
    public User brokerDetails{set;get;]
    public String brokerCode{set;get;}
    public String brokerName{set;get;}

    private static String DOCUMENT PATH  = '/sfc/serlet./download/';
     
    public convertPDFController(ApexPages.StandardControllerController){
        User brokerDetails = [select Account.Id, Account.Name, Account.BM_Email__c, Account.Ph

        brokerCode = brokerDetails.Account.Broker_Code_c;
        brokerName = brokerDetails.Account.Name;
     }

    public static String getLogo(){
        User user = [select ContactId from User where Id =: UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];
            
        Contact contact = [Select AccountId from Contact where Id =: user. ContactId];
        Account account = [Select profileLogoId_c from Account where Id =: contact.Accounid];
        string src = DOCUMENT_PATH + Account.profileLogoId_c
        retrun src;     
    }

    public List<User› getbrokerAccDetails(){
        List<User> brokerDetails = [select Account.Id, Account.Name, Account.BM_Email__c from user where id: userinfo.getuserId()]; 
            
        return brokerDetails;
    }

    public List‹User› getbrokerInfo(){
        List<User› brokerDetails = [select Account.Id, Account. Name, Account.BM_Email from user where id: userinfo.getuserId()
        return brokerDetails;
    }

    public List‹Insuredl_c> getInsured1Records () {
        List<GroupMember> groupList = [select GroupId, Group.Name from GroupMember where UserorGroupid =: userinfo.getuserId()];
        set‹id› groupIds = new set‹id›() ;
        for (GroupMember g: groupList){
            groupIds.add(g.GroupId);
        }

        List‹Group› queueList = [select id from Group where Type='Queue' AND id IN 
          :groupIc];
        return [SELECT Id, Name, CreatedById, CreatedDate, OwnerName from Insuredl_c where 
        ownerId = :Userinfo.getUserId()];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Does this answer your question? [How do I write an Apex unit test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test)

Comment: Also see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines