# Help me build a test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

Hi I am new in Apex Programming, can you help me build a test class for the following code. Thanks.

```
public static void caseClose(Map<Id, SObject> newMap, Map<Id, SObject> oldMap){
    
    Map<Id, Case> newMapCase = (Map<Id, Case>) newMap;
    Set<Id> csids = new Set<Id>(); 
    
    for(Case cs : newMapCase.values()){
       // if(cs.Id !=null){
         //   csids.add(cs.Id);
        //}
        if(cs.status=='Closed' || cs.status=='Closed - NS' || cs.status=='Closed - Spam'){
            csids.add(cs.Id);
        }
    }   
    
    for(AggregateResult agg : [select count(Id), WhatId from Task where whatId in :csids and Status != 'Completed' group by WhatId]){
        if( Integer.valueof(agg.get('expr0')) > 0){
            Case taskRecord = (Case)newMAp.get((Id)agg.get('whatId'));
            taskRecord.addError('All associated task should be completed before closing a case!');
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Test Class. I only got 88%. Help me make it 100%. Thanks.

```
@isTest
public class caseHandler {
    
   static testMethod void caseClose() {
       
        Case c = new Case();   
          c.Subject='Sample Test 1';
          c.Description='Sample Test 1 - Description' ;         
          c.Status='New'; 
          insert c;
       
        Task t1 = new Task();
          t1.WhatID = c.ID;
          t1.Subject='Sample Test 1 from Case';  
          t1.Status='Open';
          insert t1;

      
         Test.startTest();  
         boolean updateFailed = False;       
          try{
             c.Status='Closed';   
             update c;              
              System.assertEquals( true, False );
                Case c2 = [SELECT Status, isClosed FROM Case WHERE Id = :c.Id];
                System.assertEquals( 'New', c2.Status );
                System.assertEquals( false, c2.isClosed );
             }
          catch(Exception e){ 
               System.assertEquals( true, true );              
         }


         Test.stopTest();
   }
    
}
```

Comment: Tell us what you have tried as of now.  If you have not already done then please refer [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro#:~:text=A%20test%20suite%20is%20a,that%20you%20execute%20together%20regularly).

Comment: @user43598 thanks

Comment: @identigral already edit the question part. I have an existing test class already. But it is only 88%. Can you help me?

Comment: You'll find help via the canonical Q&A identigral referenced about how to identify strategies for testing certain programming language constructs (if, for etc.). It should also be noted that, while the goal is 100% in general terms, it isn't always practical or even sensible to test every possible scenario. E.g. consider exception handling where it isn't always easy to add throwing an exception from within the unit test's target production code. If you would have to add test-specific code in excess of TestVisible annotation, think hard before you do it - it's probably not gonna help long term.

Comment: It's not clear from your edit what lines aren't covered by your test class. See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines for more info.