# COVER IF CONDITIONS

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I have an apex class and a Test class already created.
Now  have added few IF CONDITIONS in my apex class, but I am unable to cover those in my TEST CLASS.

APEX CLASS:

```
global with sharing class PriceLevelAdjustment implements  Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {


  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Object>  getSurfaceGradeComponent(String searchTerm, string myObject, String filter){
        return [select Surface_Component_Grade__c from product2 where Surface_Component_Grade__c !='' and isActive=true group by Surface_Component_Grade__c order by Surface_Component_Grade__c  asc];
        
    }    
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<map<String,String>>  getMainProducts(){
        
        
        List<map<String,String>> returnMainProd=new List<map<String,String>>(); 
        integer i=0;
        for( AggregateResult  pickListVal : [Select Main_Product__c from product2 where Main_Product__c!='' and isActive=true group by Main_Product__c order by Main_Product__c asc]){
            
            if(i==0){
                map<String,String> mapOption1=new map<String,String>();
                mapOption1.put('label','All');
                mapOption1.put('value','');
                returnMainProd.add(mapOption1);
            }           
            i++;
            map<String,String> mapOption=new map<String,String>();
            mapOption.put('label',String.valueOf(pickListVal.get('Main_Product__c')));
            mapOption.put('value',String.valueOf(pickListVal.get('Main_Product__c')));
            returnMainProd.add(mapOption);
            
        }   
        return returnMainProd;
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<ALTF__Solution__c>  getAltifySolutions(String searchTerm, string myObject, String filter){
        String myQuery = null;
        if(filter != null && filter != ''){
            myQuery = 'Select Id, Name from '+myObject+' Where Name Like  \'%' + searchTerm + '%\' AND '+filter+' LIMIT  5';
        }
        else {
            if(searchTerm == null || searchTerm == ''){
                myQuery = 'Select Id, Name from '+myObject+' Where LastViewedDate != NULL ORDER BY LastViewedDate DESC LIMIT  5';
            }
            else {
                myQuery = 'Select Id, Name from '+myObject+' Where Name Like  \'%' + searchTerm + '%\' LIMIT  5';
            }
        }
        List<sObject> lookUpList = database.query(myQuery);
        return lookUpList;
        
    }
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<map<String,String>>  getTheCurrency(){
        String objectName = 'PriceBookEntry';
        String fieldName ='CurrencyIsoCode';
        
        Schema.SObjectType s = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName) ;
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = s.getDescribe() ;
        Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fields = r.fields.getMap() ;
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = fields.get(fieldName).getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
        List<map<String,String>> returnCurrency=new List<map<String,String>>(); 
        Integer i=0;
        for( Schema.PicklistEntry pickListVal : ple){
            
            map<String,String> mapOption=new map<String,String>();
            
            if(i==0){
                map<String,String> mapOption1=new map<String,String>();
                mapOption1.put('label','All');
                mapOption1.put('value','');
                returnCurrency.add(mapOption1);
            }
            System.debug(pickListVal.getLabel() +' '+pickListVal.getValue());
            mapOption.put('label',pickListVal.getLabel());
            mapOption.put('value',pickListVal.getValue());
            returnCurrency.add(mapOption);
            i++;
        }   
        return returnCurrency;
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static  Map<String,String> getTheBatchStatus(id batchInst){
        
        AsyncApexJob a = [Select Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed,
                          TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email, ExtendedStatus
                          from AsyncApexJob where Id = :batchInst];        
        System.debug('-------- '+a.Status);
        
        Integer percent;
        if(a.jobItemsProcessed == 0) {
            percent= 0;    
        }else{
            Decimal d = a.jobItemsProcessed;
            d = d.divide(a.TotalJobItems, 2)*100;
            percent= d.intValue();
        }
        
        
        
        String status='';
        if(a.Status == 'Completed') {
            status= 'completed';
        }else{
            status= 'not_completed';
        }
        
        Map<String,String> batchJobStat=new  Map<String,String>();
        batchJobStat.put('status',status);
        batchJobStat.put('percentage',String.valueOf(percent));
        batchJobStat.put('barWidth','width:'+String.valueOf(percent)+'%');
        
        return batchJobStat;
    }
    
    
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<pricebook2> getPriceBook(){
        List<pricebook2> returnPB=new List<pricebook2>();
        String userProfileName = [select Name from profile where id =: userinfo.getProfileId()].Name;
        if(userProfileName == 'System Administrator'){
            return  [select id,name,createdby.name from pricebook2 order by name asc];
        }else{
            
            
            List<PermissionSetAssignment> areaPriceBookAccess=[SELECT id  FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE (PermissionSet.Name = 'plyCRM_Manage_Area_Pricebooks' or PermissionSet.Name =  'Manage_Standard_Area_and_Account_Price_books' OR PermissionSet.Name =  'Manage_Area_and_Account_Price_books') and AssigneeId =:UserInfo.getUserId() ];
            if(areaPriceBookAccess.size() > 0){
                List<pricebook2> areaPB = [select id,name,createdby.name from pricebook2 where Pricebook_Type__c='Area pricebook' order by name asc];
                returnPB.addAll(areaPB);
            }
            
            List<PermissionSetAssignment> standardPriceBookAccess=[SELECT id  FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE (PermissionSet.Name =  'Manage_Standard_Area_and_Account_Price_books') and AssigneeId =:UserInfo.getUserId() ];
            if(standardPriceBookAccess.size() > 0){
                List<pricebook2> standardPB = [select id,name,createdby.name from pricebook2 where Pricebook_Type__c='Standard' order by name asc];
                returnPB.addAll(standardPB);
            }
            
            List<PermissionSetAssignment> accountPriceBookAccess=[SELECT id  FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE (PermissionSet.Name = 'plyCRM_Manage_Account_Pricebooks' or PermissionSet.Name =  'Manage_Standard_Area_and_Account_Price_books' OR PermissionSet.Name =  'Manage_Area_and_Account_Price_books') and AssigneeId =:UserInfo.getUserId() ];
            if(accountPriceBookAccess.size() > 0){
                List<pricebook2> accountPB= [select id,name,createdby.name from pricebook2 where Pricebook_Type__c='Account pricebook' order by name asc];
                returnPB.addAll(accountPB);
            }
            
            
        }
       returnPB.sort();
        return returnPB;
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Map<String,String>> getProductList(Map<String,String> customFields) {
        String query='SELECT Id,Product2.Id, Product2.Name,Product2.ProductCode,CurrencyIsoCode,Product2.RecordType.Name,UnitPrice,UseStandardPrice,Standard_Price_PGL__c,Product2.Main_Product__c, List_Price_m2__c, List_Price_pc__c FROM PricebookEntry where  Pricebook2Id=\''+customFields.get('pricebook')+'\'' ;
        
        if(customFields.get('ALTF__Solution__c')!=null && customFields.get('ALTF__Solution__c')!='')
            query +=  ' AND Product2.ALTF__Solution__c=\''+customFields.get('ALTF__Solution__c')+ '\''; 
        if(customFields.get('Surface_Component_Grade__c')!=null && customFields.get('Surface_Component_Grade__c')!='')
            query +=  ' AND Product2.Surface_Component_Grade__c=\''+customFields.get('Surface_Component_Grade__c')+'\''; 
         if(customFields.get('mainproduct')!=null && customFields.get('mainproduct')!='')
            query +=  ' AND Product2.Main_Product__c=\''+customFields.get('mainproduct')+'\'';
        if(customFields.get('CurrencyIsoCode')!=null)
            query +=  ' AND CurrencyIsoCode=\''+customFields.get('CurrencyIsoCode')+'\'';
        if(customFields.get('length_min')!=null && customFields.get('length_min')!='')    
            query +=  ' AND Product2.Length__c >= '+Decimal.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(customFields.get('length_min')));
        if(customFields.get('length_max')!=null && customFields.get('length_max')!='')    
            query +=  ' AND Product2.Length__c <= '+Decimal.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(customFields.get('length_max')));
        
        //query += ' limit 80';
        //System.debug(standardFields.get('Length__c'));
        system.debug(query);
        
        List<Map<String,String>> returnLst=new List<Map<String,String>>();
    
        for(PricebookEntry pEntry:Database.query(query)){
            Map<String,String> pbEntryMap=new Map<String,String>();
            pbEntryMap.put('productName',pEntry.Product2.Name);
            pbEntryMap.put('ProductCode',pEntry.Product2.ProductCode);
            pbEntryMap.put('CurrencyIsoCode',pEntry.CurrencyIsoCode);
            pbEntryMap.put('RecordType',pEntry.Product2.RecordType.Name);
            pbEntryMap.put('UnitPrice',String.valueof(pEntry.UnitPrice.setScale(2)));
            if (!(pEntry.List_Price_m2__c == NULL)) {
            pbEntryMap.put('List_Price_m2__c',String.valueof(pEntry.List_Price_m2__c.setScale(3)));
            }
        
            if (!(pEntry.List_price_pc__c == NULL)) {
                pbEntryMap.put('List_Price_pc__c',String.valueof(pEntry.List_Price_pc__c.setScale(3)));
                }
            pbEntryMap.put('UseStandardPrice',String.valueof(pEntry.UseStandardPrice));
            pbEntryMap.put('Standard_Price_PGL__c',String.valueof(pEntry.Standard_Price_PGL__c));
            pbEntryMap.put('Id',pEntry.Id);
            pbEntryMap.put('nameUrl','/'+pEntry.Product2.Id);
            system.debug (String.valueof(pEntry.List_Price_m2__c) + 'and this is '+String.valueof(pEntry.List_Price_pc__c) );
            
            returnLst.add(pbEntryMap);
        } 
    
        
        system.debug('Here are the records' + returnLst);
        return  returnLst;
        
        
        /*   return  [SELECT Id, Product2.Name,Product2.ProductCode,Product2.CurrencyIsoCode,Product2.RecordType.Name FROM PricebookEntry 
where Pricebook2Id =:customFields.get('pricebook') and (Product2.ALTF__Solution__c=:standardFields.get('ALTF__Solution__c') OR 
Product2.Surface_Component_Grade__c=:standardFields.get('Surface_Component_Grade__c') OR 
Product2.Length__c=:Decimal.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(standardFields.get('Length__c'))))
]; */
        
        
        //return [SELECT Id, Name,ProductCode,CurrencyIsoCode,RecordType.Name FROM Product2 where ALTF__Solution__c=:standardFields.get('ALTF__Solution__c') and Surface_Component_Grade__c=:standardFields.get('Surface_Component_Grade__c') and Length__c=:Decimal.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(standardFields.get('Length__c')))];
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Id updatePrice(List<String> updateRecIds,
    //String pricePercentage, 
    String price, String priceUnits,
    String unitValue) {
        
        
        Id bachInst= Database.executeBatch(new PriceLevelAdjustment(price,priceUnits,updateRecIds,unitValue), 200);
        return bachInst;
    }
    
    
    Decimal price;
    String unitValue; // Created new variable
    public String priceUnits;
    public List<String> updateRecIds;
    global set<Id> successIdsLst;
    global PriceLevelAdjustment(String price,String priceUnits, List<String> updateRecIds, String unitValue){
        
        this.price=Decimal.valueOf(price);
        this.priceUnits = priceUnits;
        this.updateRecIds=updateRecIds;
        this.unitValue=unitValue; // assigned value to a variable
    } 
    
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([select Id, UnitPrice,UseStandardPrice,List_Price_m2__c, List_price_pc__c,
        Use_List_Price_m2__c,Use_List_Price_m3__c,Use_List_Price_pc__c,Product2.Batch_Conversion_PC_per_M2__c,
         Product2.Batch_Conversion_PC_per_M3__c,
         Product2.Batch_Conversion_M2_per_M3__c
         FROM PricebookEntry where id IN: this.updateRecIds]);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<PricebookEntry> records){ 
        
        List<PricebookEntry> updatePBEntry=new List<PricebookEntry>();
        System.debug(this.price);
        System.debug('unit selected is ' + this.unitValue);
        System.debug('PriceUnit selected is ' + this.priceUnits);
        for(PricebookEntry entry:records){
            if(entry.UseStandardPrice==true){
                entry.UseStandardPrice=false;   
            }


         **// Adding new logic to update the unit price
            if (this.unitValue == 'M3'&& !(entry.Product2.Batch_Conversion_PC_per_M3__c== NULL) && !(entry.Product2.Batch_Conversion_M2_per_M3__c==NULL)) {
             if (this.priceUnits == 'percent') {
                entry.UnitPrice= entry.UnitPrice + (entry.UnitPrice * this.price/100);
             }
             else if (this.priceUnits == 'currency') {
                entry.UnitPrice= entry.UnitPrice + this.price;
             }
            entry.List_price_pc__c  = entry.UnitPrice/entry.Product2.Batch_Conversion_PC_per_M3__c;
            entry.List_Price_m2__c  = entry.UnitPrice/entry.Product2.Batch_Conversion_M2_per_M3__c;
            entry.Use_List_Price_m3__c = True;
            entry.Use_List_Price_m2__c = False;
            entry.Use_List_Price_pc__c = False;
          }
        
          else if (this.unitValue == 'M2') {
            if (this.priceUnits == 'percent'){
            entry.List_Price_m2__c= entry.List_Price_m2__c + (entry.List_Price_m2__c * this.price/100);
            }
            else if (this.priceUnits == 'currency') {
                entry.List_Price_m2__c= entry.List_Price_m2__c + this.price;
             }
            entry.UnitPrice = entry.List_Price_m2__c * entry.Product2.Batch_Conversion_M2_per_M3__c;
            entry.List_price_pc__c = entry.List_Price_m2__c/entry.Product2.Batch_Conversion_PC_per_M2__c;
            entry.Use_List_Price_m3__c = False;
            entry.Use_List_Price_m2__c = True;
            entry.Use_List_Price_pc__c = False;
          }
          else if (this.unitValue == 'PC') {
            if (this.priceUnits == 'percent'){ 
            entry.List_price_pc__c= entry.List_price_pc__c + (entry.List_price_pc__c * this.price/100);
            }
            else if (this.priceUnits == 'currency') {
                entry.List_price_pc__c= entry.List_price_pc__c + this.price;
             }
            entry.UnitPrice= entry.List_price_pc__c * entry.Product2.Batch_Conversion_PC_per_M3__c;
            entry.List_Price_m2__c= entry.List_price_pc__c * entry.Product2.Batch_Conversion_PC_per_M2__c;
            entry.Use_List_Price_m3__c = False;
            entry.Use_List_Price_m2__c = False;
            entry.Use_List_Price_pc__c = True;
          }
          //entry.UnitPrice= entry.UnitPrice + (entry.UnitPrice * this.price/100); existing logic commected
         
            updatePBEntry.add(entry);
            
        }
        
        System.debug(updatePBEntry);**
        
        
         successIdsLst = new set<Id>();
         Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.update(updatePBEntry, false);
         for(database.SaveResult s:srList){
            if(s.isSuccess()){
                successIdsLst.add(s.getId());
            }
         }
        
        
       
        
        
    }    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        
         
        Database.executeBatch(new PriceHistoryLogging(this.successIdsLst,true,'Price Change'));
        
    } 
}
```

**IF CONDITIONS I HAVE ADDED ARE HIGHLIGHTED ABOVE.**

=================================================================================

**TEST CLASS:**

```
@isTest
public class PriceLevelAdjustmentTest {
    static testMethod void PriceLevelAdjustmentCoverTest() {
        Test.StartTest();
        
        Pricebook2 standardPricebook = new Pricebook2(Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(),IsActive = true);
        Pricebook2 pb = new pricebook2(name='test');
        insert pb;
        Update standardPricebook;
        
        Product2 p1 = new Product2(Name='Product Monthly 1111', Family='Monthly', isActive=true,Main_Product__c='test', CurrencyIsoCode='USD');
        Product2 p2 = new Product2(Name='Product Yearly 2222', Family='Yearly', isActive=true, CurrencyIsoCode='USD'); 
        Product2 p3 = new Product2(Name='Product Yearly 2223', Family='Yearly', isActive=true, CurrencyIsoCode='USD'); 
        insert new List<Product2>{p1, p2,p3};
            
             
            Id pricebookId = standardPricebook.Id;
        PricebookEntry pbe1 = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2id=pricebookId, Product2id=p1.ID, isActive=true, CurrencyIsoCode='EUR',unitPrice=50);
        PricebookEntry pbe2 = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2id=pricebookId, Product2id=p2.ID, isActive=true, CurrencyIsoCode='USD', unitPrice=50);
        PricebookEntry pbe3 = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2id=pb.Id, Product2id=p2.ID, isActive=true, CurrencyIsoCode='USD', unitPrice=50, Usestandardprice=true, Use_List_Price_m3__c=True); 
        
        insert pbe1;
        insert pbe2;
        insert pbe3;
        
         Map<Id,PricebookEntry> pbeLstMap=new Map<Id,PricebookEntry>([select id,name from PricebookEntry]);
        List<Id> pbeLst=new List<Id>(pbeLstMap.keySet());
        
        PriceLevelAdjustment pla=new PriceLevelAdjustment('2','Percent',pbeLst,'M3');
        PriceLevelAdjustment.getSurfaceGradeComponent('','',''); 
        PriceLevelAdjustment.getMainProducts(); 
        PriceLevelAdjustment.getAltifySolutions('birch','ALTF__Solution__c','');
        PriceLevelAdjustment.getAltifySolutions('','ALTF__Solution__c',''); 
        PriceLevelAdjustment.getTheCurrency();
        PriceLevelAdjustment.getPriceBook();
        
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Plywood End Use Manager'];
        User u2=createTestUser(p.id,'test','test');
        
        System.runAs(u2) {
           PriceLevelAdjustment.getPriceBook();
        }
        ALTF__Solution__c als=new ALTF__Solution__c(Name='test',ALTF__Solution_Family__c='Birch plywood');   
        insert als;
        Product2 p4 = new Product2(Name='Product Monthly 1111', Family='Monthly', 
                                   isActive=true,Main_Product__c='test', CurrencyIsoCode='EUR',
                                   ALTF__Solution__c=als.id,Surface_Component_Grade__c='test',
                                   Length__c=20
                                    
                                  );    
        
        insert p4;
        PricebookEntry pbe4 = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2id=pricebookId, Product2id=p4.ID, isActive=true, CurrencyIsoCode='EUR',unitPrice=50);
         insert pbe4;
        PriceLevelAdjustment.getProductList(new Map<String,String>{'pricebook'=>pricebookId,'ALTF__Solution__c'=>als.id,'Surface_Component_Grade__c'=>'test','mainproduct'=>'test','CurrencyIsoCode'=>'EUR','length_min'=>'20','length_max'=>'40'});
        
        
        Id batchInst=PriceLevelAdjustment.updatePrice(pbeLst,'1', 'Percent', 'M3');
        PriceLevelAdjustment.getTheBatchStatus(batchInst); 
        Test.stopTest(); 
    }
    
   
    
    public static User createTestUser( Id profID, String fName, String lName) {
        String orgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
        String dateString = 
            String.valueof(Datetime.now()).replace(' ','').replace(':','').replace('-','');
        Integer randomInt = Integer.valueOf(math.rint(math.random()*1000000));
        String uniqueName = orgId + dateString + randomInt;
        User tuser = new User(  firstname = fName,
                              lastName = lName,
                              email = uniqueName + '@test' + orgId + '.org',
                              Username = uniqueName + '@test' + orgId + '.org',
                              EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1',
                              Alias = uniqueName.substring(18, 23),
                              TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
                              LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                              LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                              ProfileId = profId
                              );
        return tuser;
    }
}
```

**AT PRESENT THIS IS 76% COVERED...BUT I NEED TO COVER THOSE IF CONDITIONS AS WELL.**

Comment: So you should add additional test methods that cause your new logic to be executed. You should also add assertions to your test methods.

Comment: See [How do I increase my code coverage, or why can't I cover these lines](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines)

Comment: Actually I have tried adding test methods and everything....Almost 4 days gone byt unable to cover it..That's why I finally came here so that someone can help writing it for me

Comment: Our canonical resources linked above, and the information linked from those resources, provide the foundation on testing practices you need here. This is not a difficult problem, but you _must_ thoroughly understand how testing works to achieve it.