# Code Coverage On FinServ Batch Job

Tags: apex, code-coverage, developer-console, roll-up-summary

I am new to Apex and am having a lot of trouble getting the code coverage to 75% on the bellow Apex Class. I had previously posted on the dev forum for salesforce and got coverage up to 71% by just invocing a call to the class: recalculateThreeRBLs.RBLTriggerFunction(); but now I am getting this error after multiple successful test runs "FinServ.MoiExceptionWrapper.IllegalArgumentException: Rollup Rules: Some records or IDs don't meet our criteria. Review your records and IDs and try again.". My code coverage is now back to zero :(

I can run the Apex class just fine through the anonymous execute console by calling the class, I don't get that error, but running the test on the class keeps failing.

Test Class:

```
// Author: 
// Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm#:~:text=executeBatch%20is%20as%20follows.,the%20job%20to%20the%20queue.
// Description: Will have to do assertions on exit codes since the RBL will not run on sandbox as expected, thus cannot test with test data

@isTest
private class testRTRBLs {
    @isTest static void TestFilters() {
        // This is the part where we would verify the results: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000XfJFQA0
        // Call apex class
        recalculateThreeRBLs.RBLTriggerFunction();
    }
}
```

Apex Class:

```
// Author: 
// Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.financial_services_cloud_admin_guide.meta/financial_services_cloud_admin_guide/fsc_admin_recalculate_rbl_with_apex.htm
// Description: 3 RBL's keep failing to run, this is just recalculating that roll up since a re-run seems to make it work

public class recalculateThreeRBLs {
    // can't put logic directly in a class, need to use a method:
    public static void RBLTriggerFunction (){
        // Create a new list to insert RBL Ids
        List<Id> rollupsToRun = new List<Id>();
        // Query rollup list and get the Id of the RBL where the name matches the 3 we are looking for
        List<FinServ__RollupByLookupConfig__c> queriedRollups = [SELECT Id FROM FinServ__RollupByLookupConfig__c WHERE Name IN ('RBLForInvestmentsHH','RBLforAUMHH','RBLForFinAcctsHHHeld')];
        // Insert into our rollupsToRun list the Ids we got back from the query
        for (FinServ__RollupByLookupConfig__c rollup : queriedRollups) {
        rollupsToRun.add(rollup.Id);
        }
    // Create an instance of RollupRecalculationBatchable
    FinServ.RollupRecalculationBatchable job = new FinServ.RollupRecalculationBatchable(rollupsToRun);

    // Run the rollups
    Database.executeBatch(job);
    } // end method
    
} // end class
```

Any help in getting this code coverage to 75% would be awesome, I had previous gotten coverage errors on these two lines:
rollupsToRun.add(rollup.Id);
Database.executeBatch(job);
I just don't understand how I would do an assert on these as there is no return value on them.

Thanks!

Comment: Code coverage isn't a goal in and of itself. Code coverage is meant to make sure your code does what it's supposed to do, and only that. Have you seen [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines)?

Comment: what (if anything) is mocked for `FinServ__RollupByLookupConfig__c` ? there has to be something to query

Comment: For the FinServ__RollupByLookupConfig__c object, I am querying in the Class, should I be doing a query in the Test as well? Though, now I am getting an error on the query in the class, "FinServ.MoiExceptionWrapper.IllegalArgumentException: Rollup Rules: Some records or ID's don't meet our criteria." But when I output the ID's using system.debug, I get the corresponding 18 Id for the relevant Rollups that I am trying to run. Might also be worth noting that if I run the apex class through the anonymous execution window it runs.