# in test class should pass lastweek is not equal to currentweek

Tags: unit-test, class

Main class

```java
global with sharing class FCSTWeeklyCopyBatchCtl implements DataBase.Batchable<sObject>
{
    public Date todaysDate;
    public String dayOfWeek;
    public Date mstartDate;
    public Date mendDate;


    global FCSTWeeklyCopyBatchCtl(){
        todaysDate= date.today();
        Datetime todaysDateTime = System.now();
        dayOfWeek = todaysDateTime.format('EEEE');
        mstartDate = Date.ValueOf(todaysDate).toStartOfMonth();
        mendDate = mstartDate.addDays(date.daysInMonth(mstartDate.year(),mstartDate.month())-1);

        System.debug('>>todaysDate>>'+todaysDate);
        System.debug('>>dayOfWeek>>'+dayOfWeek);
        System.debug('>>mstartDate>>'+mstartDate);
        System.debug('>>mendDate>>'+mendDate);
         if(Test.isRunningTest()) {
            mendDate = date.today();
        }
    }
    
    global DataBase.QueryLocator start(DataBase.BatchableContext bc){  
        
        
        //mendDate=todaysDate;//------------------

        
        System.debug('>start >dayOfWeek>>'+dayOfWeek);
        System.debug('>start >todaysDate>>'+todaysDate);
        System.debug('>start >mendDate>>'+mendDate);
       
        if(dayOfWeek=='Sunday' || todaysDate==mendDate){
            return DataBase.getQueryLocator([Select Id from User where IsActive = true]);  //and Id='0055f000005jY8g'--------------------
        }
        else{
            System.debug('----'+[Select Id from User where IsActive = true LIMIT :1]);
            return DataBase.getQueryLocator([Select Id from User where IsActive = true LIMIT:0]); 
        }
        
    }
    
    global void execute(DataBase.BatchableContext bc,List<User> userList){ 
        
        
        System.debug('>>execute>>');
        
   // mendDate=todaysDate;//------------------
        System.debug('>execute >dayOfWeek>>'+dayOfWeek);
        System.debug('>execute >todaysDate>>'+todaysDate);
        System.debug('>execute >mendDate>>'+mendDate);
        if(dayOfWeek=='Sunday' || todaysDate==mendDate){ 
            FCSTUtil utilObj = new FCSTUtil();
            
            /*if(dayOfWeek=='Sunday'){
                nextWeekOftheYear= utilObj.weekPart(todaysDate.addDays(1));
            }
            if(todaysDate==mendDate){
                nextWeekOftheYear= utilObj.weekPart(todaysDate.addDays(7));
            }*/
           // System.debug('>>nextWeekOftheYear>>'+nextWeekOftheYear);
            String monthStr=String.valueOf(todaysDate.Month());
            String yearStr=String.valueOf(todaysDate.year());
            
            Integer currentMonth=Integer.valueOf(monthStr);
            //Integer previousMonth=currentMonth-1;
            Integer currentYear =Integer.valueOf(yearStr);
            
            
            
            //Integer currentWeekOfYear=utilObj.weeknumberOfYear(todaysDate);
            Integer lastWeekOfMonth=utilObj.lastWeekOfMonth(todaysDate);
            Integer currentWeekOfMonth=utilObj.currentWeekOfMonth(todaysDate);
            Integer nextWeekOfMonth=currentWeekOfMonth+1;
            
            Integer currentWeekOfYear=utilObj.weeknumberOfYear(todaysDate);
            String nextWeekOftheYear=utilObj.weekPart(todaysDate.addDays(1));
            //System.debug('>>currentWeekOfMonth>>'+currentWeekOfMonth);
           
            System.debug('>>nextWeekOfMonth>>'+nextWeekOfMonth);
            System.debug('>>currentWeekOfMonth>>'+currentWeekOfMonth);

            List<Account_SO__c> updateAccountSO = new List<Account_SO__c>();
            List<User_SO__c> updateUserSO = new List<User_SO__c>();
            
            if(Test.isRunningTest()){
                lastWeekOfMonth=currentWeekOfMonth;
            }
            
            if(((Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.Month__c.isCreateable() || 
            Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.Month__c.isUpdateable()) &&
            Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.Month__c.isAccessible()) && 
            ((Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.Year__c.isCreateable() || 
            Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.Year__c.isUpdateable()) &&
            Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.Year__c.isAccessible()) && 
            ((Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.Account__c.isCreateable() || 
            Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.Account__c.isUpdateable()) &&
            Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.Account__c.isAccessible()) && 
            ((Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.RecordTypeId.isCreateable() || 
            Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.RecordTypeId.isUpdateable()) &&
            Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.RecordTypeId.isAccessible()) && 
            ((Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.W1_Opportunity_KPI__c.isCreateable() || 
            Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.W1_Opportunity_KPI__c.isUpdateable()) &&
            Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.W1_Opportunity_KPI__c.isAccessible()) && 
            ((Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.W2_Opportunity_KPI__c.isCreateable() || 
            Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.W2_Opportunity_KPI__c.isUpdateable()) &&
            Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.W2_Opportunity_KPI__c.isAccessible()) && 
            ((Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.W3_Opportunity_KPI__c.isCreateable() || 
            Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.W3_Opportunity_KPI__c.isUpdateable()) &&
            Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.W3_Opportunity_KPI__c.isAccessible()) && 
            ((Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.W4_Opportunity_KPI__c.isCreateable() || 
            Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.W4_Opportunity_KPI__c.isUpdateable()) &&
            Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.W4_Opportunity_KPI__c.isAccessible()) && 
            ((Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.W5_Opportunity_KPI__c.isCreateable() || 
            Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.W5_Opportunity_KPI__c.isUpdateable()) &&
            Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.W5_Opportunity_KPI__c.isAccessible()) && 
            ((Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.W6_Opportunity_KPI__c.isCreateable() || 
            Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.W6_Opportunity_KPI__c.isUpdateable()) &&
            Schema.sObjectType.Account_SO__c.fields.W6_Opportunity_KPI__c.isAccessible()) &&
            ((Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.Month__c.isCreateable() || 
            Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.Month__c.isUpdateable()) &&
            Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.Month__c.isAccessible()) && 
            ((Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.Year__c.isCreateable() || 
            Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.Year__c.isUpdateable()) &&
            Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.Year__c.isAccessible()) && 
            ((Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.AI_ID__c.isCreateable() || 
            Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.AI_ID__c.isUpdateable()) &&
            Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.AI_ID__c.isAccessible()) && 
            ((Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.User__c.isCreateable() || 
            Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.User__c.isUpdateable()) &&
            Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.User__c.isAccessible()) && 
            ((Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.RecordTypeId.isCreateable() || 
            Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.RecordTypeId.isUpdateable()) &&
            Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.RecordTypeId.isAccessible()) && 
            ((Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.W1_Opportunity_KPI__c.isCreateable() || 
            Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.W1_Opportunity_KPI__c.isUpdateable()) &&
            Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.W1_Opportunity_KPI__c.isAccessible()) && 
            ((Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.W2_Opportunity_KPI__c.isCreateable() || 
            Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.W2_Opportunity_KPI__c.isUpdateable()) &&
            Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.W2_Opportunity_KPI__c.isAccessible()) && 
            ((Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.W3_Opportunity_KPI__c.isCreateable() || 
            Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.W3_Opportunity_KPI__c.isUpdateable()) &&
            Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.W3_Opportunity_KPI__c.isAccessible()) && 
            ((Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.W4_Opportunity_KPI__c.isCreateable() || 
            Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.W4_Opportunity_KPI__c.isUpdateable()) &&
            Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.W4_Opportunity_KPI__c.isAccessible()) && 
            ((Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.W5_Opportunity_KPI__c.isCreateable() || 
            Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.W5_Opportunity_KPI__c.isUpdateable()) &&
            Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.W5_Opportunity_KPI__c.isAccessible()) && 
            ((Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.W6_Opportunity_KPI__c.isCreateable() || 
            Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.W6_Opportunity_KPI__c.isUpdateable()) &&
            Schema.sObjectType.User_SO__c.fields.W6_Opportunity_KPI__c.isAccessible()) ){
               // System.debug('>>userList>>'+userList);
                if(userList!=null && userList.size()>0){ 
                    
                    List<Account_SO__c> accountSOList=FCSTQueryUtil.getAccountSOList(userList,monthStr,yearStr);
                    
                    List<User_SO__c> userSOList=FCSTQueryUtil.getUserSOList(userList,monthStr,yearStr);
                    
                   // System.debug('>>accountSOList>>'+accountSOList);
                   //System.debug('accountSOList>>>'+accountSOList);
                  // lastWeekOfMonth=currentWeekOfMonth; //-----------------------------
                  System.debug('>execute >currentWeekOfMonth>>'+currentWeekOfMonth);
                  System.debug('>execute >lastWeekOfMonth>>'+lastWeekOfMonth);

                    if(currentWeekOfMonth!=lastWeekOfMonth ){
                        System.debug('>execute >currentWeekOfMonth!=lastWeekOfMonth>>');
                        if(accountSOList!=null && accountSOList.size()>0){
                            for(Account_SO__c accSO:accountSOList){
                                String jsonVal=FCSTUtil.getFieldValue(accSO,currentWeekOfMonth);
                               // System.debug('jsonVal>>>'+jsonVal);
                               if(jsonVal!=null && jsonVal!=''){
                                    FCSTManagerWrapper accWrapObj=(FCSTManagerWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(jsonVal, FCSTManagerWrapper.class);
                                    accWrapObj.Week=nextWeekOftheYear;
                                    //System.debug('accWrapObj>>>'+accWrapObj);
                                    //System.debug('accWrapObj>>>'+accWrapObj.ForecastCategory[0].Cat_days_To_Close);
                                    String JSONString = JSON.serialize(accWrapObj);
                                    // system.debug('JSONString : ' + JSONString );
                                    accSO=FCSTUtil.accSOFieldValAssign(nextWeekOfMonth,accSO,JSONString);
                                    // system.debug('accSO : ' + accSO );
                                    updateAccountSO.add(accSO);  
                               }  
                                
                            }
                        }
                        if(userSOList!=null && userSOList.size()>0){
                            for(User_SO__c userSO:userSOList){
                                String jsonValUser=FCSTUtil.getFieldValue(userSO,currentWeekOfMonth);
                                Decimal aIProjection=FCSTUtil.getAIProFieldValue(userSO,currentWeekOfMonth);
                                String adjustCommit=FCSTUtil.getAdjustFieldValue(userSO,currentWeekOfMonth);
                                
                                if(jsonValUser!=null && jsonValUser!=''){
                                    FCSTManagerWrapper accWrapObj2=(FCSTManagerWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(jsonValUser, FCSTManagerWrapper.class);
                                    accWrapObj2.Week=nextWeekOftheYear;
                                    //System.debug('accWrapObj>>>'+accWrapObj);
                                    //System.debug('accWrapObj>>>'+accWrapObj.ForecastCategory[0].Cat_days_To_Close);
                                    String JSONString2 = JSON.serialize(accWrapObj2);
                                    
                                    userSO=FCSTUtil.userSOFieldValAssign(nextWeekOfMonth,userSO,JSONString2);
                                    userSO=FCSTUtil.userSOAdjustAssign(nextWeekOfMonth,userSO,adjustCommit);
                                    userSO=FCSTUtil.userSOAIProAssign(nextWeekOfMonth,userSO,aIProjection);
                                    
                                    updateUserSO.add(userSO);  
                                }
                                
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                    if(currentWeekOfMonth==lastWeekOfMonth ){
                        System.debug('>execute >currentWeekOfMonth==lastWeekOfMonth>>');
                        //System.debug('>>accountSOList>>'+accountSOList);
                        if(accountSOList!=null && accountSOList.size()>0){
                            for(Account_SO__c accSO:accountSOList){
                               
                                String jsonVal=FCSTUtil.getFieldValue(accSO,currentWeekOfMonth);
                                if(jsonVal!=null && jsonVal!=''){
                                    FCSTManagerWrapper accWrapObj=(FCSTManagerWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(jsonVal, FCSTManagerWrapper.class);
                                    accWrapObj.Week=nextWeekOftheYear;
                                    //System.debug('accWrapObj>>>'+accWrapObj);
                                    //System.debug('accWrapObj>>>'+accWrapObj.ForecastCategory[0].Cat_days_To_Close);
                                    
                                    

                                    
                                        //System.debug('>>jsonVal>>'+jsonVal);
                                        Account_SO__c newAccSO = new Account_SO__c();
                                        newAccSO.Account__c=accSO.Account__c;
                                        if(currentMonth!=12){
                                            newAccSO.Month__c=String.valueOf(currentMonth+1);
                                            newAccSO.Year__c=accSO.Year__c;
                                            accWrapObj.Month=String.valueOf(currentMonth+1);
                                            accWrapObj.Year=accSO.Year__c;
                                            
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            newAccSO.Month__c=String.valueOf(1);  
                                            newAccSO.Year__c=String.valueOf(currentYear+1);
                                            accWrapObj.Month=String.valueOf(1);
                                            accWrapObj.Year=String.valueOf(currentYear+1);
                                        }
                                        newAccSO.RecordTypeId=accSO.RecordTypeId;

                                        String JSONString = JSON.serialize(accWrapObj);
                                        newAccSO.W1_Opportunity_KPI__c=JSONString; 
                                        
                                        
                                        updateAccountSO.add(newAccSO);  
                                }
                                
                            }
                        }
                        //System.debug('>>userSOList>>'+userSOList);
                        if(userSOList!=null && userSOList.size()>0){
                            for(User_SO__c userSO:userSOList){
                               // System.debug('>>currentWeekOfMonth>>'+currentWeekOfMonth);
                                String jsonValUser=FCSTUtil.getFieldValue(userSO,currentWeekOfMonth);
                               // System.debug('>>jsonValUser>>'+jsonValUser);
                               if(jsonValUser!=null && jsonValUser!=''){
                               
                                    FCSTManagerWrapper userWrapObj=(FCSTManagerWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(jsonValUser, FCSTManagerWrapper.class);
                                    userWrapObj.Week=nextWeekOftheYear;
                                    //System.debug('accWrapObj>>>'+accWrapObj);
                                    //System.debug('accWrapObj>>>'+accWrapObj.ForecastCategory[0].Cat_days_To_Close);
                                    
                                    
                                    Decimal aIProjection=FCSTUtil.getAIProFieldValue(userSO,currentWeekOfMonth);
                                    String adjustCommit=FCSTUtil.getAdjustFieldValue(userSO,currentWeekOfMonth);
                                    //System.debug('>>adjustCommit>>'+adjustCommit);
                                    
                                    User_SO__c newUserSO = new User_SO__c();
                                    newUserSO.User__c=userSO.User__c;
                                    newUserSO.RecordTypeId=userSO.RecordTypeId;

                                    wrapperAdjustmentCtl adjustWrapper = new wrapperAdjustmentCtl();   
                                    if(adjustCommit!=null && adjustCommit!=''){
                                        adjustWrapper=(wrapperAdjustmentCtl) System.JSON.deserialize(adjustCommit, wrapperAdjustmentCtl.class);
                                        adjustWrapper.Week='1';
                                    }
                                

                                    if(currentMonth!=12){
                                        newUserSO.Month__c=String.valueOf(currentMonth+1);
                                        newUserSO.Year__c=userSO.Year__c;
                                        userWrapObj.Month=String.valueOf(currentMonth+1);
                                        userWrapObj.Year=userSO.Year__c;
                                        if(adjustCommit!=null && adjustCommit!=''){
                                            adjustWrapper.Month=String.valueOf(currentMonth+1);
                                        }
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        newUserSO.Month__c=String.valueOf(1);  
                                        newUserSO.Year__c=String.valueOf(currentYear+1);
                                        userWrapObj.Month=String.valueOf(1);
                                        userWrapObj.Year=String.valueOf(currentYear+1);
                                        if(adjustCommit!=null && adjustCommit!=''){
                                            adjustWrapper.Month=String.valueOf(1);
                                        }
                                        
                                    }
                                    if(adjustCommit!=null && adjustCommit!=''){
                                        String adjustCommitJson = JSON.serialize(adjustWrapper);
                                        newUserSO.Week_1_Adjustment__c=adjustCommitJson;
                                        //System.debug('>>adjustCommitJson>>'+adjustCommitJson);
                                    }
                                    String UserJSONString = JSON.serialize(userWrapObj);
                                    newUserSO.W1_Opportunity_KPI__c=UserJSONString; 
                                    newUserSO.W1_AI_Projection__c=aIProjection; 
                                
                                    
                                    newUserSO.AI_ID__c=userSO.Record_Type__c+'#'+newUserSO.User__c+newUserSO.Year__c+newUserSO.Month__c;   
                                    updateUserSO.add(newUserSO);  
                                }
                                //System.debug('>>newUserSO>>'+newUserSO);
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                //System.debug('updateAccountSO>>>'+updateAccountSO);
                if(updateAccountSO!=null && updateAccountSO.size()>0){
                    
                    upsert updateAccountSO;
                }
               // System.debug('>>updateUserSO>>'+updateUserSO);
                if(updateUserSO!=null && updateUserSO.size()>0){
                 upsert updateUserSO;
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    
    global void finish(DataBase.BatchableContext bc){
        
    }
    
}
```

how to  write test class

Comment: in test class should cove if(currentWeekOfMonth!=lastWeekOfMonth ) line no:168

Comment: Do these answer your question? [How do I write an Apex unit test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test) and [How do I increase my code coverage, or why can't I cover these lines?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines)

Comment: This site isn't a free coding service. If you're new to Salesforce (or a part/feature thereof) then trailhead.salesforce.com is going to be where you should start.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you can't cover that code indicates you have a logic bug in your code. It literally cannot be covered in a unit test, because of this code:

```
    if(Test.isRunningTest()){
        lastWeekOfMonth=currentWeekOfMonth;
    }
```

You'll have to fix the logic in order to make the unit test cover the logic, perhaps by doing something like this:

```
@TestVisible static Integer lastWeekOfMonthOverride;
```

...

```
if(lastWeekOfMonthOverride != null) {
  lastWeekOfMonth = lastWeekOfMonthOverride;
}
```

Which you can then set in your unit test:

```
FCSTWeeklyCopyBatchCtl.lastWeekOfMonthOverride = 6; // Or whatever
```

Comment: Thanku you very much

Comment: @TestVisible static Integer lastWeekOfMonthOverride<--- this code should be add in main class ?

Comment: @satya Yes, it would need to be in the main class.

Comment: @TestVisible static Integer lastWeekOfMonthOverride showing error like static is not allowed

Comment: if it possible can u edit my test class for clear codeing

Comment: ok thanks its working