# Apex test Trigger Service

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

I have such an apex class and a test for it. However, the test coverage is only 84%, and I need 100%. How can I change the test class to have 100% coverage?

```
public class InterviewService {

    public static final Integer MAX_INTERVIEW_PER_WEEK = 3;

    public static void preventCreateInterview(List<Interview__c> interviews) {
        Map<Id,Integer> ids = new Map<Id,Integer>();
        List<AggregateResult> aggregateResults = InterviewSelector.getInterviewListThisWeek(interviews);
        for (AggregateResult ar : aggregateResults) {
            Id intId = (Id) ar.get('Interviewer__c');
            for(Interview__c inter : interviews){
                if(inter.Interviewer__c == intId){
                    ids.put(intId, (Integer) ar.get('interviewCount'));
                }
            }
        }
        for (Interview__c inter : interviews) {
            if (ids.get(inter.Interviewer__c) >= MAX_INTERVIEW_PER_WEEK && inter.Scheduled_interview_date__c != null) {
                inter.addError('You already have 3 interviews per week for this interviewer. Please choose another interviewer');
            } else {
                inter.Stage__c = 'Scheduled';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TestDataFactory

```
@IsTest
public class TestDataFactory {

    public static List<Interview__c> createInterviewWithInterviewer(Integer numInterview, Integer numContact) {
        List<Contact> contacts  = new List<Contact>();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < numContact; i++){
            Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'TestContact'+ i,RecordTypeId = '0127R000000WJ24QAG',Email = 'lukasevicboda@gmail.com');
            contacts.add(c);
        }
        insert contacts;
        List<Interview__c> interviews = new List<Interview__c>();
        for(Integer j = 0; j < numContact; j++) {
            Contact cont = contacts[j];
            for (Integer i = 0; i < numInterview; i++) {
                interviews.add(new Interview__c(Name = 'devops' + i, Interviewer__c =cont.Id,Stage__c = 'Arranged'));
            }
        }
        return interviews;
    }

    public static List<Interview__c> createInterviewWithInterviewer(Integer numInterview){
        Contact contact = new Contact(LastName = 'TestContact', RecordTypeId = '0127R000000WJ24QAG');
        insert contact;
        List<Interview__c> interviews = new List<Interview__c>();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < numInterview; i++) {
            interviews.add(new Interview__c(Name = 'devops' + i, Interviewer__c =contact.Id, Stage__c = 'Arranged'));
        }
        return interviews;
    }
}

@IsTest
public class TestDataFactory {

    public static List<Interview__c> createInterviewWithInterviewer(Integer numInterview, Integer numContact) {
        List<Contact> contacts  = new List<Contact>();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < numContact; i++){
            Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'TestContact'+ i,RecordTypeId = '0127R000000WJ24QAG',Email = 'lukasevicboda@gmail.com');
            contacts.add(c);
        }
        insert contacts;
        List<Interview__c> interviews = new List<Interview__c>();
        for(Integer j = 0; j < numContact; j++) {
            Contact cont = contacts[j];
            for (Integer i = 0; i < numInterview; i++) {
                interviews.add(new Interview__c(Name = 'devops' + i, Interviewer__c =cont.Id,Stage__c = 'Arranged'));
            }
        }
        return interviews;
    }

    public static List<Interview__c> createInterviewWithInterviewer(Integer numInterview){
        Contact contact = new Contact(LastName = 'TestContact', RecordTypeId = '0127R000000WJ24QAG');
        insert contact;
        List<Interview__c> interviews = new List<Interview__c>();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < numInterview; i++) {
            interviews.add(new Interview__c(Name = 'devops' + i, Interviewer__c =contact.Id, Stage__c = 'Arranged'));
        }
        return interviews;
    }
}
```

Test

```
@IsTest
public class InterviewServiceTest {

    @IsTest
    static void testInterview() {
        List<Interview__c> interviews = TestDataFactory.createInterviewWithInterviewer(3);
        Test.startTest();
        insert interviews;
        for(Integer i=0; i<interviews.size(); i++) {
            interviews[i].Scheduled_interview_date__c = System.today() + 1;
        }
        update interviews;
        Test.stopTest();
        System.equals('Scheduled', interviews[0].Stage__c);
    }

    @IsTest
    static void testInterviewError() {
        List<Interview__c> interviews = TestDataFactory.createInterviewWithInterviewer(10);
        System.debug(interviews.size());
        Test.startTest();
        try {
            for (Integer i = 0; i < interviews.size(); i++) {
                interviews[i].Scheduled_interview_date__c = System.today() + 1;
            }
            update interviews;
            System.assert(false, 'DMLException is expected here');
        } catch (DmlException ex) {

        }
        Test.stopTest();
    }

    @IsTest
    static void testBulkInterview() {
        List<Interview__c> interviews = TestDataFactory.createInterviewWithInterviewer(20, 30);
        Test.startTest();
        insert interviews;
        for (Integer i = 0; i < interviews.size(); i++) {
            interviews[i].Scheduled_interview_date__c = System.today() + 1;
        }
        update interviews;
        Test.stopTest();
        System.equals(20, interviews.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I increase my code coverage, or why can't I cover these lines?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help. I still can't get into the if. maybe you know how to solve it?

Comment: Fundamentally your trigger doesn't work if you try to add multiple interviews in a single transaction. While it does query the data (via aggregate query) for existing interviews, it fails to consider all the new/updated interviews received together. So if you had zero interviews for the interviewer and then try to add 10 in a single DML, the trigger will think that each interview can be added (since 0 + 1 < 3). As you process each new/updated interview you need to increment the counter.

Comment: How to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger service fails to consider that it may receive multiple new/updated interviews that may be for the same interviewer and only considers pre-existing interviews when collecting the counters.

You could try updating the code something like the following:

```
public class InterviewService {

    public static final Integer MAX_INTERVIEW_PER_WEEK = 3;

    public static void preventCreateInterview(List<Interview__c> interviews) {
        Map<Id, Integer> interviewCountByInterviewer = new Map<Id, Integer>();
        List<AggregateResult> aggregateResults = InterviewSelector.getInterviewListThisWeek(interviews);
        Set<Id> interviewers = new Set<Id>();

        // Collect the unique interviewer IDs from the given interviews
        for (Interview__c interview : interviews) {
            interviewers.add(interview.Interviewer__c);
            
            // Default the count to ensure we don't have problems where
            // interviewers have no existing interviews
            interviewCountByInterviewer.put(interview.Interviewer__c, 0);
        }

        // Only add the interview counts for those interviewers involved with the interviews given
        for (AggregateResult ar : aggregateResults) {
            Id interviewer = (Id) ar.get('Interviewer__c');

            if (interviewers.contains(interviewer)) {
                interviewCountByInterviewer.put(interviewer, (Integer) ar.get('interviewCount'));
            }
        }

        for (Interview__c interview : interviews) {
            if (interviewCountByInterviewer.get(interview.Interviewer__c) >= MAX_INTERVIEW_PER_WEEK && interview.Scheduled_interview_date__c != null) {
                interview.addError('You already have ' + MAX_INTERVIEW_PER_WEEK + ' interviews per week for this interviewer. Please choose another interviewer');
            } else {
                interview.Stage__c = 'Scheduled';

                // We must count this as an extra assigned interview for the interviewer so increment the counter
                interviewCountByInterviewer.put(interview.Interviewer__c, interviewCountByInterviewer.get(interview.Interviewer__c) + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The most important change is the incrementing of the count when setting the stage to Scheduled.

Note that this code change also removes an anti-pattern; nested for loops for data matching.

Honestly, I'm not sure why you only add the interview count from the aggregate query if it is for one of the input interviews' already assigned interviewers, but then I can't see what your `InterviewSelector.getInterviewListThisWeek` is doing. The other thing that concerns me is that I don't know if this service is only receiving interviews for the "this week" period...

It is good that you realized that you needed to have a test that checked the error scenario. I haven't carefully checked the test, but it was clear that the service may be failing to do the job it needs to if we assume that the interviews it receives are coming from `Trigger.new` in a trigger and that the service is called before insert and before update.

I have made various assumptions here, since I don't have the complete picture.

Comment: Yes, this service accepts interviews only for the period of this week

Comment: However, these changes do not fix code coverage

Comment: Well, take it as a step forward and make sure your test data is appropriate for getting you into the problem scenario of > 3 existing OR NEW interviews for an interviewer.

Comment: BTW, you may hit issues if `interviewCountByInterviewer` is not set for one of the interviewers, so I've remedied that.