# Test class for Trigger Handler covering multiple if conditions

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have written below test class for apex class but unable to cover all the if conditions

Apex class

```
public with sharing class TagDefinitionTriggerHandler  {

 private static boolean hasBeenProccessed = false;


   public void OnAfterInsert(List<Tag_Definition__C> newRecords) {
       callDataExport(newRecords);

    }


     
    public void OnAfterUpdate (List<Tag_Definition__C> newRecords) {        
       callDataExport(newRecords);

    }

     public void OnAfterDelete (Map<Id, Tag_Definition__C> oldMap) {
       callDataExport(oldMap.values());

    }


    private static void callDataExport(List<Tag_Definition__C> newRecords) {
           
        Connected_Data_Export_Switch__c config = Connected_Data_Export_Switch__c.getInstance('DataExport');
        if (!Test.isRunningTest() && config.Data_Extraction_Insert_Flag__c && !hasBeenProccessed ) {
            if (config.Enable_Trace_Logging__c) {
                ConnectedLog.LogInformation('GCPSync/Trigger/InsertDataExtraction', 'TagDefinitionTriggerHandler', 'callDataExport', 
                    'Triggered ' + newRecords.size() + ' Tag_Definition__C records: ' + CDCDataExportUtility.joinObjIds(newRecords));
            }
            PubSubBatchHandler.insertDataExteractionRecord(newRecords, 'Tag_Definition__C');
            hasBeenProccessed = true; 
        }

    }


}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
public class TagDefinitionTriggerHandler_Test{
    static testMethod void testInsertTag(){
         List<Tag_Definition__C> tagList = new List<Tag_Definition__C>();
         for(Integer i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++){
              Tag_Definition__C tag = new Tag_Definition__C();
              tagList.add(tag);
         }
         if(tagList != null){
          insert tagList; 
        }
        Test.startTest();
        update tagList;
        Test.stopTest();    
     }
    static testMethod void test_OnAfterDelete_UseCase1(){
    List<Tag_Definition__C> tag_Obj  =  new List<Tag_Definition__C>();
    System.assertEquals(false,tag_Obj.size()>0);
    TagDefinitionTriggerHandler obj01 = new TagDefinitionTriggerHandler();
    obj01.OnAfterDelete(new Map<Id,Tag_Definition__C>());
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you share a more specific issue, what can't you cover? I fear this is why you are getting downvotes...

Comment: @Girbot I am not able to cover - this part -```  if (config.Enable_Trace_Logging__c) {
                ConnectedLog.LogInformation('GCPSync/Trigger/InsertDataExtraction', 'TagDefinitionTriggerHandler', 'callDataExport', 
                    'Triggered ' + newRecords.size() + ' Tag_Definition__C records: ' + CDCDataExportUtility.joinObjIds(newRecords));
            }
            PubSubBatchHandler.insertDataExteractionRecord(newRecords, 'Tag_Definition__C');
            hasBeenProccessed = true; 
        } ```

Comment: The `testmethod` keyword is deprecated. You should be using the `@isTest` annotation for test methods instead.

Comment: You're also using a really poor method of recursion control here. Using a static boolean means that your code will be prevented from running if you insert and update the same set of records in a single transaction (or update then delete). It'll also only run for the first 200 records (if you're DML-ing more than 200 records) that are involved in a single DML call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I increase my code coverage, or why can't I cover these lines?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines)

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can't cover the `if` statements. You explicitly have `!Test.isRunningTest()` in the outermost `if`.

That condition will naturally evaluate to false *when you are running a test method*.

Beyond that, you never create test records for your `Connected_Data_Export_Switch__c` custom setting. Custom Settings are data (not metadata) and so must be created in your unit test. As is, you're getting a "blank" custom setting record with all of the fields set to `null` (assuming the API version of this code is >= 21)