# Unit Test Code Coverage 72% Help

Tags: unit-test

I have created a test class for an apex class and code coverage is only at 72%. I am looking for any assistance you can provide, to increase it to 75%+.

Uncovered lines: 5/18. The lines are within the for loop.

Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class MassApproveRejectTest{
    @TestSetup
    static void makeData(){
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = 'Test';
        acc.Global_ID_Desc__c = 'International Customer';
        acc.Eligible_for_Proforma__c = True;
        
        insert acc;
        
        Commitment_And_Rebate__c cr = new Commitment_And_Rebate__c();
        cr.Account__c = acc.Id;
        cr.Year__c = '2021';
        cr.Commitment_Type__c = 'RCGL';
        cr.Current_Commitment_Amt__c = 1000000;
        
        insert cr;
    }
     @isTest
    public static void itShouldApprove() {
        Id accId = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Test'].Id;
        Id crId = [SELECT Id FROM Commitment_And_Rebate__c WHERE Account__c =: accId LIMIT 1].Id;
        List<Id> crIds = new List<Id>{crId};
        
        //Submit for Approval
        Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest testApproval = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
        testapproval.setComments('Submitting for approval from test class');
        testApproval.setobjectid(crId);
        Approval.ProcessResult result1 = Approval.process(testapproval);
        
        Test.startTest();  
        //Call approveRecs method in MassApproveReject Class
        MassApproveReject.approveRecs(new List<List<id>>{crIds});
        Test.stopTest();
        
    }

    @isTest
    public static void itShouldNotApprove() {
        Test.startTest();  
        //Call approveRecs method in MassApproveReject Class
        MassApproveReject.approveRecs(null);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Apex Class:

```
public class MassApproveReject
{
    @InvocableMethod(label = 'Mass Approve Records'
                     description = 'Approve the list of records that are selected by the user. This is intended to be invoked from a screen flow after logged user has selected the records that needs to be approved.'
                    )
    public static List<String> approveRecs(List<List<Id>> recordIds) {
        List<String> approvedListIds = new List<String>();
        try{
            //Empty lists will not be passed to this method. It will be validated in the screen flow that calls this Apex
            List<Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest> requests = new List<Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest>();
            List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem> piWorkItems = [
                SELECT Id, ProcessInstanceId 
                FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem 
                WHERE ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId IN :recordIds.get(0)
                AND ProcessInstance.Status = 'Pending'
            ];
            //Set approve for each record
            for(ProcessInstanceWorkitem piWorkItem : piWorkItems){
                Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
                req.setWorkitemId(piWorkItem.Id);
                req.setAction('Approve');
                req.setComments('Approved using Mass Approval Flow');
                requests.add(req);     
            }
            //Approve all records
            Approval.ProcessResult[] processResults = Approval.process(requests); 
            approvedListIds.add('Success');
            return approvedListIds;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            approvedListIds.add('Failure');
            return approvedListIds;
        }    
    }   
}
```

Comment: Sugi, I think you accidentally copied the same code twice! You can [edit] your question to put in the unit test code. I've added formatting for you, just copy-and-paste between there. Note that this question might not be answered, though, as we usually just like the tagged [tag:canonical-qa] question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/244794/2984). Hint: you can iterate over an empty loop without an error, and the lines inside won't be covered.

Comment: Thank you so for your reply. I have edited and pasted the test class. I am fairly new to Coding. I am a SF Admin and had to resort to coding since Mass approval was not achievable using flows. Thank you for your hint. I will definitely try to get the test to update the test class to iterate inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have no records of `ProcessWorkItem` created in your test class, so the query for `piWorkItems` returns 0 records, so the for loop never executes.

I don't know how to create those records in a test, but that's the reason your code isn't covered.

Comment: Thank you for providing your inputs David. I was under the impression that submitting the record for approval automatically created the records in ProcessInstanceWorkitem. I was able to submit a record through the UI and confirm that a record was created in ProcessInstance and ProcessInstanceWorkitem. However, I am not sure how this behavior works when a record is submtited via apex. What you are saying makes the most sense since the code is not skipping over the for loop. I will continue to investigate keeping your inputs in mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for looking into this. This ended up being a data set up issue. A field at the account was included in the setup which resolved the issue.