# I trying to write test class for a Apex class. I covered the try statement where I couldn't cover the catch statement. Please help me to resolve

Tags: code-coverage, failing-tests, try-catch

Main Class:

```
public class PrintJobPDFController {
    @AuraEnabled 
    public static List<String> getPDFprint(string recordId) {
        try{
            System.debug('recordId'+recordId);
            List<string> pageStrings = new List<String>();
            PageReference pdfPage = new PageReference('/apex/generatePdf?Id=' + recordId);
            Blob pdfBlob;
            if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
                pdfBlob = pdfPage.getContent();
            } else {
                pdfBlob = Blob.valueOf('adad');
            }
            
            String downloadURL = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(pdfBlob);
            pageStrings.add(downloadURL);
            pageStrings.add(URL.getOrgDomainURL().toExternalForm()+pdfPage.getUrl());
            return pageStrings;
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('*********Error*************'+e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class PrintJobPDFControllerTest {
    @isTest
    private static void getPdf() {
        
        test.startTest();
        
        PageReference pageRef = Page.generatePdf;      
        Account acc = new Account(Name='test');
        insert acc;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        pageRef.getParameters().put('Id',acc.id);
        try{
            List<String> result = PrintJobPDFController.getPDFprint(acc.Id);
        } catch(exception e){}
        Test.stopTest();       
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I increase my code coverage, or why can't I cover these lines?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines)

Comment: You don't need to use try-catch in your test code.  Just call your methods with correct values to test success, and call with improper values to test failure.

Comment: The general solution for covering catch blocks is to refactor your code so you can introduce dependency injection of mock services that throw mock exceptions. See this excellent discussion by [Joe Lemmer](https://www.joelemmer.com/apexmocks-documentation-stubbing/) that exploits ApexMocks.  That said, for your use case, the other comments and answers make sense

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't really seem to be anything that could cause a catchable exception to be thrown. About the only thing that could throw one is `pdfPage.getContent();` if your given Id is null or maybe if it's not an Account Id.

Given that, it may be appropriate to remove the try/catch altogether. If you want to keep it, you're going to need to look at the controller/extension for your `generatePDF` page to see if you can cause an exception (or specifically add a method for the sole purpose of throwing an exception).

On another note, 100% code coverage isn't really the end goal. It's far more important to:

- Have multiple tests that stress different scenarios (like having a test where you pass in an Id for a Contact, and another where the passed in Id is null)
- Make assertions to verify that the result of running your code is what you expect (e.g. that you get `EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf('adad'))` in your list of strings that get returned)

You could have 100% coverage of a method that tells you that 2 + 2 = 5. Coverage doesn't tell you if your code is correct, assertions can.

Also, get rid of that try/catch in your test method. It does nothing except make it harder for you to test/debug issues.