# Hi..Need help to cover the ContentDocumentLink part in uploadFile2 method and uploadFile method in @InvocableMethod. I mentioned as need to cover part

Tags: apex, code-coverage

Main Class:

```
global class FileUploadController {
    public static void uploadFile2(Id parentId, String fileName, String fileContent) {
        // Initialize response object
        Map<String, Object> response = new Map<String, Object>();
        
        // Define the Body variable outside the try block
        String Body;
        
        try {
            // Decode the base64 encoded content of the web file
            Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(fileContent).toString();
            
            // Create a ContentVersion record
            ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion();
            contentVersion.Title = fileName;
            contentVersion.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(fileContent);
            insert contentVersion;
            
            //Need to cover this part
            // Create a ContentDocumentLink record
            ContentDocumentLink contentDocumentLink = new ContentDocumentLink();
            contentDocumentLink.LinkedEntityId = parentId;
            contentDocumentLink.ContentDocumentId = contentVersion.ContentDocumentId;
            insert contentDocumentLink;
            
            // Set the success response
            response.put('success', true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log the error or add system.debug statements for debugging.
            System.debug('Error in uploadFile: ' + e.getMessage());
            
            // Set the error response
            response.put('success', false);
            response.put('message', e.getMessage());
        }
        
        // Return response JSON
        String responseJSON = JSON.serialize(response);
        RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(responseJSON);
    }
    
    // Need to cover if condition in this method
    
    @InvocableMethod(label='Files Method' description='Files processing')
    global static void uploadFile(List<Requests> requestList){
        system.debug('requestList'+requestList);
        if (requestList != null && !requestList.isEmpty()) {
            List<DataTypes> inputCollection = requestList[0].inputCollection;
            if (inputCollection != null) {
                for(DataTypes req : inputCollection){
                    uploadFile(req.base64,req.filename,req.recordId);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    global static String uploadFile(String base64, String filename, String recordId) {
        ContentVersion cv = createContentVersion(base64, filename,recordId);
        System.debug('CV@@@'+cv.Id);
        ContentDocumentLink cdl = createContentLink(cv.Id, recordId);
        if (cv == null || cdl == null) { return null; }
        System.debug('jcdl@@@'+cdl);
        return cdl.Id;
    }

    global static ContentVersion createContentVersion(String base64, String filename, String recordId) {
        ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
        cv.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64);
        cv.Title = filename;
        cv.PathOnClient = filename;
        cv.ContentLocation = 'S';
        cv.firstPublishLocationId= recordId;
        
        try {
            insert cv;
            return cv;
        } catch (DmlException e) {
            System.debug(e);
            throw new AuraHandledException('Error creating ContentVersion: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    global static ContentDocumentLink createContentLink(String contentVersionId, String recordId) {
        System.debug(contentVersionId+'--->'+recordId);
        if (contentVersionId == null || recordId == null) { return null; }
        ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
        cdl.ContentDocumentId = [
            SELECT ContentDocumentId 
            FROM ContentVersion 
            WHERE Id =: contentVersionId
        ].ContentDocumentId;
        cdl.LinkedEntityId = recordId;
        // ShareType is either 'V', 'C', or 'I'
        // V = Viewer, C = Collaborator, I = Inferred
        cdl.ShareType = 'V';
        cdl.Visibility = 'AllUser';
        try {
            insert cdl;
            return cdl;
        } catch(DMLException e) {
            System.debug(e);
            return null;
        }
    }

  global class Requests {
    @InvocableVariable(label='Records for Input' description='yourDescription' required=true)
    global List<DataTypes> inputCollection;
  }
}
```

Inner Class:

```
public  with sharing class DataTypes {
    @AuraEnabled 
    public String fileName;
    
    @AuraEnabled 
    public String base64;
    
    @AuraEnabled 
    public String recordId;
    
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class FileUploadControllerTest {
    
    @isTest
    static void testUploadFile2() {
            
        Case ca = new Case(Description = 'Test', Status = 'New');
        insert ca;
        String fileName = 'TestFile.txt';
        String fileContent = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf('Test file content'));

        // Mock the RestContext
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
        RestResponse response = new RestResponse();
        RestContext.request = request;
        RestContext.response = response;
        
        Test.startTest();
        FileUploadController.uploadFile2(ca.Id, fileName, fileContent);
        Test.stopTest();
        
       Map<String, Object> jsonResponse = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.responseBody.toString());
       System.assertEquals(true, jsonResponse.get('success'), 'Upload should be successful');
    }
   
    @isTest
    public static void testUploadFile() {
        // Initialize test data
        String base64 = 'JVBERi0xLjQKJcOkw7zDtsOfCjIgMCBvYmoKPDwvTGVuZ3RoIDMgMCBSPj==';
        String fileName = 'testFile.pdf';
        Case ca = new Case(Description = 'Test', Status = 'New');
        insert ca;
        
        String cdlId = FileUploadController.uploadFile(base64, fileName, ca.Id);

        System.assertNotEquals(null, cdlId, 'ContentDocumentLink Id is null');
        
        // Query the ContentDocumentLink to verify the file was uploaded
        ContentDocumentLink cdl = [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE Id = :cdlId LIMIT 1];
        System.assertNotEquals(null, cdl, 'ContentDocumentLink record not found');
        
        // Query the ContentVersion to verify the file content
        ContentVersion cv = [SELECT Id, VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId = :cdl.ContentDocumentId LIMIT 1];
        System.assertEquals(base64, EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cv.VersionData), 'File content does not match');
    }
    
    @isTest
    public static void testUploadFileRequest() {
        FileUploadController.uploadFile(null);
    }
    
    @isTest
    public static void testUploadFileCl() {
        Case ca = new Case(Description = 'Test', Status = 'New');
        insert ca;
        
        ContentVersion testContentInsert =new ContentVersion(); 
        testContentInsert.ContentURL='<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com/\'" rel="nofollow">http://www.google.com/\'</a>'; 
        testContentInsert.Title ='Google.com';
        insert testContentInsert;
        
        FileUploadCOntroller.createContentLink(testContentInsert.Id,ca.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, please share what is the error you are getting while running the test class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I increase my code coverage, or why can't I cover these lines?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines)