# How to call 'saveFile' method from an apex test class as it is non static.Please find the below code

Tags: community

```
public class ESMX_uploadDoc_Controller 
{
    public String sobjIds{get;set;}
    public List<id> ipidList {get;set;}

    //initialize the controller and picking up the ids
    public ESMX_uploadDoc_Controller()
    {
         sobjIds=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        System.debug(sobjIds);
         ipidList = sobjIds.split(',');
         //System.debug(ipidList);
        /*for(String id:ipidList)
        {
            System.debug(id);
        }*/

    }

    //Adding the attachments to the ids
    //body
    public  transient String base64;

     public String getBase64()
    {
        return base64;
    }
    public void setbase64(String base64)
    {
        this.base64 = base64;
    }

    //Name
    public String fileName {get; set;}
    //Content
    public String content{get; set;}
    //Installed Product
    public SVMXC__Installed_Product__c ipupd {get;set;}//Added



    public void saveFile()
    {
     try{
        String urlDecoded = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(base64, 'UTF-8');
        Blob hexDecode = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(urlDecoded);
        Attachment a ;
        List<Attachment> attachList = new List<Attachment>(); 
        List<SVMXC__Installed_Product__c> ipUpdList = new List<SVMXC__Installed_Product__c>();//Added
        /*a = new Attachment(parentId ='a046F00001eoknq', Body = hexDecode, name = fileName,contenttype=content);
        insert a;*/
        for(String id:ipidList)
        {
            //System.debug('ok');
            //id i = Id.valueOf(id);

             a = new Attachment(parentId =id, Body = hexDecode, name = fileName,contenttype=content);
             attachList.add(a);

            ipupd = new SVMXC__Installed_Product__c(id =id,ESMX_Document_Uploaded__c = true);
            ipUpdList.add(ipupd);

             a=null;
            //insert a;
        }
          //a=null;

          /*
           if(ipUpdList.size() > 0)
            {
                Database.Update(ipUpdList); 
            }
        */

        if(attachList.size() > 0){
            insert attachList;
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'Files uploaded successfully'));
          }

          if(ipUpdList.size() > 0)
            {
                Database.Update(ipUpdList); 
            }
          }
          catch(Exception e){
              ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'Error while uploading file!!!'));

          }


    }





}
```

Comment: Apex tests are not limited to static methods. You'd have to create an instance of the class. Is there more to this issue?

Comment: This would be a great starting point, to learn about static and instance method
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-methods-vs-instance-methods-java/

Comment: Could anyone give any example or provide any sample code

Comment: We don't really know what you're looking for, @user63399. Why is it a problem that this method is not static? What are you specifically struggling with?

Comment: First time I am  writing an apex test class.I don't know how to call an non static method from apex test class.If anyone have any code snippet please share.It will really help me .
@David Reed I am sorry if I cause any inconvenience posting this question

Comment: If you're just getting used to Apex syntax, I would encourage you to get started at Trailhead ([Getting Started with Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_intro)), the link Pranay shared, or our [unit testing resources](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test). What you're asking is part of the core syntax of the language, and it won't help you learn if we write the code for you.