# Test Class approach Help on Custom Object (Query and Update)

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I have an Apex class on  Custom Object Called QueueDistroHelper__c

What I am basically doing is getting the Queue Id from a custom field(Related_Queue_Id__c) on the Custom object

Querying all the users in that queue

And updating another custom field(Queue_Members__c )  with all the users in that Queue

My apex class is working fine

Here is the apex class  -

```
    global class lookUpAccountAnnotation {
public class inputValues{
        @InvocableVariable(label='Queue ID' )
        public string QueueId;
        @InvocableVariable(label='Record Id' )
        public Id recordid;
        public string temp;
    }
   @InvocableMethod
    public static void deletePackageLicense(List<inputValues> inputs){

      for (inputValues i : inputs)
   {
     List<QueueDistroHelper__c> getcurrentobject =  [SELECT Queue_Members__c ,  Next_Queue_Reassignment_User__c  FROM QueueDistroHelper__c WHERE Id=:i.recordid ];

      List<User> users =  [SELECT
                    name
                FROM
                    user
                WHERE
                    id IN ( SELECT userOrGroupId FROM groupmember WHERE groupId =:i.QueueID)
                    AND
                    isActive = true

                ];
      for ( User test : users){
      if(getCurrentObject != null && !getCurrentObject .isEmpty()) {
if(getCurrentObject[0].Queue_Members__c == null)
   getCurrentObject[0].Queue_Members__c = '';
getCurrentObject[0].Queue_Members__c = getCurrentObject[0].Queue_Members__c + ' ' + test.name;
}

getCurrentObject[0].Next_Queue_Reassignment_User__c =+ users.get(1).name;
getCurrentObject[0].Last_Queue_Reassignment_User__c =+ users.get(0).name;


update getcurrentobject[0];


}   
      }
   }
}
```

I am trying to make a test class for the  same , Here are the steps I am doing for testing

1. Creating 4 test users
2. Adding those users in a test queue
3. Updating my fields on my  Custom object with User name and Queue ID

Not sure if its the right approach

Here is my test Class -

```
@isTest
private class lookUpAccountAnnotation_Test{
   @TestSetup
     static void setup() {    
    // Setup 4 Test Users
 Group grpObj = new Group(Type='Queue', Name='Test Queue1');
insert grpObj;
QueueSObject qObj = new QueueSObject(SobjectType='Lead', QueueId=grpObj.Id);
insert qObj;
    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User']; 
    List<User> users = new List<User>();

    while (users.size() < 5) {
      Blob b = Crypto.GenerateAESKey(128);
      String h = EncodingUtil.ConvertTohex(b);
      String uid = h.SubString(0,8);
      //insert 4 test users
      User u = new User(Alias = uid, Email= uid + '@myorg.com', 
          EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
          LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
          TimeZoneSidKey='America/New_York', UserName= uid + '@myorg.com');      
         ID gr = [SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE Name = 'Test Queue1'].Id;
         ID us = [SELECT Id , Name FROM User WHERE LastName='Testing'].Id;
         //Add one user in a test queuecreated above
        GroupMember gm = new GroupMember(GroupId = gr, UserOrGroupId = us);
           insert gm;
    }
System.Test.startTest();

QueueDistroHelper__c q = new QueueDistroHelper__c();
insert q;
//insert user name and Queue ID  in custom Object  
q.Related_Queue_Id__c = grpObj.Id;
q.Queue_Members__c = users.get(1).Name;
lookUpAccountAnnotation l = new lookUpAccountAnnotation();
//queryHelper q = new QueueDistroHelper__c(Name='TestQuery' , Queue_Members__c=users.name);    

System.Test.stopTest();

}
}
```

Comment: What's your question exactly? Is something not working?

Comment: So its my test class which is not working

Comment: Please be more specific than "not working" or it will be nearly impossible to help you. Please add any clarifications via **[edit]**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works.. Its not bulkified, and would fail in bulk tests. Also, there are no asserts in your code so I would call test class as useless as you are not testing behavior but just doing pseudocode coverage. Let's tackle one problem as of now. Bulkification of the main class.

1. **You are doing DML and SOQL in for-loops.** A big No and red flag.
   SF has limits, of 100SOQL and 150DML in 1 transaction. So if lookUpAccountAnnotation.inputValues is called with more than 100 records it will break.

   Use bulk pattern and gather data first and then do a single SOQL using IN Clause

   You can read more about bulkification [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/12/platform-events-eventbus-a-new-chapter-in-the-never-ending-saga-of-bulkification.html).

   ```
   Set<String> emailAddresses = new Set<String>();

   for (Invoice__c invoice: listOfInvoices){

     if (invoice.Status__c == 'Overdue'){

       emailAddresses.add(invoice.Email__c); 

     } 
   }

   // here we invoke a query. this also has a governor limit.
   // up to 100 of these in a transaction before it throws an exception

   List<Contact> contactsOverdue = [SELECT Id, Name 
                                    FROM Contact 
                                    WHERE Email in: emailAddresses];
   ```

   2. **Test class:** You are not actually calling the `deletePackageLicense` method in your code. Thus your actuall method would never be called and you are writing test for nothing. You have to write test class in bulkified manner, and then test the Behavior. The test method should cover positive , negative and bulk scenarios to ensure your code won't break.  This is a great starting point to learn about [Apex Test](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test/244789#244789)s.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats a good catch . I will update that

Comment: Sorry, Just a small doubt . What would be the best way to call my method in the code. I tried to call the method. but test still says '0 methods called '

Comment: @richie I cant see you calling `lookUpAccountAnnotation.deletePackageLicense(values);`