# Tests passing with zero code coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

It seems like literally every test I write is passing with zero code coverage org wide. I've spent the past 2 days on and off reading forums, doing trails and debugging.

Below is an example of one of my classes and its test.

```
global with sharing class AccountingPeriodCreationService  {

    public static List <AcctSeed__Accounting_Period__c> accountingPeriod;
    public static Date currentDate;
    public static Date firstDayOfCurrentMonth;
    public static Date lastDayOfCurrentMonth;

    public static void createdAPLogic(){

        Set<String> firstDaysOfMonths = new Set<String>();
        accountingPeriod = new List <AcctSeed__Accounting_Period__c>(); // New list for accountingPeriod Object

    // Create a list of dates for the next 10 years

        for (Integer i = 0; i < 120; i++){
            currentDate = Date.today().toStartofMonth();
            firstDayOfCurrentMonth = currentDate.addMonths(i).toStartofMonth();
            String currentDateString = String.valueOf(firstDayOfCurrentMonth).removeEnd(' 00:00:00');
            firstDayOfCurrentMonth = Date.valueOf(currentDateString);
            firstDaysOfMonths.add(currentDateString);
        }

         // Check what exists already in the database

        List<AcctSeed__Accounting_Period__c> checkAccountingPeriodAlreadyExist = [SELECT Id, TEMP__c, AcctSeed__Start_Date__c, AcctSeed__End_Date__c FROM AcctSeed__Accounting_Period__c where TEMP__C IN :firstDaysOfMonths];


       // For the ones that do exist, remove them from the list
        for (AcctSeed__Accounting_Period__c ap : checkAccountingPeriodAlreadyExist) {
            firstDaysOfMonths.remove(ap.TEMP__c);
        }


       // For the ones left, insert into the list
        for (String dt : firstDaysOfMonths){
            string currName = dt.replaceAll('.{3}$','');
            Date currStart = Date.valueOf(dt);
            Date currEnd = Date.valueOf(dt).addMonths(1).toStartofMonth().addDays(-1);
            accountingPeriod.add(
                new AcctSeed__Accounting_Period__c(
                Name = currName,
                AcctSeed__Status__c = 'Status',
                AcctSeed__Start_Date__c = currStart,
                AcctSeed__End_Date__c = currEnd
                )
            );
        }

      // Insert into the database
        System.debug( 'accountingPeriod: ' + accountingPeriod.size());
        List<Database.SaveResult> accountingPeriod = Database.insert(accountingPeriod, false);


    } 
}
```

Now the Test Class and one method. This is mega basic, literally to insert two items into the list, query the DB and see if there are 2 entries. (Which passes)

```
private class AccountingPeriodCreationServiceTest {

     static testmethod void checkIfAlreadyExistsTest() {
         AccountingPeriodCreationService CAP = new AccountingPeriodCreationService();
        /* Pre requisites, insert Accounting Period */
        List <AcctSeed__Accounting_Period__c> accountingPeriod;
        Date currentDate;
        Date firstDayOfCurrentMonth;
        Date lastDayOfCurrentMonth;
         Test.startTest();

         accountingPeriod = new List <AcctSeed__Accounting_Period__c>(); // New list for accountingPeriod Object
         Set<String> firstDaysOfMonths = new Set<String>();
         for (Integer i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            currentDate = Date.today().toStartofMonth();
            firstDayOfCurrentMonth = currentDate.addMonths(i).toStartofMonth();
            String currentDateString = String.valueOf(firstDayOfCurrentMonth).removeEnd(' 00:00:00');
            firstDayOfCurrentMonth = Date.valueOf(currentDateString);
            firstDaysOfMonths.add(currentDateString);
         }

         for (String dt : firstDaysOfMonths){
            //System.debug(firstDaysOfMonths);
            //System.debug(dt);
            //System.debug(Date.valueOf(dt));
            //System.debug(Date.valueOf(dt).addMonths(1).toStartofMonth().addDays(-1));
            //System.debug(dt.replaceAll('.{3}$',''));
            string currName = dt.replaceAll('.{3}$','');
            Date currStart = Date.valueOf(dt);
            Date currEnd = Date.valueOf(dt).addMonths(1).toStartofMonth().addDays(-1);
            accountingPeriod.add(
                new AcctSeed__Accounting_Period__c(
                Name = currName,
                AcctSeed__Status__c = 'Status',
                AcctSeed__Start_Date__c = currStart,
                AcctSeed__End_Date__c = currEnd
                )
            );
        }
        Database.insert(accountingPeriod, false);
        Test.stopTest();
        List<AcctSeed__Accounting_Period__c> InsertResult = [SELECT Id, TEMP__c, AcctSeed__Start_Date__c, AcctSeed__End_Date__c FROM AcctSeed__Accounting_Period__c where TEMP__C IN :firstDaysOfMonths];

        System.assertEquals(2, InsertResult.size());



     }
}
```

I purposely included a carbon copy of the code for this instance, but zero coverage still. How can I cover this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be closed as a duplicate (we have questions under the [canonical-qa](/questions/tagged/canonical-qa) tag to handle questions like these), but...

The big thing you're missing here is that *you only gain coverage for code that is executed as part of a test method* (and the things that can be covered/need coverage is generally things inside of class methods).

Your test here is calling the default constructor for `AccountingPeriodCreationService`, but nothing else (at least not directly).

The code you have is in the static `createdAPLogic()` method.

Your test isn't calling `createdAPLogic()`, therefore you gain no coverage for this method.

[How do I write an Apex unit test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test) would be a good place to get some more specific (but still general) information (like you should be making assertions against the *output* of the code that you're testing...which could involve accessing class variables, checking return values, or querying for records inserted/updated).