# Testing In Salesforce

Tags: trigger

Please Let me know.How to write TEST class for the following code?

```
trigger TriggerForACC on Account (before insert) {
    List<Contact> conUpdatedList=new List<Contact>();

    List<Contact> ExistingList=[Select Id,Name FROM Contact];
    for(Account acc: Trigger.New){
        acc.Name='MyAccount';
        acc.BillingCity='Bangalore';
        acc.BillingCountry='India';
    }
    for(Contact cont:ExistingList){
        cont.FirstName='Kavya';
        conUpdatedList.add(cont);
    }
    update conUpdatedList;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write an Apex unit test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test) . In your test class you have insert Account.

Comment: @cloudZigZag While using after triggers for working on other objects in a trigger is certainly recommended, your assertion is wrong. it is not required to use an after trigger here. Your tone here is also very brusque, and not suitable for new members.