# How to write trigger handler class and test class?

Tags: apex, trigger

I wrote trigger which i want it to implement via handler class (As per best practice). Please help.

```
trigger PreventTaskDelete on Task (before delete) {
    Id profileid = Userinfo.getProfileId();
    profile profilename = [select Name from Profile where id=:profileid];
    for(Task T1:Trigger.old){
        if(profilename.Name != 'System Administrator'){
            T1.adderror('Task Cannot be deleted');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write an Apex unit test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test)

Comment: My main question is how do I implement this trigger thru Handler class. But thanks for link regarding unit test. I'm completely new in Salesforce and have no formal background in IT (Coding/Programming) so pardon me if I did not formulate my question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger should be simple and just pass the necessary context variables to methods in your trigger handler based on the context. This should be built in such a way that it an accommodate for other trigger contexts in the future:

**Trigger**

```
trigger PreventTaskDelete on Task (before delete) {
    PreventTaskDeleteHandler handler = new PreventTaskDeleteHandler(Trigger.old); //an instance of your handler class which accepts whichever trigger contexts variables are needed (could be Trigger.old, Trigger.oldMap or Trigger.new for beforeUpdate etc.)
    if(Trigger.isBefore){ // More necessary if your trigger is called in different contexts (ie: before delete, after delete)
        if(Trigger.isDelete){
            handler.beforeDelete(); //calls the method called beforeDelete in your handler class
        } else if(/*some other trigger context, if necessary*/){
            handler.beforeUpdate(); //example - (not necessary for your trigger)
        }
    }
}
```

**Trigger Handler**

```
public with sharing class PreventTaskDeleteHandler {
    private List<Task> tasks;
    public PreventTaskDeleteHandler(List<Task> tasks) { 
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }

    public void beforeDelete() {    //method that gets called in Trigger that does the work
        Id profileid = Userinfo.getProfileId();
        profile profilename = [select Name from Profile where id=:profileid];
        for(Task t1 : tasks){
            if(profilename.Name != 'System Administrator'){
                t1.adderror('Task Cannot be deleted');
            }
        }
    }

    public void anotherRandomMethod(String randomVariable) { //method to do more work when necessary
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please help me with Test class as well?