# how to make a test so that the lead owner is the same as the contact owner

Tags: trigger, unit-test, failing-tests

I'm starting to learn apex and I need to write a test for a simple trigger so I can have 100% code coverage.
Here's my trigger:

```
trigger UpdatePropietario on Lead (after update) {
    Id pId;

    for(Lead att: Trigger.new){  
        pId=att.Id;
    }

    List<Contact> listContact = new List<Contact>();
    for (Contact c : [select Contact.Id , OwnerId, RecordTypeId from Contact where Contact.Prospecto__c =:Trigger.new[0].Id]){

        Id RecordTypeId;  
        RecordTypeId= c.RecordTypeId;   

        if (RecordTypeId != '0126A0000009jPPQAY') {   
            Contact updatedContact = new Contact();
            updatedContact.Id = c.Id;
            updatedContact.OwnerId = Trigger.new[0].OwnerId;
            listContact.add(updatedContact);
        }

        if(listContact.size() > 0){
            update listContact;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the test, but it does not pass the test

```
@isTest
public class TestUpdatePropietario {
    @isTest static void TestUpdatePropietario() {

         Lead l = new Lead();
       l.Id ='00Q3C000002EUjn';
   l.OwnerId ='0056A000000skpzQAA';
        l.FirstName='Test';
    insert l;

        Contact cont = new Contact();

        cont.OwnerId='0056A000000skpzQAA';
        cont.Prospecto__c='0056A000000skpzQAA'; 
        cont.id= l.id;
      insert cont;


         Lead accountToUpdate = new Lead();
    accountToUpdate = [SELECT OwnerId FROM Lead WHERE FirstName='Test' LIMIT 1];
    accountToUpdate.OwnerId = '0056A000000skpzQAA';

    update accountToUpdate;


    List<Contact> lstContact = [select OwnerId from Contact where id=:cont.id];

      System.assertEquals('0056A000000skpzQAA', lstContact[0].OwnerId);  
    }   
}
```

Comment: Never use hard coded Ids. Create your test data.

Answer (score 2):

```
l.Id ='00Q3C000002EUjn';
```

Your unit test can't see existing data in your org due to [test data isolation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm#!). If that is an extant Lead Id, your code can't see it. You should generate all data required for your test inside your test.

```
l.OwnerId ='0056A000000skpzQAA';
```

You should not hard code any Ids, including Users, but you also don't need to here if you make some structural changes I will recommend below.

```
  cont.id= l.id;
  insert cont;
```

You cannot assign the Id of one type of sObject to the Id field of another. A Contact Id field can never contain the Id of a Lead.

```
     Lead accountToUpdate = new Lead();
accountToUpdate = [SELECT OwnerId FROM Lead WHERE FirstName='Test' LIMIT 1];
```

You do not need to create a new object instance in a variable to which you intend to assign a SOQL query. Because of the aforementioned test data isolation, this code cannot see any Lead with that FirstName - your test must create it.

Because it manipulates ownership, this test is somewhat more complex than some first-try Apex tests. Here is an outline of how I would test this code, for a single-record case only. Your unit tests should always cover bulk cases as well, but currently, your trigger is non-functional for bulk cases.

1. Create a User, `u`. Use a [`System.runAs()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm) construct to enter this user context.
2. Create a Lead. Do not specify the OwnerId - it will automatically be assign to the running user.
3. Close the `System.runAs()`.
4. Create a second user, `v`. Enter its context with `System.runAs()`.
5. Create an insert a Contact. Do not specify the OwnerId - it will automatically be assign to the running user. Set its `Prospecto__c` field to the Id of the Lead.
6. Update the original Lead.
7. Query the Contact and validate that its `OwnerId` field was set to the same value as the `Lead`'s - that is, `u.Id`.

You will encounter problems if your Organization-Wide Defaults for Lead and Contact aren't Public Read/Write.

I'd also strongly recommend taking some time to complete the [Bulk Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk) Trailhead module. Your trigger currently will fail to perform correctly when more than one record is updated in an operation. You'll also, I hope, find some value in the resources linked from [How do I write an Apex unit test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test).