# Trigger Code Coverage with if condition

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, code-coverage

I am creating a test class for the giving trigger but because of the if conditions I am not getting code coverage above 50%. Please help me out for the same. 
This is a trigger class :

```
trigger Correction_Counter on Case (before update) {
    Case cs = Trigger.New[0];
    if(cs.Status == 'Correction Requested')
    {    
        if( Trigger.oldMap.get( cs.Id ).Status != Trigger.newMap.get( cs.Id ).Status )
        {
            if(cs.Correction_Counters__c == 0) 
            {
                cs.Correction_Counters__c = 0.1; 
            }
            else 
            {
                cs.Correction_Counters__c +=   0.5;
            }
        }   
    }       
}
```

This is my test class

```
public class Correction_CounterTestClass {
    public static void test(){
        Case obj = new Case(); 
        obj.Status = 'Correction Requested';
        obj.Id = '5000x00000B8rliAAB';
        obj.Correction_Counters__c = 0;
        insert obj;
        update obj;
        System.assertEquals(0, obj.Correction_Counters__c);
}
```

Please help me to get code coverage above 75%.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the code which you mentioned as `test class` is not really a test class. The syntax for test class is something like below i.e. it should have an annotation `@isTest` which says that, this particular code is only testing the functionality and not really changing anything in the database. You can go through salesforce trailhead moudle [Apex Testing](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro) to learn how to write test classes.

```
@isTest
private class MyTestClass {
    @isTest static void myTest() {
        // code_block
    }
}
```

Now coming to your test class which actually is not, there are few things you need to correct

- You have some syntactical errors in your code which is the reason the code is not getting compiled i.e. you are missing a closing brace (I hope it is just a typo).
- I am not sure how your code executed successfully as it should have given you error `cannot specify Id in an insert call` at `insert obj;` line as you cannot and should not specify the `Id` in a insert call.
- You should not use hard-coded `Id` values as data won't be accessible to the code in test class as on Salesforce, all unit tests are executed in an isolated context. So your code in test class cannot see data in your organization. Although there is an annotation called `seeAllData=true` which allows tests to see all data in the Salesforce but this is strictly not recommended.

You can go though this canonical question developed by SFSE community [How do I write an Apex unit test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test) which will help you understand and learn these concepts.

As far as your test class is concerned, you should make sure that you create the test data as input for your code, which ensures that all the logical paths are executed.

So your code for test class should be

```
@isTest
private class Correction_CounterTestClass {
    @isTest static void myTest_CounterZero(){
        Case obj = new Case(); 
        obj.Status = 'Open'; //Set this to any other valid status other than 'Correction Requested' as you are checking for status change in your trigger
        obj.Correction_Counters__c = 0;
        insert obj;
        Test.startTest();
        obj.Status = 'Correction Requested';
        update obj;
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assertEquals(0.1, obj.Correction_Counters__c);
    }

    @isTest static void myTest_CounterNonZero(){
        Case obj = new Case(); 
        obj.Status = 'Open'; //Set this to any other valid status other than 'Correction Requested' as you are checking for status change in your trigger
        obj.Correction_Counters__c = 2;
        insert obj;
        Test.startTest();
        obj.Status = 'Correction Requested';
        update obj;
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assertEquals(2.5, obj.Correction_Counters__c);
    }
}
```

**Note :** Your trigger is not bulkified and hence it will work only for single record. As a best practice, it is always recommended to bulkify your code. You can refer [Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk) trailhead module to learn on this topic.

Comment: Thanks aton :) It's solved my huge big problem.

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 2):

To increase coverage you simply need to ensure that each condition (either positive like an "if", or negative like an "else") in the code has a test that has data meeting the required condition.

In this example you notionally need 6 tests since you have 3 different "if" statements (one for the positive, one for the negative). However, some of these variants are not relevant because certain data combinations work the same due to a prior condition failing. So you need 4 tests where the data is:

- the Status is "Correction Requested" and the Status has changed and the counter is 0
- the Status is "Correction Requested" and the Status has changed and the counter is NOT 0
- the Status is "Correction Requested" and the Status has NOT changed (counter value irrelevant)
- the Status is NOT "Correction Requested" (whether the Status changed is irrelevant, as is the counter)

Note that a trigger can be called with up to 200 instances and your code needs to be updated to handle the appropriate iteration of all these instances (not to just process the 0th entry).