# Test class for Visualforce page with clone funcationality

Tags: visualforce, standardcontroller

I just a small help in understanding how to write a Test class for an std controller which performs a custom clone Functionality.

I have 2 questions
1. Is it necessary to write the Test class for the Lead std controller as I used it?
2. If that is the case to write case how can we write a Test class for Clone Functionality

Note: Why I'm using vf page rather than javascript URL hack the fields which we are trying to clone are Read-only for some profiles. In order to overcome, I have gone through page

Thanks prior for sharing your Knowledge

This is my Class:

```
public class customcloneLead{
private lead l;
public customcloneLead(apexpages.standardcontroller std){
}
public void clonelead(){
lead l1 = new lead();
l1 =l.clone();
insert l1;
}
}
```

This is my Test class can anyone help?

```
@isTest 
public class customcloneLead
{
 static testMethod void clonelead() 
 {
 Lead testLead = new Lead();
 testLead.LastName='Test lead';
 insert testLead;

 Test.StartTest(); 

  PageReference pageRef = Page.Customclone;
  pageRef.getParameters().put('id',String.valueOf(testLead.Id));
  Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);


  myController customclone = new customclone(new Apexpages.StandardController(SC));
  Customclone.save();
  //testAccPlan.save(); call all your function here
 Test.StopTest();
 }
}
```

> Invalid type: myController at line 16 column 3:

This is the error i'm facing

Comment: Did you write any Apex code for your controller? It is unclear from your question. If you wrote any Apex code, you must write a test class.

Comment: public class customcloneLead{
private lead l;
public customcloneLead(apexpages.standardcontroller std){
}
public void clonelead(){
lead l1 = new lead();
l1 =l.clone();
insert l1;
}
}      This is the Apex class i wrote but my question is how to check Test class for this as my requirement is to clone?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add this information and include any attempt you have made to write a test class. If you do not know how to write a test class, I suggest reading [How do I write an Apex test class?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is quite clear about the problem. You are referring to the class under test by an incorrect name.

```
myController customclone = new customclone(new Apexpages.StandardController(SC));
Customclone.save();
```

The class you are testing is not called `myController` or `customclone`; it is called `customcloneLead`. Further, the method you are attempting to test is called `clonelead()`, not `save()`. Because test classes are very specific to the code being testing, note that copying test code from elsewhere *generally will not help*: at most you'll get a rough skeleton that you'll need to tailor to your exact situation.

You'll need to name your test class something other than `customCloneLead`, since that name is taken. `customcloneLead_TEST` is a common pattern used in many orgs.

You have the beginning of a viable test class here, but you need to also write *assertions* to validate that your class does what it is expected to do. Here, you might write a query on the `Lead` object and use an assertion to verify that a second Lead was successfully inserted. See [How do I write an Apex unit test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test) for more resources on the basics of Apex testing.