# Code Coverage Failure trigger deploy on production

Tags: apex, trigger, deployment, code

i have a code for trigger:

```
trigger SendDisbursement on Opportunity (after update) {
if (!System.isFuture()){
    for (Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.new.size(); i++) {
        if (Trigger.old[i].StageName != Trigger.new[i].StageName && Trigger.new[i].StageName == 'Disbursement' && Trigger.new[i].RecordTypeId == '12903903930390') {
            Organization org = [SELECT IsSandbox FROM Organization];
            String orgStr = (org.IsSandbox == true) ? 'sale' : 'credit';
            EmailUtil.mailSender(Trigger.new[i], orgStr);
        }
    }
}
}
```

when i try deploy on production i get the message:

Your code coverage is 0%. You need at least 75% coverage to complete this deployment.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write an Apex unit test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test)

Comment: Did you deploy your test class as well in the change set?  It says only deploying 1 component.  If you're deploying this for the first time to production, you'll need to include the trigger and the unit test class

Answer (score 4):

To deploy a trigger to production , you will need to ensure your trigger has a test class and the class needs to cover at least 75% of the lines of code .

Looks like you are writing the trigger for first time .

I suggest you go through Salesforce trailhead content and learn some of the best practices such as below

1. [bulkify your trigger](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_bestpract.htm)
2. do not write soql or dml inside loop
3. [Have a trigger framework for the project](https://github.com/kevinohara80/sfdc-trigger-framework) to manage complexity and help easy debugging
4. Ensure proper test code coverage with system asserts

Check the below link on how to write test case for a trigger

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_triggers

Comment: Hello, when i upload without check "isActive" work fine deployment, but when i check the "isActive" get a error on deploy, is for any reason?

Comment: Have you written the test class ? You will need a test class as well to deploy with the trigger

Comment: i update the question with the apex class code when i try run the code i get a: "Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts"

Comment: Looks like you have a third party web service callout using http class.I suggest look into Salesforce mocks for same .

Answer (score 0):

From your last updated comment it seems that you have run the test method but your hackClipDisburse() which is called is not having isTest qualifier I only see one on class.