# Assistance with Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, class

I could get a sample class to automatically deactivate inactive users in Salesforce and did some changes to it:

```
    public class DeactivateInactiveUsers implements Schedulable {
    public void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
        User[] selectedUsers = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE IsActive = TRUE AND Id NOT IN (SELECT UserId FROM LoginHistory WHERE LoginTime = LAST_N_DAYS:365) AND Z_Profile_Text__c = 'BR Marketing' AND Z_Profile_Text__c <> 'System Administrator' AND Z_Profile_Text__c <> 'API-Only'];
        for(User record: selectedUsers) {
            record.IsActive = false;
        }
        Database.update(selectedUsers, false);
    }
}
```

Now I have the "big"challenge to create a test class to deploy this class to production.
Could anyone give some assistance on this?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Unit testing is a pretty common question, and the general "how do I write a test" questions are too broad to be a good fit for the Q&A format here. [How do I write an Apex Unit Test](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test) has some good information, as do the rest of the questions under the [tag:canonical-qa] tag. In general, if you're new to Salesforce (or a specific feature/concept), https://trailhead.salesforce.com is going to be a better resource than this site will be.

Comment: A broad answer for a broad question :-) fair enough.

Comment: I will say, though, that in addition to the Apex Testing module on Trailhead, you'll probably want to create a test user (creating the data you'll need for the test, inside of the test class is one of the more important points of unit testing). To do that, you'll likely need to use `System.runAs(){ /*code to insert user here */}` to avoid a `MIXED_DML_OPERATION` error.

Comment: Answering my question:

@isTest
public class DeactivateInactiveUsersTest
{
  static testMethod void testDeactivateInactiveUsers()
  {
  DeactivateInactiveUsers du = new DeactivateInactiveUsers();
  du.execute(null);
  }
}