# Apex Test Class for SOQL

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I'm having trouble providing code coverage for my Apex Class.

Apex Class

```
public class CSMetricsDashboardController {
    public CS_Metrics_Dashboard__c dashboard {get;set;}

    public CSMetricsDashboardController() {
        List<CS_Metrics_Dashboard__c> results = [
            SELECT
                Antic_Needs_Avg__c,
                Antic_Needs_Target__c,
                Expenses_Color__c,
                KLAS__c,
                KLAS_Target__c,
                Investment_Projects_Led__c,
                Investment_Projects_Supported__c,
                Product_Release_Training_Color__c,
                Project_NPS_Avg__c,
                Project_NPS_Target__c,
                Project_On_Budget__c,
                Project_On_Budget_Target__c,
                Time_Entry_Color__c,
                Time_Entry_Missed__c,
                Time_Entry_Missed_Percentage__c,
                Time_Entry_Rating__c,
                Utilization_MTD_Actual__c,
                Utilization_YTD_Target__c,
                Utilization_YTD_Actual__c
            FROM CS_Metrics_Dashboard__c
            WHERE User_Name__c =: UserInfo.getUserId()
            AND Inactive__c = false
        ];
        if (results.size() > 0) {
            this.dashboard = results[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class CSMetricsDashboardContollerTest {

    public static testmethod void testRunAs(){
        // Setup test data
        // Grap Profile
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name ='Standard User'];
        // Create new user
        User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', 
                          Email = 'standarduser@stratadecision.com',
                          EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8', 
                          LastName = 'Tester', 
                          LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                          ProfileId = p.Id,
                          TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Chicago',
                          UserName = 'standarduser@stratadecision.com');
        insert u;
        // Create new account 
        Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test Account',
                                DBA_Name__c = 'Test Account', // Legal Entity Name
                                Type = 'Prospect'); 
        insert a;
        // Create new contact, master to CS Metrics Dashboard
        Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'Tester',
                                AccountId = a.Id,
                                Status__c = 'Active');
        insert c;
        // Create new CS Metrics Dashboard record related to new contact
        CS_Metrics_Dashboard__c cs = new CS_Metrics_Dashboard__c(Contact__c = c.Id,
                                                                 User_Name__c = u.Id,
                                                                 Project_NPS_Avg__c = 90,
                                                                 Inactive__c = false);
        insert cs;

        // start test
        test.startTest();

            System.runAs(u){
                // The following code runs as user 'u'
            List<CS_Metrics_Dashboard__c> results = [SELECT Id,
                                                            Inactive__c,
                                                            Project_NPS_Avg__c,
                                                            User_Name__c 
                                                     FROM CS_Metrics_Dashboard__c 
                                                     WHERE User_Name__c =: u.Id]; 
                System.assert(u != null);
                System.assertEquals(false, results[0].Inactive__c);
                System.assertEquals(90, results[0].Project_NPS_Avg__c);
                System.assertEquals(u.Id, results[0].User_Name__c);
         // stop test
         test.stopTest();
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SFSE. Please take a [tour] and read [ask]. It looks like you lack of very basic knowledge of how unit tests work for Apex and I suggest you to get familiar with [Apex Basics & Database](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database) and [Apex Testing](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing) trails. Also, you can have a look at [How do I write an Apex unit test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test).

Comment: I do see you're creating test data, which is good. The links Przemysław Tamoń provided are good. To give you a quick push in the right direction... the golden rule of unit testing is that _you only gain coverage for code that is executed as part of a test method_. So if you're not getting coverage, that means _that_ particular code isn't being executed. Here, you need to ensure that your `CSMetricsDashboardController` constructor is called. Also, don't neglect making assertions about the results of calling your code.