# Execute method within batch APEX not firing from test class

Tags: batch

I have written the following batch apex class and corresponding test class. Tests are successful but the execute method is never called. I have attempted to debug to try to pinpoint the problem but have had no luck.

**Batch Class**

```
global class BatchAddToCampaign implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,  Database.Stateful
{
    global final Id campaignId;
    global final Set<Id> qKeys;

    global BatchAddToCampaign(Id campaignId, Set<Id> qKeys){
        this.campaignId = campaignId;
        this.qKeys = qKeys;
    System.Debug('this.campaignId is ' + campaignId);         
    System.Debug('this.qkeys is ' + qKeys);                 

    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator('Select Id From Lead Where Id In :qKeys');
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Lead> scope) {
        System.Debug('Starting Execute Method!');         
        Integer collsize; 
        List<CampaignMember> cm = new List<CampaignMember>();   
        Map<Id, Campaign> cmMap = new Map<Id, Campaign>([Select (Select LeadId From CampaignMembers) From Campaign c Where Id = :campaignId]);
         for(Lead myLeads : scope) {
             CampaignMember newCM = new CampaignMember(
             CampaignId = campaignId,
             LeadId = myLeads.Id,
             status = 'Added' );

                 if (!cmMap.containsKey(myLeads.Id)) {
                     cm.add(newCM); 
                     collsize = cm.size();
                 }
         }

         try {
             Database.insert(cm); 
         } catch (DmlException ex) {
            System.Debug('Insert failed ' + ex);
         }        
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        AsyncApexJob a = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed,  TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email From AsyncApexJob Where Id = :BC.getJobId()];
        // Send an email to the Apex job's submitter notifying of job completion.
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {a.CreatedBy.Email};
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setSubject('Add to Campaign ' + a.Status);
        String campaignURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/' + campaignId;
        mail.setPlainTextBody('The batch Apex job processed ' + a.TotalJobItems + ' batches with '+ a.NumberOfErrors + ' failures. ' + 'Link to Campaign: ' + campaignURL);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
public class BatchAddToCampaignTest
{
    static testMethod void testMethod1()
    {
        List<Lead> lstCM= new List<Lead>();
        for(Integer i=0 ;i <1;i++){
            Lead myLead = new Lead();
            myLead.Id = '00Q1U00000KqFcDUAV';
            lstCM.add(myLead);
            Integer collSize = lstCM.size(); 
            System.debug('List Collection Size is ' + collSize);
                {

                System.debug('Start Set');
                Set<Id> leadIds = (new Map<Id,SObject>(lstCM)).keySet();
                System.debug('End Set');
                Integer collSizeSet = leadIds.size(); 
                System.debug('Set Collection Size is ' + collSizeSet);
                Id workingCampaignId = '7011U000000RWRAQA4';

                Test.startTest();

                //BatchAddToCampaign ba = new BatchAddToCampaign(workingCampaignId, leadIds);
                DataBase.executeBatch(new BatchAddToCampaign(workingCampaignId, leadIds));

                Test.stopTest();  
                }
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: It won't execute because you don't have any data. You need to update the test to insert some data before you run the batch.

Comment: You also have a for loop running the `Test.startTest()` and `stopTest()`. I know it's a for loop that only runs one time, the `Test` start and stop, as well as the `executeBatch` should definitely not be running in a loop block context

Answer (score 6):

Your unit tests execute in an [isolated data environment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm#!) and cannot see the records with the hard-coded Salesforce Ids you've included. Hence, your query returns no records.

Your unit tests should always generate their own data within test context. See [How do I write an Apex unit test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test) for links to great resources on how to do this well.