# Issue with Test Class unable to cover SOQL query and insert statements

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, visualforce-component

I have created a VF page that is basically a form. The issue is that my test class is unable to cover the SOQL statement inside the retrieve method. Also, it is unable to insert ptw or cle in save method.

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Please find my test class and controller. Thank you in advance for the help!

**Controller:**

```
public class i2{
public Cleaning_Activity__c cle{get;set;}
public Permit_to_Work_Number__c ptw{get;set;}
public List<Cleaning_Activity__c> clelist{get;set;}
public String paramValue{get;set;}


//constructor to create a new record
public i2(){
    cle = new Cleaning_Activity__c();
    ptw = new Permit_to_Work_Number__c();  
}



public void refresh(){
    ptw = new Permit_to_Work_Number__c(); 
}

 public void retrieve(){
   if(cle.Password__c == 'pv' || cle.Password__c == 'sunsure')
        {
           clelist = [SELECT Name, Password__c, Number_of_Workers__c FROM Cleaning_Activity__c where Password__c =: cle.Password__c];
            system.debug(clelist);   
        }
     else if(cle.Password__c == NULL)
         ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'Please key in the password to retreive the details'));
     else
          ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'Password is incorrect'));
}



public void save1(){  
    system.debug('paramValue ' + paramValue);
    if(paramValue == 'button2')
    {
        system.debug('Password is ' + cle.Password__c);
        if(cle.Password__c == 'pv' || cle.Password__c == 'sunsure') 
        {
            System.debug('I am here');
            insert ptw;
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'PTW Inserted Successfully'));
            ptw = new Permit_to_Work_Number__c();
        }
        else
        {
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'Wrong Password'));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(cle.Password__c == 'pv' || cle.Password__c == 'sunsure')
            //if(cle.Qualtiy_of_Cleaning__c != NULL & cle.Operation__c != NULL)
        {
            insert cle;
            clelist = [SELECT Name, Password__c, Number_of_Workers__c FROM Cleaning_Activity__c where Password__c =: cle.Password__c];
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'Cleaning Activity Inserted Successfully'));
            system.debug(clelist);
            cle = new Cleaning_Activity__c();
        }
            //else
            //{
             // ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'Please input the Operation Name and Quality of Cleaning'));  
           // }
        else
        {
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'Wrong Password'));
        }
    }



}

}
```

**Test Class:**

```
    @isTest()
    public class Testi2 {

  @isTest static void Test1()
    {

    PageReference pageRef = Page.MaintenanceVFPage;
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

    Cleaning_Activity__c d = new Cleaning_Activity__c(); 
    d.Operation__c = 'a0S2800000552ITEAY';
    d.Qualtiy_of_Cleaning__c = '5';
    d.Number_of_Workers__c = 6;
    d.Password__c = 'sunsure';
    insert d;
    d = [SELECT Name, Password__c, Number_of_Workers__c 
         FROM Cleaning_Activity__c WHERE Password__c =: d.Password__c];
   // List<Cleaning_Activity__c> clelist1 = [SELECT Name, Password__c, Number_of_Workers__c FROM
                                          //    Cleaning_Activity__c WHERE Password__c = d.Password__c];
    //system.assertEquals(1,clelist1.size());





    Permit_to_Work_Number__c ptw = new Permit_to_Work_Number__c();   
    system.debug(d.Password__c);
    ptw.Cleaning_Activity__c = 'a0a1m000000lPWsAAM';
    ptw.Number_of_Workers__c = 3;
    ptw.Date__c = date.today();
    ptw.PTW_Number__c = 'PTW-1001';
    insert ptw;

    Test.startTest();    
    i2 me = new i2();
    me.paramValue = 'button1';
    me.retrieve(); 
    system.debug('xxxxs' +d.Password__c);
    me.save1();
    me.refresh();

    me.paramValue = 'button2';
    me.retrieve(); 

    me.save1();
    me.refresh();           
     System.assertEquals(d.Number_of_Workers__c,6,'Error');
    Test.stopTest();

    }

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

This unit test has a number of problems that will prevent it from operating correctly and providing you with any valid information about the behavior of your code.

- You hard-code Salesforce Ids. Every unit test must create its own data - all of its own data. Your unit test code cannot see existing records in your org, so those Ids are invalid.
- Your unit test contains no assertions.
- Your unit test attempts to gain coverage by calling code that it is not testing.

The three steps every unit test must execute are

1. Create data and setup the test conditions.
2. Exercise the unique code path being tested (call the code, run the trigger, etc).
3. Validate the results by making assertions.

You should expect to write *multiple* unit tests to cover multiple units of code.

Currently, your unit test isn't hitting any of those marks. I'd really recommend you complete [Unit Testing on the Lightning Platform](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/unit-testing-on-the-lightning-platform) on Trailhead and review the other resources linked in [How do I write an Apex unit test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test) to learn how to write high quality unit tests that achieve full code coverage *as a side effect* of properly testing your code.