# Test Class for a simple Apex Class

Tags: apex, lightning, unit-test, lightning-experience, code-coverage

I am trying to write a test class for a simple Apex Class which sets the status of the Case to be Closed like below

```
public class updateCaseRecord {    
     @AuraEnabled
    public static void updateCheck(String caseId){
        List<Case> records = [select id,Status from Case WHERE Id = :caseId];
        for (Case record : records)
        {
            record.Status = 'Closed';
        }
        update records;     
    }
}
```

The test class I have written so far is like below I have created a test account,contact and a case.

```
@IsTest
public class updateCaseRecordTest {
@IsTest(SeeAllData=true) static void testIsUpdateCheck() {
    ID parentRecType = '012U0000000PqA9IAK';
    ID csRecType     = '012U0000000QGv4IAG'; 

    Account pa = new Account(Name='Test Parent Account', recordTypeId=parentRecType);
    insert pa;

    Account testAccount = new Account(Name='test', Industry='Biotech',Territory__c='EUR',BillingCity='Test',BillingCountry='Germany',ParentId=pa.id);
    insert testAccount; 

    Contact c = new Contact(LastName='Test',LeadSource='Customer Service',AccountId=testAccount.Id);
    insert c;

    Case newCase = new Case();
    newCase.Subject = 'testStatusClosed';
    newCase.Status = 'New';
    newCase.Category__c = 'Inquiry';
    newCase.Sub_Category__c = 'Other';
    newCase.AccountId = testAccount.Id;
    newCase.ContactId = c.id;
    newCase.recordTypeId=csRecType;
    insert newCase;

     ApexPages.standardController std = New ApexPages.standardController(newCase); 

updateCaseRecord uC = new updateCaseRecord();
uC.updateCheck(std);
}}
```

I get the error like `Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void updateCheck(ApexPages.StandardController) from the type updateCaseRecord`. How  can I test the apex class and can have the assertion statement. I am writing first time test scripts and I am kind of lost. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your class `updateCheck` method is static. you can't invoke static method from an instance of the class in Apex. It should be invoked from a class:

instead of

```
updateCaseRecord uC = new updateCaseRecord();
uC.updateCheck(std);
```

should be

```
updateCaseRecord.updateCheck(newCase.Id);
```

you don't need any standard controller,  as for VF controller.

---

I recommend you to read [Get Started with Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_intro) trailhead, not hardcode ids and if possible not to use `SeeAllData=true` in tests

Comment: Thank you that worked. How can I write an assertion statement here

Comment: @user81642 you will need to select this case and verify, that Status is updated with the expected value.

Comment: Please review the resources in [How do I write an Apex unit test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test) to learn about standard testing practices.