# Test class for Wrapper Class Method

Tags: apex, unit-test, wrapper-class

I have wrapper class `WrapperDemoClass`, writting test class for this `getwrapperObj` method.

in the below test class how to read the wrapper class return `list` from test class.

Getting `In valid type WrapperDemoClass.getwrapperObjwrap` Error

```
 @isTest
    public static void testgetwrapperObj(){
    WrapperDemoClass.getwrapperObjwrap =new WrapperDemoClass.getwrapperObjwrap ();
    Test.startTest();  
    WrapperDemoClass .getwrapperObj();
    Test.stopTest(); 
}
```

```
public with sharing class WrapperDemoClass {



    Public List < StudentWrapper > getwrapperObj() {
        List < student__c > accList = [Select id, name from student__c limit 5];


        List < StudentWrapper > conwrap = new List < StudentWrapper > ();
        for (Account acc: accList) {
            StudentWrapper aWraper = new StudentWrapper();
            aWraper.studentId = con.Id;
            aWraper.studentname = con.Name;
            conwrap.add(aWraper);
        }
        return conwrap;
    }

    public Class StudentWrapper {
        @AuraEnabled
        public Id studentId {
            get;
            set;
        }
        @AuraEnabled
        public string studentname {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error.

```
WrapperDemoClass.getwrapperObjwrap =new WrapperDemoClass.getwrapperObjwrap ();
```

This would create a new instance of a type called `WrapperDemoClass.getwrapperObjwrap` (that is, an inner class), which doesn't exist.

`getwrapperObjwrap()` is an instance method, which would be called as

```
new WrapperDemoClass().getwrapperObjwrap ();
```

Note the positions of the two sets of parentheses.

Comment: Hi David, I'm new to salesforce, Sorry, I'm not getting your answer. I'm calling WrapperDemoClass .getwrapperObj(); the method from test class, My question is how we can read the return list<> from the test class.

Comment: Your code does not compile. It contains a syntax error. I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Right now, the returned list is empty because you have not created any test data.

Comment: If you'd like to access some resources for getting started writing Apex unit tests, please take a look at [How do I write an Apex unit test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test).