# Your code coverage is 73%. You need at least 75% coverage to complete this deployment

Tags: code-coverage, error, code, production

Already run test but no luck.

```
public class UNILAB_NMAP {

/* wrapper class to store required properties for "lightning:map" component' */ 
public class accountLocationWrapper{
    @AuraEnabled public string icon {get;set;} 
    @AuraEnabled public string title {get;set;} 
    @AuraEnabled public string description {get;set;} 
    @AuraEnabled public locationDetailWrapper location {get;set;} 
}
/* sub wrapper class to store location details for "accountLocationWrapper" location property.*/ 
public class locationDetailWrapper{
    @AuraEnabled public string Street{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public string Brgy{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public string City{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public string Province{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public string District{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public string Region{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public string Country{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public string Longitude {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public string Latitude {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public string Amount {get;set;}
}



@AuraEnabled
public static Account fetchMainAccountAddress(String acctID){
    Account acctAddress = [Select Id,Name,Account_Address_1_Bldg_No_Street__c, Account_Address_2_District_Brgy__c, Territory_Town_City_Municipality__c, 
                           Province__c, District__c,Region__c,Area__c, Zip_Code__c,  Longitude__c, Latitude__c
                           ,sales_ave__r.amt__c
                           from Account where Id=:acctId
                           LIMIT 1
                          ];
    //System.debug('CHECKER -> ' + acctAddress);
    return acctAddress;
    
}  

@AuraEnabled
public static List<Account> fetchNearByAccount(String acctID, String city){
    //System.debug('Checker1: ' + city);
    // pryceRegion = pryceRegion.removeEnd(',');
    //List<Account> returnList = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> nearbyAcctList = [Select Id,Name,Account_Address_1_Bldg_No_Street__c, 
                                    Account_Address_2_District_Brgy__c, 
                                    Territory_Town_City_Municipality__c, 
                                    Province__c, District__c,Region__c,Area__c, Zip_Code__c,
                                    Longitude__c, Latitude__c
                                    ,sales_ave__r.amt__c
                                    from Account 
                                    where Territory_Town_City_Municipality__c = :city
                                    AND Province__c != null
                                    AND Id != :acctID
                                    ORDER BY Longitude__c DESC
                                    LIMIT 5
                                    
                                   ];
    //System.debug('Checker :' + nearbyAcctList.size());
    //returnList.addAll(nearbyAcctList);
    return nearbyAcctList;
    //return returnList;
    
}    

@AuraEnabled
public static list<accountLocationWrapper> getLocation(String acctId){
    list<accountLocationWrapper> lstALW = new list<accountLocationWrapper>();
    
    Account acctMain = fetchMainAccountAddress(acctId);
    //if(acctMain != null){
        accountLocationWrapper acctLocation = new accountLocationWrapper();
        locationDetailWrapper acctLocDetailWrap = new locationDetailWrapper();
        
        acctLocDetailWrap.Street =  acctMain.Account_Address_1_Bldg_No_Street__c;
        acctLocDetailWrap.Brgy = acctMain.Account_Address_2_District_Brgy__c;
        acctLocDetailWrap.City = acctMain.Territory_Town_City_Municipality__c;
        acctLocDetailWrap.Province = acctMain.Province__c;
        acctLocDetailWrap.District = acctMain.District__c;
        acctLocDetailWrap.Region = acctMain.Region__c;
        acctLocDetailWrap.Country = 'Philippines';
        acctLocDetailWrap.Longitude = String.valueOf(acctMain.Longitude__c);
        acctLocDetailWrap.Latitude = String.valueOf(acctMain.Latitude__c);
        acctLocDetailWrap.Amount = String.valueOf(acctMain.sales_ave__r.amt__c);
        
        acctLocation.icon = 'standard:account';
        acctLocation.title = acctMain.Name + ' | '+ acctMain.sales_ave__r.amt__c;
        acctLocation.description = acctMain.Account_Address_1_Bldg_No_Street__c; 

        
        acctLocation.location = acctLocDetailWrap;
        lstALW.add(acctLocation);
        
        
        List<Account> listAcct = fetchNearByAccount(acctMain.Id,acctMain.Territory_Town_City_Municipality__c);
        //System.debug('CHEEEEEEECK List Account ' + listAcct);
        for(Account acct: listAcct){
            accountLocationWrapper nearAcctLocation = new accountLocationWrapper();
            
            //System.debug('CHEEEEEEECK>> ' + acct);
            
            locationDetailWrapper nearAcctLocDetailWrap = new locationDetailWrapper();
            nearAcctLocDetailWrap.Street =  acct.Account_Address_1_Bldg_No_Street__c;
            nearAcctLocDetailWrap.Brgy = acct.Account_Address_2_District_Brgy__c;
            nearAcctLocDetailWrap.City = acct.Territory_Town_City_Municipality__c;
            nearAcctLocDetailWrap.Province = acct.Province__c;
            nearAcctLocDetailWrap.District = acct.District__c;
            nearAcctLocDetailWrap.Region = acct.Region__c;
            nearAcctLocDetailWrap.Country = 'Philippines';
            nearAcctLocDetailWrap.Longitude = String.valueOf(acct.Longitude__c);
            nearAcctLocDetailWrap.Latitude = String.valueOf(acct.Latitude__c);
            
            
            nearAcctLocation.icon = 'standard:work_order';
            nearAcctLocation.title = acct.Name;
            //nearAcctLocation.description = 'TOTAL SKU + SOMETHING FIELD'; 
            nearAcctLocation.description = acct.Account_Address_1_Bldg_No_Street__c; 
            
            nearAcctLocation.location = nearAcctLocDetailWrap;
            lstALW.add(nearAcctLocation);
        }
        
    //}
    return lstALW;
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. What is your question? You cannot turn off the 75% code coverage requirement, so you'll likely to have write more or more successful test classes. See our standard resources: [How do I write an Apex unit test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test).

Comment: already revised the code according to standards but no lock. Hope you can help me figuring what went wrong. :(