# how to write test class?

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

how to write test class for this class

Multiple objects are included to this method. i don't know how to its cover

```
public static void createAutoIndex(List<EmailMessage> emList, Map<Id, Case> mapCasesById){ 
     
        List<case> updatecase=new List<case>(); 
        set<id> ids = new set<id>();
        set<string> csubject = new set<string>();
        set<string> ccountry = new set<string>();
        for(EmailMessage em : emList){
            Case mm = mapCasesById.get(em.ParentId);
            
            if(em.Incoming ==true && !em.Subject.contains('ref:') && mm != Null && mm.ParentId ==null && mm.RecordTypeId==COE_EQM_RT_ID){
                ids.add(em.ParentId);
                csubject.add(mm.Subject);
                ccountry.add(mm.SuppliedCountry__c);
            } 
        } 
        
        list<case> lstCase=[select CaseNumber,id, Type,Topics__c,Subtopics__c,status,Subject,SuppliedEmail,SuppliedName,Description,RecordTypeId,SuppliedCountry__c,OwnerId,ParentId,CreatedDate,Owner.Name,OwnerGroup__c,OwnerName__c,(select id,Incoming,XSFDCOriginalRCPT__c from EmailMessages),
                            EmailConfiguration__c,EmailConfiguration__r.Email__c,Team__c,Team__r.MergeEmailsCase__c,Team__r.Id,Team__r.Country__c,EmailConfiguration__r.EmailServicesAddress__c,EmailConfiguration__r.OwnerId
                            FROM  case where id =:ids AND RecordTypeId =:COE_EQM_RT_ID LIMIT 1];
        if(lstCase.size() > 0){
        String TeamCountryName =lstCase[0].Team__r.Country__c;
            
            Map<String, Cluster__c> ContryDetail =COE_CMP02_EQMProcessController.getCountryDetail(TeamCountryName);                    
            
            //String CountryName    =lstCase[0].Team__r.Country__c;
           // String CountryCode    =ContryDetail.get(TeamCountryName).Name;  
           // String CountryId      =ContryDetail.get(TeamCountryName).Id; 
            String TeamIdProcess  =ContryDetail.get(TeamCountryName).ProcessQueue__r.OwnerId; 
            String TeamIdAudit    =ContryDetail.get(TeamCountryName).AuditQueue__r.OwnerId; 
            String TeamIdGeneric  =ContryDetail.get(TeamCountryName).GenericQueue__r.OwnerId; //It is a Generic Id; 
            Integer GroupCaseMin  =integer.valueOf(ContryDetail.get(TeamCountryName).GroupMinutes__c);
            DateTime timeNow = System.now(); // Get the time now
            DateTime X30MinutesAgo = timeNow.addMinutes(-GroupCaseMin); // Subtract N minutes from it  
        
        List<Case> existingCases = [Select Id,ParentId, OwnerId,CaseNumber,CaseClosureReason__c,Owner.Name, SuppliedEmail, EmailConfiguration__c, EmailConfiguration__r.Email__c,
                                        EmailConfiguration__r.EmailServicesAddress__c, Subject,Team__c,Team__r.MergeEmailsCase__c, Status,
                                        IncomingRequest__c,RunTeamAssignment__c,LastEmailDate__c, CreatedById,SuppliedCountry__c,Type,Topics__c,Subtopics__c
                                        From Case
                                        Where BookingNumber__c =:null 
                                        And Status != 'Closed' and Origin = 'Email' And Id !=: ids And Subject =:lstCase[0].Subject
                                        AND ParentId =:null AND RecordTypeId =:COE_EQM_RT_ID 
                                        AND SuppliedCountry__c =: TeamCountryName                                             
                                        AND createdDate <:timeNow AND createdDate >:X30MinutesAgo                                                                                            
                                        ORDER BY createdDate DESC LIMIT 1];
        
        List<Rulebook__c> lstRuleBook=[SELECT Name,RecordTypeId,Priority__c,ActionRequest__c,
                                               FromMailid__c,SubjectKeyword__c,BodyKeyword__c,Country__c,RuleType__c,Category__c 
                                               FROM Rulebook__c
                                               WHERE Active__c=true
                                               AND Country__c =:TeamCountryName
                                               AND RecordTypeId =:COE_EQM_RUL_ID
                                              ];
        for(Case c : lstCase){
         
            if(existingCases.size() > 0){
                c.Status = 'Closed';
                c.CaseClosureReason__c = 'Duplicate';
                c.OwnerId = existingCases[0].OwnerId;
                c.ParentId =existingCases[0].Id; 
                c.SuppliedCountry__c =existingCases[0].SuppliedCountry__c;
                c.Type=existingCases[0].Type;
                c.Topics__c=existingCases[0].Topics__c;
                c.Subtopics__c=existingCases[0].Subtopics__c;
                updatecase.add(c);
                
            }else{ 
                List<Rulebook__c> ruleList = new List<Rulebook__c>();
                String strBody,strSubject,strFromemailid,strPriority,strCategory,strCountrycode,strValidRequest,strRuleType,strCountrycodee,strActionRequest;
                String RuleCheck,StrTopic,strSubtopic;
                String TeamId;
                Integer i =0;
                
                for(Rulebook__c eqmrule: lstRuleBook){
                    
                    ruleList.add(eqmrule);
                    Boolean Subject_Key = c.Subject.contains(eqmrule.SubjectKeyword__c);
                    Boolean Body_Key    = c.Description.contains(eqmrule.BodyKeyword__c);
                    Boolean From_mailid = c.SuppliedEmail.contains(eqmrule.FromMailid__c);
                    
                    if(Body_Key ==true || Subject_Key == true || From_mailid==true )
                    {
                        strRuleType = eqmrule.RuleType__c;
                        strBody    =  eqmrule.BodyKeyword__c;
                        strSubject =  eqmrule.SubjectKeyword__c;
                        strFromemailid = eqmrule.FromMailid__c;
                        
                        if((strRuleType=='MS' && Subject_Key == true)
                           || (strRuleType=='MB' && Body_Key == true) 
                           || (strRuleType=='MF' && From_mailid == true)
                           || (strRuleType=='MSOB' && (Subject_Key == true || Body_Key== true))
                           || (strRuleType=='MBOF' && (Body_Key== true || From_mailid == true))
                           || (strRuleType=='MSOF' && (Subject_Key == true || From_mailid == true))  
                           || (strRuleType=='MSOBOF' && (Subject_Key == true || Body_Key== true || From_mailid == true))  
                           || (strRuleType=='MSAB' && (Subject_Key == true && Body_Key== true))  
                           || (strRuleType=='MBAF' && (Body_Key== true && From_mailid == true ))  
                           || (strRuleType=='MSAF' && (Subject_Key == true && From_mailid == true)) 
                           || (strRuleType=='MSABAF' && (Subject_Key == true && Body_Key== true  && From_mailid== true)))                             
                        {
                            i++;
                            strActionRequest = eqmrule.ActionRequest__c;
                            strPriority = eqmrule.Priority__c;
                            strCategory    = eqmrule.Category__c;                                                             
                            strCountrycode = eqmrule.Country__c;
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                if(i>0){ 
                    if(strActionRequest==C3S_UTI01_Constants.CASE_EQM_REQ_TYPE){
                        TeamId=TeamIdProcess;
                        RuleCheck='YES';
                        StrTopic=C3S_UTI01_Constants.CASE_EQM_REQ_TOPIC;
                        strSubtopic= C3S_UTI01_Constants.CASE_EQM_REQ_SUBTOPIC;                            
                    }
                    else if(strActionRequest==C3S_UTI01_Constants.CASE_EQM_INFO_TYPE)
                    {
                        TeamId=TeamIdGeneric;
                        RuleCheck='YES';
                        StrTopic=C3S_UTI01_Constants.CASE_EQM_INFO_TOPIC;
                        strSubtopic= C3S_UTI01_Constants.CASE_EQM_INFO_SUBTOPIC;                                
                    }
                    else if(strActionRequest==C3S_UTI01_Constants.CASE_EQM_NOAC_TYPE)
                    {
                        TeamId=TeamIdGeneric;
                        RuleCheck='YES';
                        StrTopic=C3S_UTI01_Constants.CASE_EQM_NOAC_TOPIC;
                        strSubtopic= C3S_UTI01_Constants.CASE_EQM_NOAC_SUBTOPIC;                                
                    }
                }else{
                    TeamId=TeamIdProcess;
                    strActionRequest=C3S_UTI01_Constants.CASE_EQM_REQ_TYPE;
                    strPriority='Low';  
                    strCategory='';      
                    RuleCheck='NO';
                    StrTopic=C3S_UTI01_Constants.CASE_EQM_REQ_TOPIC;
                    strSubtopic= C3S_UTI01_Constants.CASE_EQM_REQ_SUBTOPIC;                          
                }
                //START INDEX
                COE_Indexer__c myIndex        = new COE_Indexer__c();
                myIndex.RuleCheck__c          = RuleCheck;
                myIndex.IndexInput__c         ='AUTO INDEX';
                myIndex.Case__c               = c.id;
                myIndex.RequestType__c        = StrTopic;        
                myIndex.RecordTypeId          = COE_EQM_INDX_ID;
                myIndex.EQMCategory__c        = strCategory;
                insert myIndex;
                
                c.OwnerId       =TeamId;
                c.OwnerQueue__c =TeamId;
                c.COE_Indexer__c=myIndex.Id;
                c.Type=strActionRequest;
                c.Topics__c=StrTopic;
                c.Subtopics__c=strSubtopic;
                c.SuppliedCountry__c = TeamCountryName;
                c.Priority=strPriority;
                updatecase.add(c);  
                
            }//Exists case close
        }
         update updatecase;
        } // lstcase size close
    }
   
  public static void setRandomauditAction(List<Case> csListNew){
        set<id> ccsIds = new set <id>();
        Set<string> Cntry = new Set<string>();
        Map<Id, Case> caseMap = new Map<Id, Case>(csListNew);
        try{
            for(Case cs: csListNew) {
                if(cs.id != null && cs.RecordTypeId == COE_EQM_RT_ID)
                {
                    ccsIds.add(cs.Id);
                    Cntry.add(cs.SuppliedCountry__c);
                }
            }
            List<Case> cusUpdateList = new List<Case>();
          
            Cluster__c clu =[select Id,RandomAudit__c from Cluster__c where CountryName__c =:Cntry  AND RecordTypeId =:COE_EQM_CLU_ID LIMIT 1];
            Integer randomAudit =integer.valueOf(clu.RandomAudit__c);
            List<Case> casextList =[SELECT Id,CustomsDeclared__c,Status,RecordTypeId FROM Case WHERE RecordTypeId =:COE_EQM_RT_ID AND Status=:C3S_UTI01_Constants.CASE_STATUS_CLOSED 
                                                    AND ClosedDate=TODAY AND SuppliedCountry__c =:Cntry  AND CaseClosureReason__c!='Duplicate' ORDER BY ClosedDate DESC LIMIT :randomAudit];
            List<Case> csExList = new List<Case>();
            for(case cex: casextList){
                if(cex.Status == C3S_UTI01_Constants.CASE_STATUS_CLOSED && cex.RecordTypeId == COE_EQM_RT_ID && cex.CustomsDeclared__c==true){
                    cex.CustomsDeclared__c=true;
                    csExList.add(cex);
                }
            }
            if(csExList.size()==0) {
                List<Case> ccusList =[Select Id,CustomsDeclared__c,Status,RecordTypeId From Case Where Id =:ccsIds AND RecordTypeId =:COE_EQM_RT_ID AND Status=:C3S_UTI01_Constants.CASE_STATUS_CLOSED 
                                                      AND ClosedDate=TODAY AND SuppliedCountry__c =:Cntry];
                for(case cu: ccusList){
                    if(cu.Status == C3S_UTI01_Constants.CASE_STATUS_CLOSED && cu.RecordTypeId == COE_EQM_RT_ID){
                        cu.CustomsDeclared__c =true;
                        cusUpdateList.add(cu);
                    }
                }
                update cusUpdateList;
            }
                        }
            catch(Exception e){
            LogEvent__e logEvent = C3S_UTI02_Logger.logEventFromException(null, e, 'COE_TRG02_CaseStatusHandler', 'setRandomauditAction', null, null, null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please take a [tour] and read thru [ask]. There should be many questions already answered on this site for this problem. Also, have you tried reading up apex developer guide or relevant trailhead modules?

Comment: I recommend reading the introduction to https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write an Apex unit test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test)

Comment: You need to create all the required records in your test method or in your testSetup. Then call your method with appropriate parameters