# Writing Apex Extension Test

Tags: apex, visualforce

I was graciously given the code below by sfdcfox, however after spending the night googling for test class walkthroughs I can't seem to figure it out.

Would anyone have any resources to share or be able to point a beginner in the right direction for testing this extension class?

```
public inherited sharing class InventoryTransferSheetController {
  Inventory_Transfer_Sheet__c record;
  public InventoryTransferSheetController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    record = (Inventory_Transfer_Sheet__c)controller.getRecord();
  }
  public void saveChildren() {     
  update record.Inventory_Transfer_Lines__r;    
  }
}
```

Comment: The [How do I write an Apex unit test](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test) canonical-qa question goes over the basics and shares some resources (like one of the modules on unit testing that Trailhead provides).

Comment: While that is unlikely to tell you _exactly_ how to write a unit test for this class, the important things to keep in mind are that there's not too much difference between testing code X and code Y. You set up appropriate data, call the method that you want to test, gather the results, and make assertions that the output matches what you think it should be (as a result of running your code).

Comment: That link is miles ahead of anything I found on google haha, thanks so much for the resources!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @Kylan! If you apply those resources and get stuck you're welcome to come back to us with a specific challenge.