# Getting error in test class: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY

Tags: apex, code-coverage, failing-tests

I am doing a test class for a trigger. Here is the test code. The error happens in line 13, which is inserted

```
@isTest (SeeAllData=false)
public class pullCommentsApprovalOCRTest {
    
    @isTest
    public static void test(){
        
        Order_Cancellation_Re__c OCR = new Order_Cancellation_Re__c();
        //OCR.id = 'a0A0k00000Pk6GgEAJ';
        //OCR.Requested_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2010, 07, 15);
        OCR.Approval_Status__c = 'Draft';
        OCR.Account__c = '11128432890AdcgHUa';
        OCR.Approver_Comments3__c = 'ok';
        insert OCR;
        
        User submitter = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE IsActive = true LIMIT 1];
        
        
        //System.runAs(submitter) {
            Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest r = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
            r.setObjectId(OCR.Id);
            r.setNextApproverIds(new Id[] {UserInfo.getUserId()});
            //r.setNextApproverIds(null);      
            //r.setNextApproverIds('1298jundjdd');
            Approval.process(r);
        //}
        
        
        Test.startTest();
        update OCR;
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

This is my trigger class code:

```
trigger pullCommentsApprovalOCR on Order_Cancellation_Re__c (before update) {
    Map<Id, Order_Cancellation_Re__c> oppMap = new Map<Id, Order_Cancellation_Re__c>([
        Select (Select IsPending, ProcessInstanceId, TargetObjectId, StepStatus, OriginalActorId, ActorId,Actor.Name, RemindersSent, Comments, IsDeleted, CreatedDate, CreatedById, SystemModstamp 
         From ProcessSteps where StepStatus IN ('Approved','Rejected') ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) From Order_Cancellation_Re__c WHERE Id IN : Trigger.new]);
    
    for(Order_Cancellation_Re__c opp: Trigger.new) {
        Order_Cancellation_Re__c opp1 = oppMap.get(opp.Id);
        opp.Approver_Comments__c = '';
        for (ProcessInstanceHistory processStep : opp1.ProcessSteps) {
            opp.Approver_Comments3__c = 'aa'; //This is a dummy value & field only.
            opp.Approver_Comments__c += 'Comments: ' + processStep.comments + ' . Status: ' + processStep.StepStatus + ' . Date: ' + processStep.CreatedDate +' . Commentor Name: ' + processStep.Actor.Name + '/';
            //opp.Approved_Date__c = DateTime.parse(system.now().format());
            opp.Approver_Comments3__c = 'aa'; //This is a dummy value & field only.
        }
        opp.Approver_Comments3__c = 'aa';
    }
}
```

This is the error that I get during the Apex test execution:

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []
```

May I know how to solve this error? Why this error is occurring?

Comment: The account Id is invalid. As part of the test, you should create an account and tag it in line 11

Comment: If you're new to writing unit tests, please review https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test