# I am new to SalesForce development and don't have much understanding of test classes. Can anyone please help me creating test class for following code

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
public class GenerateFirstInvoices {
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void fetchOrderItems(List<Id> orderId) {
        List<OrderItem> oproduct = [SELECT Id, Next_Billing_Date__c, OriginalOrderItemId, Payment_Term__c, Quantity, TotalPrice FROM OrderItem WHERE OrderId = :orderId];
        for (OrderItem oitem : oproduct) {
            switch on oitem.Payment_Term__c {
                when 'Monthly' {
                    for (Integer i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                        Proforma_Invoice__c proforma = new Proforma_Invoice__c();
                        proforma.Rate__c = oitem.TotalPrice / 12;
                        proforma.Amount__c = oitem.TotalPrice / 12;
                        proforma.Order_Product__c = oitem.Id;
                        proforma.Quantity__c = oitem.Quantity;

                        insert proforma;
                    }
                }
                when 'Quarterly', '25%' {
                    for (Integer i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        Proforma_Invoice__c proforma = new Proforma_Invoice__c();
                        proforma.Rate__c = oitem.TotalPrice / 4;
                        proforma.Amount__c = oitem.TotalPrice / 4;
                        proforma.Order_Product__c = oitem.Id;
                        proforma.Quantity__c = oitem.Quantity;

                        insert proforma;
                    }
                }
                when 'Semi Annually', '50%' {
                    for (Integer i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                        Proforma_Invoice__c proforma = new Proforma_Invoice__c();
                        proforma.Rate__c = oitem.TotalPrice / 2;
                        proforma.Amount__c = oitem.TotalPrice / 2;
                        proforma.Order_Product__c = oitem.Id;
                        proforma.Quantity__c = oitem.Quantity;

                        insert proforma;
                    }
                }
                when else {
                    //Do nothing
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Following is my Test class

```
@isTest
private class GenerateFirstInvoices_TGN_TEST {
    @isTest
    private static void fetchOrderItems_TGN_TEST() {
        String Payment_Terms = 'Monthly';
        Database.SaveResult dsr;
        OrderItem drOrderItem;
        drOrderItem=new OrderItem(OrderId='802x00000000000AAA',PricebookEntryId='802x00000000000AAA',Quantity=123,Payment_Term__c='Monthly',type__c='Subscription');
        dsr=Database.insert(drOrderItem,false);
        
        Test.startTest();
        try{
        GenerateFirstInvoices.fetchOrderItems(new List<Id>{dsr.getId()});
        }catch(Exception e){}
        try{
        GenerateFirstInvoices.fetchOrderItems(null);
        }catch(Exception e){}
        Test.stopTest();
        
        Test.startTest();
        try{
                drOrderItem.Payment_Term__c == 'Monthly';
                Proforma_Invoice__c proforma = new Proforma_Invoice__c();            
                proforma.Rate__c = 100;
                proforma.Amount__c = 100;
                proforma.Order_Product__c = '802x00000000000AAA';
                proforma.Quantity__c = 1;
        
                insert proforma;
            
        }catch(Exception e){}
        Test.stopTest();
    }
    @isTest
    private static void GenerateFirstInvoices_TGN_TEST(){
        GenerateFirstInvoices obj = new GenerateFirstInvoices();
    }
}
```

**Note:-** The above test code is just for one condition only

The above test class code covers up to for loop, but it does not cover switch statement and as code inside switch. My total coverage is only 30%. Hope it will explain what I need. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please go through this answer [How do I write an Apex unit test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test) and [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/unit-testing-on-the-lightning-platform) to have better understanding of test class. If you have made an attempt of writing the test class then provide the code and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know how to write the test class but I am stuck with switch conditions. So I am able to cover the rest but not switch in my test class. I tried to paste my code here but it is too long to post. How could I post my code here in comment??

Comment: [Edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/347546/edit) your question body section and add the test class code there, describing clearly in the edited question itself where you are stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have DML in a loop. Don't do this. Instead, add all of the items to a list and create them at the end:

```
Proforma_Invoice__c[] recordsToInsert = new Proforma_Invoice__c[0];
...
for (OrderItem oitem : oproduct) {
  ...
  for (Integer i = 0; i < ...; i++) {
    Proforma_Invoice__c proforma = new Proforma_Invoice__c();
    ...
    recordsToInsert.add(proforma);
  }
  ...
}
insert recordsToInsert;
```

The reason why you want to avoid DML or SOQL in a loop is that you will run in to governor limits this way when enough records are involved.

---

Second, we can apply DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself, a basic programming principle) here by collapsing your conditions into variables. Further, we can get rid of the switch and use a Map here:

```
    Map<String, Integer> factors = new Map<String, Integer>{
        'Monthly' => 12,
        'Quarterly' => 4,
        '25%' => 4,
        'Semi Annually' => 2,
        '50%' => 2
    };
    for (OrderItem oitem : oproduct) {
        Integer factor = factors.get(oitem.Payment_Term__c);
        for (Integer i = 1; i <= factor; i++) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

---

This reduces your code to just:

```
public class GenerateFirstInvoices {
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void fetchOrderItems(List<Id> orderId) {
        List<OrderItem> oproduct = [SELECT Id, Next_Billing_Date__c, OriginalOrderItemId, Payment_Term__c, Quantity, TotalPrice FROM OrderItem WHERE OrderId = :orderId];
        Proforma_Invoice__c[] recordsToInsert = new Proforma_Invoice__c[0];
        Map<String, Integer> factors = new Map<String, Integer>{
            'Monthly' => 12,
            'Quarterly' => 4,
            '25%' => 4,
            'Semi Annually' => 2,
            '50%' => 2
        };
        for (OrderItem oitem : oproduct) {
            Integer factor = factors.get(oitem.Payment_Term__c);
            for (Integer i = 1; i <= factor; i++) {
                recordsToInsert.add(new Proforma_Invoice__c(
                    Rate__c = oitem.TotalPrice / factor,
                    Amount__c = oitem.TotalPrice / factor,
                    Order_Product__c = oitem.Id,
                    Quantity__c = oitem.Quantity
                ));
            }
        }
        insert recordsToInsert;
    }
}
```

Which will automatically have 100% coverage as long as you use any of the correct payment terms.

Notice how we made the unit test easier by fixing the logic in our code. The purpose of a unit test is to catch flaws in our actual code. Sometimes, this means fixing the code, not the unit test.

Finally, you had a bug in your logic. Presumably, there should have been an equal number of items created for each category, but you were creating one less than what you needed (11 items for monthly, 3 for quarterly, and 1 for semi-annually). I fixed this in the rewrite.

Always make sure you use assertions to verify the correct output.

Comment: Thank you so much for your brief reply and guidance on my approach. I will definitely use the approach you advised and will check the result.