# Testing Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

My code comes out as 0% coverage even though I have no errors. What am I doing wrong?

```
@IsTest
public class TestPlayerTrigger {
   @IsTest static void RacquetRequest(){
      List<Racquet_Restring_Request__c> requestList = new List<Racquet_Restring_Request__c>();
      Player__c p = (new Player__c(Restring_Request__c = true));
        
      insert requestList;
        
      Test.startTest();
      Database.SaveResult[] result = Database.insert(requestList, false);
      Test.stopTest();
        
      System.assert(result[0].isSuccess());     
   }
}
```

```
trigger PlayerTrigger on Player__c (after insert, after update) {
    List<Racquet_Restring_Request__c> requestList = new List<Racquet_Restring_Request__c>();
    
    for(Player__c player : Trigger.New){
        if (player.Restring_Request__c == true){
            requestList.add(new Racquet_Restring_Request__c(Name='New Request for '+ player.Name));
        }
    }
    
    if(requestList.size() > 0){
        insert requestList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Thank you for sharing code that you have tried so far. See if this helps: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/244788. If it does not help, come back and [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/355582/edit) your question to add what else you have tried (and any errors you might have gotten). Someone will likely try to directly help then.

Comment: Also, please do not post code (or errors) as *only* screenshots - people accessing your question who use screen readers or other technology for accessibility will not know what the text of your code is. Please edit your question to add your trigger code as text - and when you do, please use three "backticks": ``` to start and end your code so that it will be formatted correctly. _(Click the question mark (?) on the Body text box when editing your question to get more info on formatting your questions and answers.)_

Comment: One thing: your trigger is on the `Player__c` object, but in your test method you never insert a `Player__c` record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are inserting the wrong objects in your test class.

Use the below code

```
@IsTest
public class TestPlayerTrigger {
  @IsTest static void RacquetRequest(){
     Player__c p = (new Player__c(Restring_Request__c = true));
    
     Test.startTest();
     insert p;
     Test.stopTest();

   List<Racquet_Restring_Request__c> requestList = [Select Id from Racquet_Restring_Request__c ];
    
     System.assert(requestList.size()==1);     
    }
}
```

Also, I recommend using [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro) to brush up on Apex Testing.